# I reverse the source code, you negate the output!

Tags: code-golf, source-layout

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program that outputs a non-zero number(can be integer or float). The tricky part is that if I reverse your source code, the output must be the original integer negated.

## Rules

- You must build a **full program**. That is, your output has to be printed to STDOUT.
- Both the numbers must be in base 10 (outputting them in any other base or with scientific notation is forbidden).
- Outputting the numbers with trailing / leading spaces is allowed.
- This is code-golf, so the shortest (original) code in each language wins!
- Default Loopholes apply.

### Example

Let's say your source code is `ABC` and its corresponding output is `4`. If I write `CBA` instead and run it, the output must be `-4`.

Comment: If we could reverse at the bit level rather than the byte level the one byte `-` (0x45 = 0b00101101) works in Jelly -  `-` yields -1 since it defines the literal -1, while `Ṇ` (0xB4 = 0b10110100) yields 1 since it performs a logical not of the implicit input of zero. (Of course `Ṇ` works just as well :p)

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Does "have an unused, empty input" mean we can rely on input functions immediately reaching EOF?

Comment: @Borka223 No, you may not.

Answer (score 53):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
(1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9fw/D/fwA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUOP/fwA)

```
(       # negate nothing
 1      # push 1 (and implictly output it)
```

```
1       # push 1
 (      # negate it (and implictly output it)
```

Comment: +1 for "[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fUOP/fwA)"..

Answer (score 31):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell),  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

```powershell
1-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/31DX4P9/AA) or [!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/30DX8P9/AA)

*Golfed a byte by using arithmetic instead of the number-comment-number format.*

---

This is apparently also the same as jshell (per [Sam](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/89348/sam)), and jq (per [manatwork](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4198/manatwork) -- [`1-0`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99Q1@D//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA) and [`0-1`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99A1/D//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA)).

Comment: The same in jshell

Comment: The same in jq: [`1-0`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99Q1@D//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA "jq – Try It Online") [`0-1`](https://tio.run/##yyr8/99A1/D//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3XzAA "jq – Try It Online").

Answer (score 30):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 19 bytes

```javascript
print(1)//)1-(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxNCsMgEIX3niK7zECd4K5QcpJSiJihGMQRFa9vGqi0u/fzvXfYZovLPlXd7t3JzuvWU/axgsFlQaOhRp9T36gE7xjMTRtUKnPjXHif1ulJRNfwRd8QkA7xEeYZH0o5iUUCU5A3XNgn42bD0P/1OB3Iz/cT)

---

almost identical to...

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 19 bytes

```cs
Print(1)//)1-(tnirP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/oCgzr0TDUFNfX9NQV6MkL7Mo4P9/AA)

*(thanks to @someone for pointing it out)*

---

still pretty much the same in...

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 19 bytes

```lua
print(1)--)1-(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/J@cn5JqqxEd/b@gKDOvRMNQU1dX01BXoyQvs6jgf2ysplVxaZKGoY6ukSYXV1FqWWpRcWqKgq0CSJsVlK8BlILoBolqcuXkJ6ZAmEAZiARMJ1QSztXQ/A8A)

---

but shorter in...

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 15 bytes

```python
print 1#1-tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EwVDZULckL7Oo4P9/AA)

---

Even shorter in PHP, because it has this magic printing tool: `<?=` ...

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 12 bytes

```php
<?=1;#;1-=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7W0FrZ2lDX1t7m/38A)

---

Even shorterer in Ruby, because you can `inspect` rather than print

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 8 bytes

```ruby
p 1#1- p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0DBUNlQV6Hg/38A)

Comment: Also C# Interactive, `Print(1)//)-1(tnirP`. ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy7WTS7O/P8/oCgzr0TDUFNfX1PXUKMkL7Mo4P9/AA "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online"))

Comment: For C#, the shortest program is likely also the trivial one: `class A{static void Main(){System.Console.Write(1);}}//}};)1-(etirW.elosnoC.metsyS{)(niaM diov citats{A ssalc`

Comment: Not a programming language, but you can do `1<!--!<1-` (9 bytes) with HTML, which will be `-1<!--!<1` when reversed. It does exactly the same as your answer.

Comment: Mostly the same in Lua: `print(1)--)1-(tnirp`

Comment: @val This is a community wiki answer, so feel free to edit.

Comment: It would be nice to find answers for those languages, without any comment.

Comment: @EricDuminil: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193169/81663

Comment: Now that is a true bigbrainer

Answer (score 15):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 4 bytes

```
9/9-
```

Outputs `9`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/31LfUvf/fwA)

Reversed:

```
-9/9
```

Outputs `-9`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X9dS3/L/fwA)

Everything before the `/` is printed, while the rest is ignored (not really used slashes much so I don't know exactly what happens, but it doesn't output anything).

Comment: +1 for using Slashes. The `/` begins the pattern-reading process, and thus, the characters after it is readed into the pattern, not outputted.

Comment: I came up with `/\-//1-` and thought I was clever. :D

Answer (score 11):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 21 bytes

```
S S S T N
T   N
S T N
N
N
T   S N
T   N
T   T   S S
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.

Outputs `1`/`-1`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgZOLkwtIcHFxKgBZnJwKCv//AwA) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0GBk5OLk0uBk4uLi1MByOJUUFD4/x8A) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

Utilizing the *Exit Program* builtin being a short palindrome `NNN`.
The regular program will:

```python
SSSTN  # Push 1 to the stack
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

The reverse program will:

```python
SSTTN  # Push -1 to the stack
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

Small additional explanation of pushing a number:

- First `S`: Enable Stack Manipulation
- Second `S`: Push a number to the stack
- `S` or `T`: Positive/negative respectively
- Some `S`/`T` followed by a trailing `N`: number in binary, where `S=0` and `T=1`

I.e. `SSTTSTSN` pushes `-10`.

Answer (score 11):

## [Google](https://www.google.com), 3 bytes

```
2-1
```

[Try it online!](https://www.google.com/search?q=2-1)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://www.google.com/search?q=1-2)

Comment: This also works in TI-Basic

Comment: "output" here isn't well defined for the entire search engine Google. Did you mean, specifically, [Google's Calculator](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3284611?hl=en)?

Comment: Also works in python IDLE

Answer (score 11):

### [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) `-mn`, 4 bytes

```
:-:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcshDgAhDERRzy1qm/QCvUE9jrANQW4WA5K7d6fm5Y@YfcZ85zg7QkU9iF0LS0s68CzPagI6cGLABG5SQX6LXgE1MUx7TCPkWz8) In the footer I've included all other 4-byte solutions. (Stack Cats ignores everything after the first linefeed.)

[Try the reverse!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v8/3krX6v///7q5eQA)

#### Explanation

The `-n` flag turns on numeric output (and input, but we don't have any), and the `-m` flag is normally just a golfing convenience which lets you avoid the redundant part of the source code. This is because every Stack Cats program needs to have mirror symmetry. With the `-m` flag you only give it the first half (plus the central character). So the *actual* program here is:

```
:-:_:-:
```

As you can see in the first TIO link, there's a ton of 4-byte solutions, but I picked this one for its simplicity. Stack Cats is stack-based, and this program only uses the initial stack. Since we don't have any input, it contains a single `-1` (an EOF marker) on top of an infinite well of zeros. The three commands in the program have the following meaning:

```
:   Swap the top two stack elements.
-   Negate the top stack element (i.e. multiply by -1).
_   Pop a. Peek b. Push b-a.
```

So here is how the program modifies the stack (states and commands are staggered to indicate how each command changes the stack from one state to the next):

```
   :   -   :   _   :   -   :

-1   0   0  -1   1   0   0   1
 0  -1  -1   0   0   1   1   0
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …
```

As it turns out, the only command that really does anything here is `_` which turns our EOF marker into a `1`. Output at the end of the program is implicit, and the EOF marker is optional, so this just prints out the `1` we get.

Now if we reverse the source code, due to the implicit mirroring, the actual program becomes:

```
_:-:-:_
```

This does something very different:

```
   _   :   -   :   -   :   _

-1   1   0   0   1  -1   0  -1
 0   0   1   1   0   0  -1  -1
 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 …   …   …   …   …   …   …   …
```

This time the bottom of the stack *is* still a `-1` so it does act as the EOF marker and only the `-1` on top of it gets printed.

...

Now with all of that said, since Stack Cats has such a unique relationship with reversing code, I feel that using `-m` is a little cheating. It's normally only meant to save bytes by omitting the redundant part of the source code, but here it actually makes the challenge a lot easier and even the full program shorter. This is because reversing a full program will only change the program if it contains any of `<>[]`, which also means that the program ends up making use of multiple stacks (Stack Cats actually has a tape of stacks, where all but the initial one are only filled with zeros to begin with). Furthermore, reversing it then just swaps the `<>` and `[]` pairs, which still makes the execution symmetric. The only way to break that symmetry is to use `I` which does `-]` or `-[` or nothing depending on the sign of the top of the stack. So...

---

### [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) `-n`, 11 bytes

```
*|]I*:*I[|*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdG7jgMhDAXQfr8i0zoaRbslQtPf3h0BFKVcKU1S8u@zNr5IW8BwwDaPeX8ez9/n4/M@TxkVkgRlyLmPLAesjf3y/bWPgp46KoViqggpIzXESIqRIS8HL7ykUOrf3pcfE6SmIliqtlYoZaSGGLkUkaFD0K8dksV26C1vds7taN3lA/jUEjqWDslIsN7VOvN6c/kAM9uUtlTsRtW@lN2ImhmY2RQiMdQMjbInsCr@IJRVofwQdhY/kqmMY8uwNqpLKZ3yaXjAklWh7Ff5DawvUzqlUxj3qduASymdqswrIeaF7ly7hbjmOs/99Qc) The footer again includes all other alternatives at the same byte count. Some of those output 1/-1 and some output 2/-2 as indicated after each program. I picked this one to explain kinda randomly as one of the ones that output 2.

[Try the reverse!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v9fqybaU8tKyzO2Ruv///@6eQA)

#### Explanation

As I said, this one's a bit longer. Even if we did use the `-m` notation for this, it would weigh in at 6 bytes instead of the above 4.

The commands in use this time:

```
*   Toggle the least significant bit of the top of the stack.
|   Reverse the longest non-zero of prefix on this stack.
[]  Move one stack to the left/right and take the top of the current stack with you.
I   If the top of the stack is positive, -], if it's negative, -[, otherwise do nothing.
:   Swap the top two stack elements.
```

The first program only uses two stacks. That's a bit messy to do in ASCII art, but I'll try my best. The square brackets indicate which stack the tape head is on, and I'll put the commands between each pair of stack states.

```
  [-1]
…   0   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      *

  [-2]
…   0   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      | (does nothing)
      ]

      [-2]
…   0   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      I

   [2]
…   0   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      *

   [3]
…   0   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      :

   [0]
…   3   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      *

   [1]
…   3   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      I

      [-1]
…   3   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      [

  [-1]
…   3   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      |

  [ 3]
…  -1   0   …
    0   0
    …   …

      *

  [ 2]
…  -1   0   …
    0   0
    …   …
```

Now the `-1` acts as an EOF marker and the `2` gets printed.

The other program is the same until the `[`. It's still virtually the same all the way until the second `I`. We'll technically be on a different stack, but without values on them, they're all indistinguishable. But then the difference between `I[` and `I]` ends up mattering:

```
    *|[I*:*I

      [-1]
…   3   0   0   …
    0   0   0
    …   …   …

        ]

          [-1]
…   3   0   0   …
    0   0   0
    …   …   …

        | (does nothing)
        *

          [-2]
…   3   0   0   …
    0   0   0
    …   …   …
```

And this time, we don't have an EOF marker, but the program still outputs the `-2`.

Answer (score 10):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein) 011, 5 bytes

```
1-
@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/99Ql8tB/////waGhgA)

## Reversed

```
/@
-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/1/fgUvX8P///waGhgA)

These take advantage of Klein's unique topology, specifically the real projective plane.  (Although individually each answer only needs a Klein bottle).

Answer (score 10):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) without comments, 41 bytes

Forwards prints `1` + newline:

```hs
main=print$!1
niam=main
"1-"!$rtStup=niam
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0RF0ZArLzMx1xYkxKVkqKukqFJUElxSWmALEv7/HwA)

Reversed prints `-1` with no newline (which could be added at a cost of 2 bytes):

```hs
main=putStr$!"-1"
niam=main
1!$tnirp=niam
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oLQkuKRIRVFJ11CJKy8zMdcWJMxlqKhSkpdZVGALEvr/HwA)

- The first line of each program prints the number.

  - For `-1` string output is used to avoid parentheses.
  - Using `$!` (strict application) instead of a space allows the reversed line to be a valid definition of the operator `!$` (just `$` wouldn't do since the redefinition would break the use).
- The middle line ensures that `niam` is defined for the last line.
- The last line is a definition of an operator `!$`, which is not used but needs to parse and typecheck correctly.

Answer (score 9):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

A PHP version without comment abuse. `ohce` is an undefined constant, so it will be equal to string value of its name. As a result, this will try to print `+1-'ohce'` or `-1+'ohce'` when reversed. Since `'ohce'` is a non-numeric value, 0 will be used instead in the arithmetic operations and only `1` or `-1` will be printed.

```php
;echo+1-ohce;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkrVOTM/K1DXXzM5JTrf//BwA)

[‮Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAkrVOTM/J1DbXzM5JTrf//BwA)

Comment: That's clever. Nice!

Comment: Man, it's sad that I've arrived to the same answer as you, 3 hours late :( Have my upvote.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Any single digit integer `>0` can be used in place of the `2` as can `A-G`, `H`, `I`, `J` or `L` (`10-16`, `32`, `64`, `-1` & `100`, respectively).

```
n2
```

[Test it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bjI) | [Reversed](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Mm4)

The `n` method when applied to an integer, subtracts that integer from the argument passed to it, which defaults to `0`. When run forwards, the `n` method is being run on the implicit first input, which also defaults to `0`.

Alternatively, the `g` method could be used instead of `n`, which gives the sign of the result of subtracting its argument from the integer it's applied to.

Answer (score 7):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
@)O(@
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QClPKEA=&input=&speed=3)
[Reversed](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=QChPKUA=&input=&speed=3)

#### Explanation

Cubified:

```
  @
) O ( @
  .
```

Unrolling the control flow, we execute `)O(@`, which increments, outputs, decrements, and exits.

Reversed and cubified:

```
  @
( O ) @
  .
```

Unrolling the control flow, we execute `(O)@`, which decrements, outputs, increments, and exits.

#### Previous version

```
@O(.)O@
```

[Try it here](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgTwogICAgKCAuCikgTyBAIC4gLiAuIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=&speed=3)
[Reversed](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgIEAgTwogICAgKSAuCiggTyBAIC4gLiAuIC4gLgouIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgIC4gLgogICAgLiAuCg==&input=&speed=3)

Not as short, but aesthetically pleasing.

Comment: nice, way to put it on a size 1 cube!

Comment: `@)O(@` for 5 bytes and restoration of symmetry :)

Answer (score 6):

## T-SQL, 16 bytes

```sql
--Forwards:
PRINT 4--4-TNIRP

--Backwards:
PRINT-4--4 TNIRP
```

Picked 4 because 1 is overused :)

Comment: If you are curious, an answer for MySQL would be `select 1#1-tceles` (17 bytes). You can check the result on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/107825.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
NC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/P@f9/AA)

`N`egative, results in `0`, then `C`omplement, results in `1-0` = `1`.

---

```
CN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/Z7/9/AA)
`C`omplement, results in `1-0` = `1`. `N`egative, results in `-1`.

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 3 bytes

```
2-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/99I1/D/fwA)

am i missing something? seems obvious for REPL languages

Answer (score 6):

## [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 5 bytes

```
1!@!(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99Q0UFR4/9/AA)

Any valid program must:

- Have a termination command (`@` or `:`). The latter is only different for the former when there's a memory pointer movement command. Also this command must not be at the first or the last byte.
- Have an output command. (`!`, `;` is also possible but would probably take more bytes)
- Have a memory manipulation command.

Therefore a 2-byte program is obviously impossible. A 3-byte program is impossible because the second byte must be the termination command, and the first byte must not be a mirror/IP manipulation command, therefore only 1 byte can be executed.

I think a 4-byte program is not possible. Such a program must have the form `a@bc` with hexagonal grid

```
 Forward:       | Backward:
                | 
  c b           |   a @
 @ a .          |  b c .
  . .           |   . .
```

Therefore `a` must be a IP redirection command. However it's impossible to generate both positive and negative number with only 1 memory manipulation command.

Comment: +1 for proof of optimality in an otherwise trivial answer

Answer (score 5):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 4 bytes

```
1@Z1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/QIcrw/38A) [Try it Reversed!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/98wysHw/38A)

I couldn't find a way to re-use the `1` command, even at the expense of a byte or two.

[`1@ɩ`](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/9/Q4eTK//8B) also works, but is the same number of bytes.

Comment: Why the input? The question said your program must take no input.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I misread and already fixed it

Comment: Yeah, I see. Clever.

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/),  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

```apl
1-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wRDXQOudCBtoGsIFOBKBwA)

Trivial answer. Prints `1` when run and `¯1` when run reversed.

Answer (score 5):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 12 bytes

```sh
<<<2 # 2-<<<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsbGSEFZwUgXyABxdME8EAcA)

Basic forward, comment, reverse method.

---

If I/O is less restrictive, then a more interesting **11 byte** solution is possible thanks to Zsh supporting negative return codes:

```sh
return -127
```

Reversed, `721- nruter` exits with code `127` (command not found). `exit -127` cannot be used, it would be cast to a `u8`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9vyi1pLQoT0HX0Mj8fy1XEVCIy9zIUFchr6i0JLWIq5aLK40rNTkjX0HFnourCMb8DwA)

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 3 bytes

```
W;1
```

Try it online!

- [Normal](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/P9za8P9/AA)
- [Reversed](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/39A6/P9/AA)

#### How they work

Normal version:

```
W    e# Push -1
;    e# Delete
1    e# Push 1
     e# Implicit display
```

Reverse version: you get the idea.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (-p), 12 bytes

```perl
\$--{}}{++$\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z9GRVe3ura2WltbJeb//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z9GRVu7ura2WldXJeb//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

The `}{` pseudo-operator really comes in handy.

---

### [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) (-M5.010), 9 bytes

*Provided by Nahuel Fouilleul in a comment*

```perl
say+1-yas
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLbULcysfj//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLXULsysfj//3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA0A)

Comment: should be `say 1#1-yas`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul yas indeed

Comment: 9 bytes : `say+1-yas` and `say-1+yas`

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
Nqv
```

Try it online!

- [Normal](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36@w7P9/AA)
- [Reversed](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6zQ7/9/AA)

#### How they work

Normal:

```
N   % Push number of elements in the stack: 0
q   % Subtract 1: gives -1
v   % Concatenate stack contents vertically: leaves -1 as is
    % Implicit display stack contents
```

Reversed:

```
v   % Concatenate stack contents vertically: gives the empty array, []
q   % Subtract 1: leaves [] as is
N   % Push number of elements in the stack: 1
    % Implicit display. [] is not displayed
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>21</s> 18 bytes

```
Print@1;tnirP//1-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78r/Q/oCgzr8TB0LokL7MoQF/fUNfgv5K@vgaXQki@a0VBUWpxcWZ@noOyNZpAcAlQX3pQallqUXGqgzKXptp/AA)

-3 thanks to [Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-output/193040?noredirect=1#comment460420_193040)

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 6 bytes

```
-`<
-
```

Prints `1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/XzfBhkuX6/9/AA)

---

```
-
<`-
```

Prints `-1`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n0uXyyZB9/9/AA)

#### Explanation: `1`

```
-`<
-
```

This... does nothing. Due to the `` ` ``, this is a substitution from `<` to `-` (with configuration `-`, which does nothing), but the input is empty, so the output is empty as well.

And this second stage matches the empty regex against the empty input and counts the number of matches, which is exactly 1. Output is implicit.

#### Explanation: `-1`

```
-
```

This time we replace the empty regex with `-`. This does indeed turn the empty input into a single `-`.

```
<`-
```

Here, the configuration actually does something: `<` prints the stage's input before executing the stage, so we print the `-`. Then `-` counts the hyphens in the stage's input which is again 1. Due to the implicit output, this prints a `1` after the `-`, giving us `-1` as required.

Answer (score 4):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 156 bytes

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++<+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++++++++++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fmxSgp00qsCFZB5Id//8DAA) / [Forward/backward verifier in Bash](https://tio.run/##nY@7DoMwDEV3f4WHSh4qmm5IVdqhQ38CEMoLgaABhQCfn0YdStWhLw@WdeVzfS3FWIegNDJ/HcA7TDRSbpGQcyTTV4QnFLB9qQ8C7H4l7gLw/7DnaxAzA8CiMFExuBI@dqPqHmAwrsNk2KdpapA25dGZ2bjR4KYkFPFPGXdcY32FdOndIpw@YJZlBKwfPJNONLaaVLtOkeLItJmZnbruARdFkVtazc5Ctd@4yTduIdwA)

Prints `-1` forward and `\n1` backwards.

Despite being almost trivial, I believe this is the optimal solution for this particular fixed output.

Proof:

- The program cannot have `[` or `]`.

  Therefore the program must have the form `<A> . <B> . <C>`.
- Each `,` can be replaced with a sufficient number of `<` without increasing the number of `+` or `-`.
- Each `+` is only useful in either the forward or the backward program, never both.

  Proof: `+` in part A is obviously only useful in the forward program, and `+` in part C is obviously only useful in the backward program.

  Denote `shift(P)` = number of `<` in P - number of `>` in P. Consider program `<B> = <D> + <E>`, the `+` in the middle is useful in the forward program \$\iff\$ `shift(E) = 0`, similarly it's useful in the backward program \$\iff\$ `shift(D) = 0`. However if `shift(D) = shift(E) = 0` then the program `B` executed either forward or backward would add a fixed value to the current cell before printing the second time, which can't be the case because `ord('1') - ord('\n') != ord('1') - ord('-')`.

Therefore the program needs at least `ord('-')+ord('1')+ord('\n')+ord('1') = 153` `+`s, 2 `.`s, and at least a `<` `>` or `,` because `shift(B) != 0`.

Answer (score 4):

## Google Sheets, 12

Fun problem!

Forward:

```
=1+N("(N+1-=
```

Backward:

```
=-1+N("(N+1=
```

Google sheets auto-closes quotes and parens. `N(string)` is always 0.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iJ_ak7F0OucUrc55Nl5n3Y7Hpc1lyL-21ZV-VIZD5fM/edit?usp=sharing Cool answer!

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes

```hs
main=print 1--)1-(tnirp=niam
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0TBUFdX01BXoyQvs6jANi8zMff/fwA)

[Try it enilno!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzcxM8@2oCgzr0RD11BTV9dQoSQvs6jANi8zMff/fwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), 4 bytes

```
i%%d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/P1NVNeX/fwA)

Outputs 1.

Ungolfed:

```
   i
  % %
 d
```

**Reversed:**

```
d%%i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/P0VVNfP/fwA)

Outputs -1.

Answer (score 3):

## Java 5 or 6, <s>127</s> 67 bytes

```java
enum A{A;{System.out.print(9);}}//}};)9-(tnirp.tuo.metsyS{;A{A mune
```

Outputs `9`/`-9`.

No online compiler, because Java 5 or 6 isn't available anywhere.

You can however try this **127 bytes** Java 8 equivalent:
[Try it online](https://tio.run/##Dc3BCoUgEEDRX5mlLrJ19A9tXEaLQS2mhxo6CSF@u8/tgcu9seB021/vFNilE42DrWZGJgMlkgWPFITmROHaD5RVf5mdV/Fl9Qxksci1tXlubZXLJDhQehS/UXnH@dNV4rFfA1mLQOjBUixgaBxy3cAZPJMbUe9/) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##Dc3BCoUgEEDRX5mlLrJ19A9tXEaLQS2mhxo6CSF@u8/tgcu9seB021/vFNilE42DrWZGJgMlkgWPFITmROHaD5RVf5mdV/Fl9QxkMS1ybW2eW1vlIjhQehS/UXnH@dNV4rFfA1mLQOjBUixgaBxy3cAZPJMbUe9/).

**Explanation:**

```java
enum A{                              // Create an enum
 A;                                  //  With a mandatory value
 {                                   //  And in a separate instance code-block:
  System.out.print(9);}}             //   Print 9 to STDOUT
//}};)9-(tnirp.tuo.metsyS{;A{A mune  // Comment and thus a no-op
```

Java 5 and 6 had a bug allowing you to create a code block inside an enum to do something, despite missing a program's mandatory main-method. This will result in an error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
> Exception in thread "main"

But will still output what we'd want to STDOUT first, so [we can ignore that](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12503/52210).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 31 bytes

The obligatory comment abuse for JavaScript!

```
console.log(1)//)1-(gol.elosnoc
```

and reversed:

```
console.log(-1)//)1(gol.elosnoc
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Golang](https://golang.org/), 109 bytes

```golang
package main;import "fmt";func main(){fmt.Println(1)}//})1(nltnirP.tmf{)(niam cnuf;"tmf" tropmi;niam egakcap
```

And its reverse:

```golang
package main;import "fmt";func main(){fmt.Println(-1)}//})1(nltnirP.tmf{)(niam cnuf;"tmf" tropmi;niam egakcap
```

[Try it online!](https://play.golang.org/p/QtWh7Sh9Dee)

Comment: I don't know Go, but it seems you can remove a few bytes. The `Println` can be `Print`, and the `import "fmt";` doesn't need the space: `import"fmt";`. :)

Answer (score 3):

\$\Large{\mathbf{\TeX} \left(\text{MathJax}\right)},~4\,\text{bytes}\$

```
1%1-
```

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|}
\hline
 & \textbf{Code}
 %& \begin{array}{c}\boxed{\textbf{Boxed}} \\ \textbf{Result} \end{array}
 & \textbf{Result}
\\\hline
\textbf{Forward:} & \texttt{1%1-} &
  %\boxed{
1%1-
  %}
\\\hline
\textbf{Backward:} & \texttt{-1%1} &
  %\boxed{
-1%1
  %}
\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 3):

## Poetic, 153 bytes

```
mood o-o level a
was i redder?o,rats
lived on,lager:a trap!no reviver
ah hah ha
god deified on?now i strap on
redder was i?redder i saw,o
sleep o-on time
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?LY4xDsMwCEV3TkF39wJdfBYqaGKJmAhb9vFT4nZg@PqPB4cZoz0NVYYoEkxqWNCFWTxbcuoNtAwJqialTfxF2J3OR7XARlQOtOO@BrbQsZRPWQu52gxbu/mI8NPiupH/IWqayaCpyHm/UrGXQ67rTfwF)

Prints `1`.

#### Reversed

```
emit no-o peels
o,was i redder?i saw redder
no parts i won?no deified dog
ah hah ha
reviver on!part a:regal,no devil
star,o?redder i saw
a level o-o doom
```

[!enilno ti yrT](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?LU5JDsMgDLzziumdfqAX3uLKbmKJ4MogeH4aaA5zGM0qhzYUexq@IrkGi4MqFC7M4klRadwklMtE3qY8rKSLsuhHhcG2BdqxLwSXrl0cVh7TD3q5bJTjCnTNoTbyaOlfi7URCFm6ZMwrbHac55v4Bw)

Prints `-1`.

Comment: Wow! Point is, they are still words when reversed!

Answer (score 2):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 5 bytes

```
+
:
-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fm8uKS/f/fwA)

**Reversed:**

```
-
:
+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL//9fl8uKS/v/fwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
U1
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=U1&i=&a=1)

[!zyx.gnalxats ta ti gubed dan nuR](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=1U&i=&a=1)

Push -1. Push 1. Implicitly print the top of the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Language](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 29 bytes

```lua
0 * - r 1
1 * 1 * 1
1 r _ * 0
```

And its reverse:

```lua
0 * _ r 1
1 * 1 * 1
1 r - * 0
```

[Try it online!](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?a470826438f96e2e464ab4af555ad1a2)

Note: This will run in a continous loop both ways.

Explanation:

```lua
0 * - r 1     ; Prints a hyphen '-' then moves right along the tape.
1 * 1 * 1     ; Prints '1' and loops back in on itself.
1 r _ * 0     ; Never hits.
```

And its reverse:

```lua
0 * _ r 1     ; Prints a space then moves right along the tape.
1 * 1 * 1     ; Prints '1' and loops back in on itself.
1 r - * 0     ; Never hits.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 7 bytes

A solution using the stack length. The regular and reversed programs share most of the code.

```
2l-n;<3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3yhHN8/axvj/fwA)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39jGOk83x@j/fwA)

---

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 7 bytes

A more boring solution where the programs only share the `;`.

```
1n;n-10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zDPOk/X0OD/fwA)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38BQN886z/D/fwA)

---

If we were allowed to use the fact that stdin is empty, this 5-byte variation of the second solution would be legal. [Alas, it is not.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/192979#comment459970_192979)

```
1n;ni
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/3zDPOi/z/38A)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/PzPPOs/w/38A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), <strike>10</strike> 8 bytes

```forth
1 . -1 0
```

Outputs: 1

**Reverse:**

```forth
0 1- . 1
```

Outputs: -1

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//GyroKegaKhj8Ty7iilEoSi1LLSpOTbHiMlAw1AVKGf4HAA)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
1     \ Place 1 on the stack
.     \ Output top of stack
-1 0  \ Place -1 and 0 on the stack but don't output them

Reverse:
0 1-  \ Place 0 on the stack and subtract 1
.     \ Output top of stack
1     \ Place 1 on stack, but don't output it
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 10 bytes.

Not very special, but it's rare for PHP to be short :)

```
<?=1#1-=?<
```

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I suspect the last `>` should be `<`.

Comment: This doesn't work when reversed. And with `>` changed to `<` it won't work at all because of "unexpected end of file" error. It would need semicolons to work which will be same as the version already posted in this post: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192982/81663

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), <s>8</s> 6 bytes (WIP language) (OLD)

No TIO interpreter yet, but is runnable by cloning the repository above, and calling `python main.py "code here"`.

Forward, prints `1`:

```
od12do
```

Backward, prints `-1`:

```
od21do
```

If instructions try to peek or pop at an empty stack, they are `nop`ed. In this case, instructions `o`, `ɲ`, and `d` turn into `nop`s when the code is run, depending on where they are.

Forward:

```
oɲd12dɲo
o      ; nop
 d     ; nop
  1    ; push 1
   2   ; push 2
    d  ; pop, pop, push [2 - 1]
     o ; pop, print
```

Backward:

```
oɲd21dɲo
o      ; nop
 d     ; nop
  2    ; push 2
   1   ; push 1
    d  ; pop, pop, push [1 - 2]
     o ; pop, print
```

-2 bytes for not swapping the stack.

Answer (score 2):

## [MAWP 0.1](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MAWP), 18 bytes

```
?.:M?%?00?;W590?.?
```

Displays 1.
[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%3F.%3AM%3F%25%3F00%3F%3BW590%3F.%3F&input=)

```
?.?095W;?00?%?M:.?
```

Displays '-' and then 1, which shows -1.
[Try it!](https://8dion8.github.io/?code=%3F.%3F095W%3B%3F00%3F%25%3FM%3A.%3F&input=)

Comment: Nice answer, +1. You are answering with MAWP 0.1 everywhere recently.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: All MAWP links are broken since Dion rerouted the website. It was too much manual work, so I've left most of my answers as is. You can test this here: https://8dion8.github.io/MAWP

Answer (score 2):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn), 3 bytes

Forward:

```
1-0
```

Backward:

```
0-1
```

Pretty simple, I'm looking for a more interesting answer now

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
-1
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=-1&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 2):

## [HBL](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl), 1 [byte](https://github.com/dloscutoff/hbl/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
+<
```

[Run forwards](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=Kzw_), outputs `4`:

```
+   Increment
 <  Three
```

[Run backwards](https://dloscutoff.github.io/hbl/?f=0&p=PCs_), outputs `-4`:

```
<   Negate
 +  Four
```

Found while exploring different answers to [Am I being run backwards?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/195551/16766), which is a superset of this question.

Comment: One of the not-so-trivial answers to this trivial challenge!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 18 bytes

```python
print(1)#)1-(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Ew1BTWdNQV6MkL7Oo4P9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```ruby
p 1#0~p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfnJ@Saquurv6/QMFQ2aCu4D@QzZValpijAJJBsPSKUstSi4pT/wMA)

Thanks Arnauld for chipping off 1 byte and making it less dull.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 5 bytes

```
ωＰ¹1←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//985/s9Gw7tNHzUNuH/fwA) Outputs `1`. Explanation:

```
ω   Print the empty string (does nothing)
Ｐ¹ Print a `-` without moving the cursor
1   Print a `1`
←   Move the cursor left (no effect on output)
```

Reversed:

```
←1¹Ｐω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5//9R2wTDQzvf79lwvvP/fwA) Outputs `-1`. Explanation:

```
←1  Print a `1` and move the cursor left
¹   Print a `-`
Ｐω  Print the empty string (does nothing)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
wṅ1?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v/zhzlZD@///AQ)

Prints the positive output with a leading zero. The leading zero is actually just a zero that gets printed separately, but...

```
w       Print the input variable.
 ṅ      Something negated
  1     is 1,
   ?    which is the input variable.
```

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/397w4c7W8v//AQ)

```
?       The input variable is the input variable,
 1      which is 1.
   w    Print it
  ṅ     negated.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Stax, 5 bytes

```
1PsPU
```

Not going to win any awards, but this one is refreshingly straightforward. Depends on input being empty.

Answer (score 1):

## Vim, 6 keystrokes/bytes

```
<C-x><C-x><esc>1i1
```

Outputs 1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/38ZZt8IOQqQWJ9sZZhr@//9ftwwA)

```
1i1<esc><C-x><C-x>
```

Outputs -1. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/3zDT0Ca1ONnOxlm3AkL8//9ftwwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 5 bytes

```
1#-10
```

Explanation:

```
1#    Push 1
 #-10 Comment
```

Reversed explanation:

```
01-#  Push -1
   #1 Comment
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-93 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
1-.@.1
```

*-1 byte thanks to @squid.*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1NNZNS0rK/P/fUFfPQc/w////AA)

Answer (score 1):

### [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/), 4 bytes

Simply abusing comments to remove a number.

```
1#1-
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31DZUPf/fwA)

Reversed:

```
-1#1
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X9dQ2fD/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

### [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
vo
```

o is a variable denoting 1, v is -1.

`0-1` is another 3 byte solution, but since it was already made in Python, I decided to make this instead.

-1 byte from Dlosc.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/LP//fwA)

Comment: You are learning Pip. Wow. Something I always wanted to learn but haven't time.

Comment: It is surprisingly easy.

Comment: The newline isn't necessary, so you can officially beat Python. ;)

Comment: I was initially using 1 and -1 instead of v and o. silly me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
u1
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=u1&inputs=&header=&footer=)

[!enilnO ti yrT](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?flags=&code=1u&inputs=&header=&footer=)

`1` pushes 1, `u` pushes -1. The last one pushed is automatically printed at the end of execution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fueue](https://github.com/TryItOnline/fueue), 9 bytes

```
(H)!45 54
```

Outputs `6`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SytNLU39/1/DQ1PRxFTB1OT/fwA)

**Reversed**

```
45 54!)H(
```

Outputs `-6`.

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##SytNLU39/9/EVMHURFHTQ@P/fwA)

### Explanation

[Fueue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fueue) is a queue-based language where the program is stored in a queue. (The program queue is also the only way to store data.) From [Esolang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fueue):

> Evaluation proceeds as follows:
>
> - Look at the front element of the queue.
> - If it is a numeric value, convert it to a character and print.
> - If it is a function, and there are enough values of the appropriate type directly behind it in the queue, the function and those values are popped, and the result is pushed back to the end of the queue.
> - Otherwise, it is simply sent to the back of the queue.

(There is another bullet point on the Esolang page, but it is irrelevant for this answer.)

I take advantage of the fact that the decimal representation of the ASCII code for `6`, which is 54, is the reverse of the ASCII code for `-`, which is 45.

In my explanations, I will be listing out the steps to evaluate each program, skipping a few obvious steps. The explanation to the right of a queue is how to get from the previous queue to the current queue, not how to get from the current queue to the next queue.

#### Normal

| QUEUE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `(` `H` `)` `!` `45` `54` | Starting code. |
| `)` `!` `45` `54` `[H]` | Put `H` in a block. (Note that the results of an operation are put at the *end* of the queue.) |
| `!` `45` `54` `[H]` `)` | Can’t be executed, so moved to end of queue. |
| `54` `[H]` `)` | Pop `45`. |
| `[H]` `)` | Output "`6`". |
| `)` `[H]` | Blocks can’t be executed normally. |
| `H` | Unblock `[H]`. |
|  | Halt. |

#### Reversed

| QUEUE | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- |
| `45` `54` `!` `)` `H` `(` | Starting code. |
| `!` `)` `H` `(` | Output "`-6`". |
| `H` `(` | Pop `)`. |
|  | Halt. |

Answer (score 1):

## [convey](http://xn--wxa.land/convey/), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

-1 byte if writting it horizontaly and not verticaly, (you save one line feed)

Prints -1 and 1

```
1-0
[}[
```

[Try it online! (old version)](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiWzBcbn0tXG5bMSIsInYiOjEsImkiOiIifQ==)

```
[}[
0-1
```

[Try it online! (old version)](https://xn--wxa.land/convey/run.html#eyJjIjoiMVtcbi19IFxuMFsiLCJ2IjoxLCJpIjoiIn0=)

I wonder if there is someway to work whit the direction of the conveyor when you reverse the code, i have been trying to do something like that but it changes also the output position `}` and the code doesn't compile :(

Comment: Another of the not-so-trivial answers to this trivial challenge!

Answer (score 1):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 4 bytes

```
O1~O
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv2@v4JmU4uQaFrOdLoTybQncZ1OZhs5G7vNdCUlAkFIYkMBCh@2U4n96917wReol9N8yIjAwX3h3Af8B72nMYuCZXIipM//ZiGNY@M/IpjNk@sokpHBHxMu/NhQX6ssB7yjUcyb@9qZEvU@FUmweBp3m0ScLlZMijiJUpbIyKJklcyD2IllGjHu0gx2guWHeZDweEkZt4r9BU3Y3Dr9aA1H49FwFMN61ht31t8NP47EuG2NxPoZIe1Tki05/wy7EU/SSBia8GF3vF6LNAyzXJhnM7dLViFPDOp6Dn/kzNLgpF@IwCOu69JL/NHTIa7224lTD2y3KKhxQi5myZzYdMjGJEskOB6I2U6rskyFw7j7/d31rTsc9/NQ/UbDlK/ihCYBM5Z4C5ZHVp6zFZ7@FKJ4TyPwodun50pMob9PO53cP@aq9SEdO6WsfjC1GCnsYZnmaxalQoU9kg@G4A85IzKfe@lsx/oe75QQp94E3CBdeDzagys3AfdKypBTsQdY7WYFq36BYEQ0rIiXh26DZHG6ROm2EvXJpwkFruWOakp2OFN81@d2eVJ8N0FbbpQLOox/CdG8AkGNAKymgnE5zb3W3Dg@1owHPua/yiig8CoERUi2@FNyvc6mu9djMnx58r9x@9Q@qyhPj4/xglGmZd6ZqI1kfrpYVs5MSmeeqfzMyCQLk3ntylFt6/ExbVzbTMcZOu6oCcxyMi/TeG7hKunnqXI9@O3N@5vB2@vBnbvKioR543ORbHDgKfeH9OTPT2P8v3vy4hOEYDMASigYmx1iU4AgYFMzPupoMA0Al4cox2GgwNxgJlCO5smwxowrauYG70FhBt/LwDe6R3g/peX9OkH1umxNfhWfhXwQRlBZZrQaprUmzZgrF0gZXy2630qvkd/ZDikEtEgXSjZJVWzUnKK@r3GlPF9zpkO10kEyqMEH4SdN@CIND8LbTbgf3Ote1lt4E41LKEW9pcncAd4Ipkk9Bb/3XZJ5RYWQiQGq4E4M76vxJ4@kCaZK/x/qrhV@T5/UB@LTUGr6lvLhsL5a/Hp9ZNHzLvkm59vtb/CePy6lQJLShCuDjERCbRR8Bny75wYYxyMwMtxTSc71e9tbby4aqAbxa9oPoCEe5r1WvSviD4qSSnLOo5BGCSkrCLbbjRwwEWwR81BnUPIK558IJZMLMJOrI45ZBeMfntKDg2tldKA5PhkcpJDnUq3nmK0xgTkuHt2O25dkdHZqP1e0wmgAszydSKABh5V8iKFOPtwh2GxhW2Lrdcts4Q9Su1QPrVj0wKpFIIBJvvEllUAoLphMcZn7PePZimaTXS1d2d/MI/usS9br7kbNKgaEQzULnZgUgELhdulBUK3LifiSU@g9egV6gvHVqHWQ8RVKv1RYLLornKL@7VfBejRzI/4lDSJumdPYJPYKR2S15WlbbB6E/qdlJBmPEfX618HV3ZubwW3dm19DDTjUmjWW5BcMk3klZuhpnU7dtDar9jVeXfZU1nXWDjnNGcNxnsb5GD98mI/9c1bOxn45G09dZZFTmoLKjqZ76PQ2gN4tZgaNZukCB45nK79zlhmgxJiil9BRPWykfZ4Hdkoy7Y4xEBazPZtvjBSwxDbGChTn0vy3oAvuevlvUB27bHt2VQcsx3EqVFVZ8ipuovYkkMIyO5XUKjyeUY6c6ijtuKZtmB3PyWVUXbxjbtWmG@8PzhIniBV/bRiXsmmhyoj4LIgTrlwkKwjtGfaq8oG08ZawzAGYZCxSGPI8SNRHypLwqwG9wGBzGsEXzCyhFDOoSf2aIHTseppGCEzVufSrLZIMXqCWp@UB0WtPPUbl743@ThqYA2nco2QolGnoo61KhX8EtVLLKgw4sasQmO9M2yLuRfEkM03bc1@l0ymPHBqGklkwgPsSg0StLjCiCxO5DZT34ElJPDD8c591wNUHyDhunUEXVjvqJedgbn0IIPHNkTAJYS5z4jCAF2LXNk7qyb6sNIxkumXvc8sarXsaSvD1h@cvfnjx47@fv/ixrVYjKny5wLDp569Nm7oXGDLaCG0Nab1sIaRK9Dy8hVWe3t3AgMvSzFySM43k4goYcCV9GDSLtxPplebq1@mwAvcywZlNN/KVMpLqS1f5UvG4VP/r2xO1XfWhpnN7HDX/qw4VBdHhj8FmFdewR5UC9dZqPoAayF8qJHqsG1Imk47@Cbl1UY1vjWCXlsWJL9PEeYigcYPAPM@JTRsxu2kKqrUW0szRSD0PC7IB0y73yC/ZCBDS24mZYG/814TY1cykW9IBimIRqa8LG23hW8P5ky0kvgt2IdtbSOzLu5CnW0j1GtiB/H5bptxt58ctpJq6dyDPK2RFlfIITgTVEf3Mxf4zs31nLvefwZK/88xxdcaiZV43/k5zWRzrNTJv/eQx2vO2M7KvHct37V0BczVYo7bgk3a9BpXa876ZyNQp3ueeW@n3GsI/VMJX2D37jaTtk41020nmN7kIaPruBd0ZLLbt@8/aIRW02m7bazzSbCz/2mdZwWj5V0oUsl6bZjNqt4UCX6koDz2hynf9bc0VuGz1ONZf0g5MlaUJ0OFIh3Vqkzo@9uK6YfzV0ite8@kOOIhOWUVgYrkfPodO@Df8uzn76@b/)

[Try It Online reversed!](https://tio.run/##lVhrc9s2Fv2@v4JmU4uQaFrOdLoTybQncZ1OZhs5G7vNdCUlAkFIYkMBCh@2U4n96917wReol9N8yIjAwX3h3Af8B72nMYuCZXIipM//ZiGNY@M/IpjNk@sokpHBHxMu/NhQX6ssB7yjUcyb@9qZEvU@FUmweBp3m0ScLlZMijiJUpbIyKJklcyD2IllGjHu0gx2guWHeZDweEkZt4r9BU3Y3Dr9aA1H49FwFMN61ht31t8NP47EuG2NxPoZIe1Tki05/wy7EU/SSBia8GF3vF6LNAyzXJhnM7dLViFPDOp6Dn/kzNLgpF@IwCOu69JL/NHTIa7224lTD2y3KKhxQi5myZzYdMjGJEskOB6I2U6rskyFw7j7/d31rTsc9/NQ/UbDlK/ihCYBM5Z4C5ZHVp6zFZ7@FKJ4TyPwodun50pMob9PO53cP@aq9SEdO6WsfjC1GCnsYZnmaxalQoU9kg@G4A85IzKfe@lsx/oe75QQp94E3CBdeDzagys3AfdKypBTsQdY7WYFq36BYEQ0rIiXh26DZHG6ROm2EvXJpwkFruWOakp2OFN81@d2eVJ8N0FbbpQLOox/CdG8AkGNAKymgnE5zb3W3Dg@1owHPua/yiig8CoERUi2@FNyvc6mu9djMnx58r9x@9Q@qyhPj4/xglGmZd6ZqI1kfrpYVs5MSmeeqfzMyCQLk3ntylFt6/ExbVzbTMcZOu6oCcxyMi/TeG7hKunnqXI9@O3N@5vB2@vBnbvKioR543ORbHDgKfeH9OTPT2P8v3vy4hOEYDMASigYmx1iU4AgYFMzPupoMA0Al4cox2GgwNxgJlCO5smwxowrauYG70FhBt/LwDe6R3g/peX9OkH1umxNfhWfhXwQRlBZZrQaprUmzZgrF0gZXy2630qvkd/ZDikEtEgXSjZJVWzUnKK@r3GlPF9zpkO10kEyqMEH4SdN@CIND8LbTbgf3Ote1lt4E41LKEW9pcncAd4Ipkk9Bb/3XZJ5RYWQiQGq4E4M76vxJ4@kCaZK/x/qrhV@T5/UB@LTUGr6lvLhsL5a/Hp9ZNHzLvkm59vtb/CePy6lQJLShCuDjERCbRR8Bny75wYYxyMwMtxTSc71e9tbby4aqAbxa9oPoCEe5r1WvSviD4qSSnLOo5BGCSkrCLbbjRwwEWwR81BnUPIK558IJZMLMJOrI45ZBeMfntKDg2tldKA5PhkcpJDnUq3nmK0xgTkuHt2O25dkdHZqP1e0wmgAszydSKABh5V8iKFOPtwh2GxhW2Lrdcts4Q9Su1QPrVj0wKpFIIBJvvEllUAoLphMcZn7PePZimaTXS1d2d/MI/usS9br7kbNKgaEQzULnZgUgELhdulBUK3LifiSU@g9egV6gvHVqHWQ8RVKv1RYLLornKL@7VfBejRzI/4lDSJumdPYJPYKR2S15WlbbB6E/qdlJBmPEfX618HV3ZubwW3dm19DDTjUmjWW5BcMk3klZuhpnU7dtDar9jVeXfZU1nXWDjnNGcNxnsb5GD98mI/9c1bOxn45G09dZZFTmoLKjqZ76PQ2gN4tZgaNZukCB45nK79zlhmgxJiil9BRPWykfZ4Hdkoy7Y4xEBazPZtvjBSwxDbGChTn0vy3oAvuevlvUB27bHt2VQcsx3EqVFVZ8ipuovYkkMIyO5XUKjyeUY6c6ijtuKZtmB3PyWVUXbxjbtWmG@8PzhIniBV/bRiXsmmhyoj4LIgTrlwkKwjtGfaq8oG08ZawzAGYZCxSGPI8SNRHypLwqwG9wGBzGsEXzCyhFDOoSf2aIHTseppGCEzVufSrLZIMXqCWp@UB0WtPPUbl743@ThqYA2nco2QolGnoo61KhX8EtVLLKgw4sasQmO9M2yLuRfEkM03bc1@l0ymPHBqGklkwgPsSg0StLjCiCxO5DZT34ElJPDD8c591wNUHyDhunUEXVjvqJedgbn0IIPHNkTAJYS5z4jCAF2LXNk7qyb6sNIxkumXvc8sarXsaSvD1h@cvfnjx47@fv/ixrVYjKny5wLDp569Nm7oXGDLaCG0Nab1sIaRK9Dy8hVWe3t3AgMvSzFySM43k4goYcCV9GDSLtxPplebq1@mwAvcywZlNN/KVMpLqS1f5UvG4VP/r2xO1XfWhpnN7HDX/qw4VBdHhj8FmFdewR5UC9dZqPoAayF8qJHqsG1Imk47@Cbl1UY1vjWCXlsWJL9PEeYigcYPAPM@JTRsxu2kKqrUW0szRSD0PC7IB0y73yC/ZCBDS24mZYG/814TY1cykW9IBimIRqa8LG23hW8P5ky0kvgt2IdtbSOzLu5CnW0j1GtiB/H5bptxt58ctpJq6dyDPK2RFlfIITgTVEf3Mxf4zs31nLvefwZK/88xxdcaiZV43/k5zWRzrNTJv/eQx2vO2M7KvHct37V0BczVYo7bgk3a9BpXa876ZyNQp3ueeW@n3GsI/VMJX2D37jaTtk41020nmN7kIaPruBd0ZLLbt@8/aIRW02m7bazzSbCz/2mdZwWj5V0oUsl6bZjNqt4UCX6koDz2hynf9bc0VuGz1ONZf0g5MlaUJ0OFIh3Vqkzo@9uK6YfzV0ite8@kOOIhOWUVgYrkfPodO@Df8u/nr7Ob/)

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
d;3
```

Boring approach for now. Will see if a 2-byter is possible.

Outputs `3`/`-3`. `c;2` and `b;1` are two alternatives for `2`/`-2` and `1`/`-1` respectively.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/F2vj/fwA) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9/YOuX/fwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
d    # Push builtin -3
 ;   # Discard the top of the stack
  3  # Push 3
     # (output the entire stack joined together implicitly)
```

Comment: Why does MathGolf have a builtin for -3?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle I have absolutely no idea.. XD It has way too many 1-byte number builtins tbh.. The ones available are: `-3` through and including `38`; `60`; `64`; `100`; `128`; `256`; `512`; `1000`; `1024`; `2048`; `3600`; `4096`; `10000`; `86400`; `100000`; `1000000`; `10000000`; `100000000`. As well as PI, 2*PI, golden ratio, `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.. All single-byte builtins.. In the mean time it's missing a simple 1-byte negate. ;)

Comment: Why not a built in for the Ultimate Answer(42), like AlephAlpha's esolang, Samau?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle Like I said, I have no idea why there are so many number builtins to begin with. ;) You should ask [maxb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/79994/maxb) who created the language.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 39 bytes

```c
main(){puts("1");}//};)"1-"(stup{)(niam
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///PzcxM09Ds7qgtKRYQ8lQSdO6Vl@/1lpTyVBXSaO4pLSgWlMjLzMx9/9/AA)

Corrected as @AdamBorkBork error spotting.

Comment: Darn! You beat me by... 4 hours.

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 16 bytes

```bash
echo -1 # 1 ohce
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzU5I19B11BBWcFQIT8jORUiAObrQgQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
2-”2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/30j3UcNco///AQ)

```
2-”	| push the string "2-"
   2	| push 2
	| implicit print TOS
```

```
2”	| push the string "2"
  -2	| push -2
	| implicit print TOS
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python REPL, 4 bytes

```
1-0
```

Only works in the Python REPL environment.

Shaved one byte based on suggestion from Ilmari Karonen.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As this only works in Python REPL, I've edited the language to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that!

Comment: Wouldn't `1-0` be one byte shorter?

Comment: It would, yes. I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Putt](https://github.com/ajmwagar/putt), <strike>3</strike> 2 bytes

```
N1
```

1. `N`EGATE
2. PUSH `1`
3. Prints implicitly

### Reverse:

```
1N
```

1. PUSH `1`
2. `N`EGATE
3. Prints implicitly

Answer (score 0):

## dc, 4 bytes

```
1p1_
```

prints 1

in reverse,

```
_1p1
```

prints -1

Answer (score 0):

## [ink](https://github.com/inkle/ink), 6 bytes

```
1//1-\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v/fUF/fUDfm/38A)

#### Reversed

```
\-1//1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8zL/v8/RtdQX9/w/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename: 6 bytes + content: 0 bytes = 6 bytes.

- Filename: `1.p.1-`
- Content: empty

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhtV9pI9/v@imEWyAwQkii2lnF0FW2XXaWuut1WoJ4IQaIhARIUBfrX@9w7SRCsz9mX01NmcufOfX8bu3bY//4z6UfRMKwaxo0b9SfX5U4wMD78ql8Mbee9/fDk@MZw6gzKwyB0p244MK694NoY2G4Md8sb5YHrL49/Cp2I6M5ETAZ2eEdMc2NDONNhMI7Ice1q//hY1gSLHocOuXGiTuD38nn1BVwHtt/lu0bXuTf8ieeRjd28lc8nl0/3L36VNMsSPKIPUwLqiGdnuBSri3ijL2jK9s9G/fPV@cWh3DDNzRR4@vG8/vn4y1Xt49nZUe1CWqJJdJ/Q7Oxg//zXq09HZ@f1j40qkCHtfH5GlFYBUVoK/CgeiMXyzuVrV5zBxLMjh4R9vBAMI9g9BONuOPTcSNiea4dEvyFadmYVafYXutCkhqsmGn8eH9dODmVVsQClkWFXhH23FynmXYKICcDp9AOS/ZlTIomFrJmChH0HbBgFAQm87m4eveBGxOLCubc9QjOkZ3uhQ@fzV9DJKr6SQOFM56HTJVpoTI1HQ4Tw82Roiu8Tac/noLKiBDg/sAVNwALevXz3ToALh67nMM560hQdO3SAg0WJ6xPWK3DSA28IJ7Q7wg5DZ3DtPaLjA/D5vk/0@2hizaMx0WshMa2NzcrWm7fb74jWbPmFtja/GTtDUp7bD3dEOzj6UG/MPGDSlZU3AqzLhmPXj3pEG54GH/2GW7/q1MLz@0@9987R@Ozhr@nnxy9Pl/Z@dDE46R4W9Uw2l9Pm/4F11pS01qQkaxLali1KwSRe8OCMWRiLwGiuQ0tZk3NCW1RQAYbUVGgwSkvnJVqlXKDoPRlKSkUvGDMBEe@5vkN6u6bgM7fHUkC4I02u8AAYoiVr@XxPyi6fHTEuFEtSa4ZtsXDA6wSx1OlDHz0R749ZjyM78ZJwfIKElDNNsVgs2fzIQHGIrxyzkAMAMRa9id@J3MAnx6yjZO9kQF4eRnbnrukVi23ZWUGCK4jj8VniMeolNvBAd0/XeQqHfwkN3WongoAdFgtNeUK/JwGEjwo@moZErHWi4y4o6Bel0XyYPj61Dd2wDbSAv2MmzGnZJgcVUo4R6Jx2bIhoiG26DG6FB75mMRW7bexR8guI5heBXBX0RJKB0snoGvl8xueJLWMIn02kr1silszfnay6V/kgESUWgjwYASnbr8ryUpdYOGon8gCGcp//L0imbocYFYndc2GrhbUvTVE6Z00Sm5noXkQ2sBIBpXnqBVuauECQZnsUd30AaGEBTDYM/E54P47aRoHZOxYvGs0iZJ4ef29w8I8zjcTCGBozICNCKBCLcMcS8D856sOuD4pHRiGTscViFsqM0ew5iTeEjUZxr9pG0fCAauO9DmyYDb4HATpgqGbghyAAAPsINAaGDscW7FJZxMKCJH2h5uaamtrstOkWzbbMgl@LRTGU8K1vQFIMv0EA5/PAfBaD5DAO3cl1GI1Z1ixtctF1PAcaxmlT1922iBWDi1890vxK2kW83zFmcIVRBcjSEs2TPC3FJP@WQBYphMbM1eXGC9z/c9NLbiieZMn0H3N8Fjy1IoQ@eDybwx0gMmLOiRmj8SzlswBtB9VzKKYy23gvyKPMxu4SK0KsijLkiB9gIk135COfXckpXH4Uj/JKLNasDZHLjFbR2JsWH6vg9L2pDmsG1gKsOVhzj1Vobq/rddQ4nGEJuoUQvN1xxW2xGFchQLttY3ak/RFSrVzIGoYWAwwwB9jQMLBpouQF45TluTBu4JvA4CWuoT@qPHCvIBN6zjgatMHuRh4qpyEikSY0gOIKAQd8pk5sBC7Utotb7HLYsnvLeUB1ZQ1zmJlcm8/j7y6QHjvRZOxj54m5FJGA3e2mXHX8Dq@j9DuD3zDWpN@tLAK67n0KyCmEICUQGuWC8dfFe0bzUAHBHC8kW7bjuCyfN@8kJA8keNoH@3Ef1GBKiNLKo6Gh58ury5bhsAM@u4OsAzJtCT/YD9BfB0DxYAeh4gBcBpvSQYIAmxfEUXRgwFWf7xIoclxAaoedsTuMZCIodj/H6X6jZWhgYxhH1edqkztlhxz1Kf3OeFseKplAtPUGF5s/8/tae/xteUDgYNdaOfr9@Uhp83xysXaCTFH55/PP7IzPziSgKUl0PXE9OVtBmrBa0hOYbu3AAFHb2dh6w/dqVeynS7QPSAssMPG/GWUDyU58MfFx@HgmmuyWLXYva1b1VV3@RGZwq7YC22cnaVPav4YpvQope/JaP1reGLJ0hMmAQfmEfYbflfMgHiNeP/RZvTQqHZa8Z5zZSAISzF2e499EfTbiKoLq0HDqO9ITdYifCWOHMqnbo1K9ZHH@jTZN/V2b7h0WK9vVyhYOPUs2Lshwyj6s875iJ6Va6bL0hc9OJC1fVUkjiLA@OTfOmIqaBHxxCWzVzBMPe5W3sVO2tvn12LHvsOLVoNZWmptbbaydl7JS0WvJ5RgFOz3bju9ZFehuNSk3saPGSPB@ilx/4ogF2j7Gru1UthFxd@st5wqsZHjmHjPgX@QXwmo6IAt0pjhll4Uvqzp2Vox/yi7WDRCuHH5eS4B7cMtt6RNXtRZMb0K230oV0uCEW7DFJ0zeUr0t1IKjI25u4@9bXW/LT6sOGK@wws0YXnGB7z3m8yATzlb7jJbHVQJbimpgAqik5gWMmDVnPjwnGpCDMgQYGSCxIv@U/VEaxRwhl3mCbYk/VGjFAZYA/9gZrVx8/BcXd1cvPi2FYvHVVK5E/CVitGKJPlbJdcsP4uM7HOz74DJEWT3vomdWUZIuiXjiDorKmsdUiapj3S1CLWKYOiDXbbzE9ZDz2HFSIaFHn5mpNoS8flPhA5IWX@QvNqb6EgVyDFgDio5oO@aeXq/W13ynGtcaxcILitjJRkk9@C2JFqYMD2Oip1aZxEu2Si6dcZBZRsxo19sbGV7VM0acr3KFbvgPaeZepZkDmjlFE1v79/eN/ZMjqVnlYdnSNTKf/5RAWubWVst8ow60n2ofGxdHjQv5PX0nZRUanSevb9KDH98eODCGvcB46BC9A/V25SSh9nwbC4fjR6@h/Hh9aYse2H/5Bl@58t8e2I0zNdTBvAhzFv5RR78jlj8uWekY9lVV5QJpsXKhxbMwdLUsHEP4gsJDBlu2VMOS3iHqr04TzPpggJMJAMc/AJ/F7FaI3qisIeBIEsJ5QIZut@RE7sApDTvDSek@fBJdO3L4qpqVv1czsl2P6H5lI1UHlGDl1my7tUBlWpahPb@t9A2r8rayvfmmsg2vEHjtgFXUwBoPqHb8dvv3dsYXW2wnXCg@@NJhiKYII9nScP14di41LR3msBa4MHm5OETga4h3mm5bLv/80WrlAlpyIf0aZ7ktU0orkTUkdPm2H8Fbb0Roy4cBJDnuNLNmO9YNx7BkAk@RIBL6RA@//w8)

`.p` is `until empty; do putchar pop; done`. `.1` is not a command; treated as a substring for literal.

Answer (score 0):

## [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), 10 bytes, with warning

```
1dnl lnd1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yzX5/98wJS9HIScvxVD3/38A)

---

## [M4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html), 16 bytes, clean output

```
1m4exit tixe4m1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yzX5/98w1yS1IrNEoSSzItUk11D3/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 5 bytes

```
+p;p-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7T1tl9M21t/zKzTOAvFMkokztEDKFCiFs5yzT8sBuvshhNaJlcSLYwe/MEyfefjrfe7Viy3JspMwsO12d04bEku6ku69um@6kreX@TqJz37rksHxgCySIIxXE1Lky8FdfNJxHKfzOKV@TgOSxOTVuiCPihXxzsjo7uT23cnZHTIejUedzkO/AEjphHzvxyGNOg/f0zQLk3hCvKE3hAo/bQMGBap7g9F4ML4NXyejEXny8hXrBv7wnzwhQTLpEPhjHwGdQ4fLIl7kAO6IP9z4bymMNl74OSkySt77UUEJ/NgmYZzTlIRL4qcrEmZkHvnxW9Lz44Dk2AoeLyN/lRHoSECY@4u3F34aZG4FPEqSbUZWNBewkyX5SOZ0maSUrKATgB1nYcArHrF2cowIeZWQZZpsyGLtp/gbRkVwCO/DBR0gavxqhlWnvgYDMJps/Dxc@FF0SbIcu/ZjmEDqXwJAsqGbJL1kYDfJe0ryNS3nD83xZ0w/iAlUndAIEJblQIwNjfPsAUlSKLicU/LPIstJnORa6f3BgFysw8WaLLDzBcwjM2GQHoMccmKwMTIkP3AFZfHzXREu3pJtmqxSf5MpFH4a/vrrze@KX3@9Ono2XZ288ObZjbPpaD6avxnNVje@gq8efv1u5gG7AEmxAdYnA@JHMNsYkPSeRpcTDVb2MvNeetn4@ZkK1KuAjkugbBgXCHpNoyghF0kaBezh1dQ7fzc7GmQn32bT1f0bH6ej8@272WqQfTv7eO5tgcB08ZYxU0Ypsl0Yb4scQW3TcEPJOs@32eT0FJYWXSXRcghYW7ylH4Ax4hUdLpLN6buCZkjz7PSrO197d07DbJCv4SMuNnOaDvwBgySGM3o3m25nI1gjFHqFapPDuvh6fOdsfBputhEjHUDPU1i5g42/WIex6IXgqjgQ7PhsdJoxuANoPRB0Jj3gJzohV1tEyQ8/vgIeR@CiuA9LauEj0yC3ctTBmgPk@WkGwuJiTYHPfWB2aI2cSTfb/JIv0@9uzm8Wy6UfJTfJ1bPz6Xw0BYrOvRkQ9gzoPJ6evZvNz05mtz8ZWWPv7vju7dOkyGFggznv7VP/5ah99nw0XW2ffzyYhD6O5u6de6f3vvr6jseAhScvflmMFqO/TE/C2cdPgHfvzu27CrzqY05zlCKchTkfck6nIOGvlqNvYFksZ9qqWJaLAkSGBCCpe5kUUnwUTJr5QYDaBoTFEustR8YAbB9XGfQ2OoEFAD3dP/6IvaHwuno2vl97TsjgWxDJ0GGShn5EekkUTDiQgYDCqkKT2cf7K4RPXCGp2MdTgMwYkksqzpsblJCAPSpVAbLtFYi/cLXmonPtv0cJeEmubgl1AjIBp3/hx9g@ykNYIhxc1pfy8iYKVR9ECPC9DyMmPZClF2EUGUpgwVRxpQVQ9rOlAisFVlV@uQX5DuoFtDqqqGydFFEAY62PpNR@NEaIoKaCARIkEDO9CPM1jk4gAfCXcv3AlGgSo0ZCPISgAjIcfVXXFdMir1mv@Ec/@CgZJuT1zW0CaiN5fXP8Wu0UJ3JJs5vjPqGAlts6RHjCkLECMU@mDlR0@gSqOhwY/3l7xroDGfNkgnRBbQn/xwlAXPiAGNTFwA@gfEmPDldD8jp2kX/eFQgFle7GT0GW95z@LRcgAEKRZ0Ex4pxjHJIQ7jGj8AUQoIgjmmUMrUFSzCPGEZthOfE3gHNeEPSrVRBBU1iqsLqQ6PAv0Gp@SVLkKSB2jr@LDD9fjD1mToAdkoYBWiHIcbCQsVdz4LDu2LwcJwcJ5jhX2HoA64D/7kgTCxcU/AV0yZmnhzRwFY28ipI5rBkUvOpvaZxk6sOUboEn1SdcXD7Kn8SB@jhPtj8uX6IcUp@iWeOvqPpI2DDqIzSyHidF@birPAeQqdb/okhTUG2Pk80G2OpZHNAPJixjaAteNTOr/S3Mclu9x8n20pwEDR7hktQeU1hi8HilPgTT6CmYRtqEgQHy70BL6JMWNcc7SWAb/g4kZG/D7atEfULj4KkAbo4vjGWJbSiiixqu6gN4aim3QVbRrLXZhhQYXx9anvwNKAVIzir@VZ@SczKdVUVGt1A68NQCbbxVW8tksXA661/7vxnpotJGCwfXdhRuQPaDIADJNcQFvxTE1rACnTfhX2BAmeFTH8z1qsygdL0CZw474lT8QA2ut7vlOtQfiSVbPpTeifwtFj/2NJqRYyJN8UpUlFXlcqxGpSw65aFccvDoh0TYs2IhaROVi0t7qCxEY/bsQxFsUPwqFV6VShjZLcdBkMS30CSIA1AMNE0TUD2cshc2A@fWrVuVrXGF0vcbSWSv/DYesj/584dvyDRHKxktKphUwR0ypv6424ZKkOOKOZWAyUUld7me3/gfkNPQvWLOYjZjbh@a69siW/OWzITsSxsFnoHG6ku74kqy7zJM0USSqrZf@UNciebrNClWa/645w7Js6VQ1iFaQM4VqHI2HzRo0JRh5lYm7a2Qu1b6oIbkRwRxEWa0j/qewVbWwtI2MuZBC8/CFzau6Bprs6INzddJwG0PMAO4qsOO0TbYoA2Qhzi4XjikxGNNWN20ACAX4Oq7aIVmW7pAE3Th4/hG@IhDygDjSLcQCYkakgNDDvE88SsHFR@5Oo9w5mLm8zmzoocAL/IXtOcQp@84vDoXlrJGto3CvOd8A4UiFBCiaOCVYPUZrBgue0AKiSNhG5SlogYWScBXjotr@PwcrA@lem01C7orFSojEZZhS8t6b1rd8oeYmVndm1mxpEzFOngmEnrVQFytNKV5kcZ15CAJWegnjJVJ6JChV1YFer31@vUto9/a9Ksf1Txev3b6EqN9z60B6NTRqsswLvo4R4h/wJ7fekz6ddH3GDALMVP8czCDmbMBS7H0L8qWY1Xu5ull1XHTZASJbir0QOzRiG7asKfBrtwMuug5PnTgkBM0rHsIxq0jRg6VycKs504d39HZCU3sbT5pbImAO2aBN/S3W1CvPVbLbZg7VrSup4jGKqchZ3hta6n6IReDOeoaluoYUjp0m7uyI8qGpK2fZZKhVMspq6SNN5nMRCE62UjmFOMSDAFlfVeZevlwGs4U0wd/1la1jloNA1zsMimUsyUPeHNtgoMPUSGNbAnmiEGREqY3qvcjvpwQz0qeqq0@aGlRQAl4foqBxwbd583cWnVhgNiaiK5cvZ@uKd36hNcuESwb9stOXENTdFHZyUJumwyVUiYJeSnSWVackG524W/ZbzBYQKdGYQxiJvKli8daa9TrMpQV0uDtCVjVnLomfrslQ5ZP2tpzlsSwPepeEm62CVi0W5ouf14ISxaEnzCEX2EVYYhyw1cp6Lna2q7wASZZBP62xZa@T5D7SywrXFYfcja1QFA42Qb/pMZlUglZKt9gtqCF26v6YprfiumfkK8sGozzl/NcBIMRrQGqoCH5PgxYPAT4A4Mb8BVk/ocQo2sxN4geOHW5PU@p/1adhcJpLD7JdQfwGtvjmaA1yDVeX/wLHKbbpzRfaGaPoiCVCUGB6hwcoX60WgqOM/wneDlqbUWuMl2sEcBuY3RkfMZYy0tc@2qkZptkWTiPqPB0nZE3Prv91dd37t77@MvDm28eDJ0uuYlrOKUZcwx8MEdBWjLLBA1SHsWrhHRMcS0mUDNZVv4Ex/AbFqZ7wDwKWcQRXep/3UXjnpvPHvG4E2kU@66O7TiB2aK0h1rqJF1TIYpOpebFNjrfiP6xoM3UFHCmAw81DGt0ojdSgKm161Yotwp7JT6OkQBuXRgoH0hrdZ2LWR4UJLNElrQQUqmOUVZpJr/P/OVFpfVKH@AN8wGgXEE7rw2flep9oxvUlcNdOsk6xm0eednng/36fGDtc7yz03G9V9k19nJkOAE1EwqHOLQMUR/qMkr8HAHqzFhnvKoJCoGqmbvbyjKHbvovvh4GsVX/WK@PwxAMNxVcNrOoMwXIL3YgptNkNntobyb6dC0dgpeAeEezlaFo0uUbWhlrzqMbMgymc02Dl2EIIQ50t58B9bghiuPlP9y9vAfNFjGsMIDTZzs4gvwGe0oR/X24QAn0vxps58SZ@EHQ1x8OnElWzHPUdEbJsTMRW1GXRsmpMwnC92FAjecXzoTtjf8Dt8aNshfORG5d9EkXkT5if2AJ4g6u2Cbj8ZcgXPEYDtur6nnnMPU@GZ/zXZA@OTtnS8AlA7ahPqdRcsFIFdDcDyOg9Bw0NAhUNFRxh4QBzPQBZTBxjHgZ41w5E9CnxsP7zkRw3PfJRWwUflsW/rQ1ip5DHzR/zkuNsi00S2OzpyNngsrSeLpwJnwjzng@xTmAZYVxbKNo5kxA1VkKbgBZk6CIEuP5XwAWWNvG0xRnIMKlTJcb5efOpFrCT94VIDONGj9L9AR/x7Dhs/gllxvWyjlOCIksg89GeR@RBsAeg232yByLD/yNkd5ncVjG7s0OHok6P4LF7vMKXb5NmpRPMFMFU12WLOkFhrNgMbZEX77OBhCJpR/a@nuJ@IvoIn8KLgOLQxsV5pK0r5LnlTloVPpOTPtRHLwAG81eKRSVngGuV7XSd87kXRHmwso2Cp@JtfAMgzdG2RIY6QNdFDltoEkA0gDzr6r9o5oHgX//p5jhLMKgCiv2wwVjygEX/UTK7hPHFbJYqzzFHzO3Upymt8nJZ2ZLoQ8q8rF88vf/AeGB@@V8dxOcthXIige8Pai2kJfkIdtSL2Bq6KLGMLKCQeMdd1lAnZm3Sv5TkmJtPU8LO2fxEYA2IOGQDlkmgA90XLCtXBFLxmwt4apAXSy4tbzFAvAo0XjWFLepKfr@KDOFr1V2x@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@fH1AIy/gNxkdYWkcxHyxVi47TDUMF4lhHFjLXP5ObPuRXmiYsol3VZ5GEsgUPFAgdHdBFuMG04DRBByBw2@DI2IQAJPKylHRSzOREMcPUHPXBV6AiwbCjbO0CUmp7uoioE4zbO7pxucmlCeSpJtAGicSkAFTAaK0rzQu90VhrhHTYo9GZ1ohHIi3NKsKz0QAhkA7nI93zMLI9oSdR0RT1RnaIDIGq29KkY8m30C0qhnngwbU0MKJkVRbOBWR4Vofe90aue8BoTr3R8XFvfuINxIRgfMe1Zx2BIbEEdmNHBEVHmJAsvhsOhTY0Y@felunRlCoA0CcDti5nCin5PD8rMWuos2ekaG3YcrQQiVSIbT0ngHOp4pRcInXZgz4/1cMT3t77aejLfS2OfW6tdTHFPCZvWD5@WrGQEI9/rY4HOcoikjsLZfsHu9sfGQAsFFcb9ck/mlqN6k3WlnGaO49W6McI9MRzXQte/UAiVOQalgl4ZcAkIyxdHSiHElIp42hhIW5WTbSuVbQznOBOVyHX@Xnz8igN0UZGOzkvqQPgVA6sbV20iaraDgeiSYbcBa7kTzZlJqYUtMhCxBv3kdowV9UuYX0ZBA52InDAEFgprM@LQr4DIRDIf/Apnkqqiac8SqYiAbNSxyrmRmIp9knZxKguEndE/QRTSdsb@HpG//VwfXouxtu0pPW6YrCNhDn97Jxt6HyxbSS5G6scn5dkEcXhYZRRW@1LnJY27fTpHkig4wMIdLybQMfmysEdPxXdR0y7s1SLz7aqFAKyzQBBPZEZLexaREFfSesEjyOnfkDk8UwZjFZTD7oMnEZs/MpJgSfSmtoJsSYlWzsUNsDYlgZheWS3rY5q2lXucUPpTLOQLPQz98P1@jJTR3GAuhmeYrXORxzNLo@sK8e2rajZG5DB9tdAjWFqVnjaZb6ZeKrYrtxGVZGEx9Yz7dx6sbXhwFaPMQVLBcma8mIaDSvM5hKAYPL37pmZXKJMC2jVMzfM0yyGR6IHGuq5IjsG0TiQ5jQSc0D2UIhCDdzxbqdHADX2owjW/Hw0GTWQZLAvSe7duz5NRi0kGRxKEhhQnQ5VBoFVdhi3ORgLXEVr1Y9IJXF3x8IqbkhjTXYxzyCrSylTAtkYo6ltswj/pHOhVc6M285W9vMbOrF4HVXOKdFLRBBuAqsIKjJ@@gjKwpiWB3x4zmlHBA2PCMYqMI@SowzvRggXoF5FIqpAzJMfn5Ie32AGHcwOVmM7ft@Kep8EOz/lth20bbBlbEc@6ls1OE@eraDOVDkjntW0jeRLK1/srYUs1G0naWsghEcva/lruxVXGxjGEvyIjAgvLfAEMDenRI6OtoDxoTjOCUVkQPRFwqicFjE/SXMrk7kLZYNQ8Iy4eyZWtD5wAsX0GlModPmVN2xLqceSEN64/DhbiD34mCDxnqaYah8uq7tbDjkzXCdl2yHpAyBbMlftmQu7kgGacgm0A6o7BlM7UnwY22oJgyosue8xleFY1ZbvE/m0xrpKmUyNdPuMAYcBpVv8Ihu5ktF3HQOyjmv0eQfRmLrK404/xfxcbMAPxg7J84iyfHTM3md7c@yAI@bX@HkeUdbpNqXw@XC18cMIbzFhXpJPluGH8pBmmGUFAM2SJD5y3HqOLyaWV8ylelFmXoGFT9xut6taLJqAwrwedhOHzHjk3uo8xatXcraRoiT5dBrzQtWQYt0@EV0qzFO3OthOGyniPIy4BxYl7DYJMZRafbE73na4hOVFW9Mx9jpw0lZxh02npcc2nMMUdK3j5s@FHCnnS@nNTluRuZ9xcyHLi@VSMbPAsMBot8hiw52sBI80w2xtCnEP/q@niri2I0V/qmVxvdyJg1nDkkuxs/a/xQr6N8Gj1U1qfsAzMnk2tmoClimcVgOQXfjBNBYrZrY0HvfXPCrypq/UYdf58Zu40NZmlwMwx2MZ8rsYata53d2yXX/TbhBZDbqGm3Asx5L29gA@r8m3K@3UZrrWTD@Za4L3J2GiyR7nL80msp9DGlsSQ2B9qjkdwo9TloO8PEQelfnFUc/b2vvUF1O7ijtvL6/OZf3iVLai7lJ52klIHOTH32uQH502Y9cc5sPfa5gPHYvd7Rq3ZlTn9D7nCEHYCi@4FhxxDYGosl7Ll9@dK9XljfJeO/3/B2DI2vi82R@KE2vjG89@D16sDeNsJvhyHy7sfBaDNZVBFtUa1y2qxgx5dR/Ra0sn3pd0qNusdWxWoK5b9krnx0IT6Tpo5cIKdVCKs1ybXLdMVUmpkXbbNa7V0bpgias213y3AdyKT8yCq3isvSrPhnM/3zo7uHMyMK77aTi3UMa9DFI015Yc0EQ7w76pzJv2GfaJ8zp23NoC1Ill0RXXTF3XGeGaPsj5NQF8ojr6c6LgII3350TBwUr1j4UGrpab1LFF0/6hfJT/WoP/KdagwnZ/DsPw2iu3/fhfc9P/GpT/OoPyd9ZS@vCvCetL2axP5XVNzYarkb7Krsc4KFGPN5FF1QIXoM5cFtvN1HyCG@TMPSxDeFeagwZ873RUo12ZmmoXM20NR/sfMIH6MifBdjoDLyLh@C/PvOGjpuRPzIItM6EC5V02Zprkbhh7BMd37/FbgtrNFKSb7Uu85bAhMXJ3ZmnjBaII1kaSeo9l2ubunNf2nurpQvrtMdZFxatUN1vYM9n0i/LVO7xZqrS6iFnH5rU0B61ntoKTlIz6YlMmTkiZR7brfFbbGh1Zz6lpVcR0zLRY6/U5yqR25sTtyJiyMNnINlZLvXIp82Qn9f4e9fSon2VdmQ3H32dRXSmICnlCllG4PU3xRm@8BXsexqdrkPY9dg/PW3xT1QXedM9SNIFKGXX7eEgz2eDNhfKFHd74a2jJ3sDCHmMCR58sfJr5KcnW4TKXr7WoLhJSeUOlt5aqyC5iFszCXtX1SQmPDIolo/s6iY47EhsX63oukWsjrV69actDOexVu21JRSTxPZmzL25YWrKDs5RdGxnReJWvVc63pbkDjJ/5Te5Z9UIbge15kueY3VM7Y0b8sa1N@RowYLwkZoWBHNBACJTy9K485cCT9GBo3lCvMjLKR0PyJMp4K67r1b6luIKftzKpZKru2V3xcny0z8HiOFlqBoxmgBXF7PAKuyCY8PzkPt6Jy27r7JP9@Mj2DpK9ro7UBXBHcgIng/E2hZzZ7OVFgTxzuXSetVQztb1Wm9mD1lQ1/WLD6oLiR7jWSnj6xqgckW7OsNPJ2iXvynBqy6lB/PH3Ulj0ZNvt75rIn5a9GpDqox@rtw6IV0rhdaxjrkHVqSg60joVrrnDfLEmZgYEFhlvzWjIj6/Qbb8HnUFRrzznPbq2azyUYnsKhzbiUf3WFGt6/a6pmsYMXx66w62hctSGx9F/8ajh0eqK26/WLQHrkuY/ApcNU27HqbwA2rjRUBzcK2IwtUJ8CUpHERZFphrcIoH/chGh1kHjCC9zF/bXyeD49EafvHjx5ClTM9RPI3ypaEARcT5etLHxP5xu8DJ48QXvbOKXWyySqNjEp2ly0Sc@AASZeQreMHZTbGpvEWtQVzWN02zqdMWwOTI6jXfgyitcTU3QcC6iDkO5V7t6i4H@0XyKxnJhpHFmxOoSHeHfzreGGUhsT04Tzpl2NeUh3kRDxwedytA1afl@iv2PDuqOq@2cinarpopqdsMAuw1YvluP39qOooQZFPisetOA7eQEs/VY8h3FF3KxdySybD68/xvfecju6SDl4fwqd1WBNhbgHijgAiCLDRbjjDKdD5@W0GIaymPPCFUkBXIR1@KmQEvdUzGbySRhi3G@x9vprvM6v103lauhXM/pi3sj5PTL2zZM0WFkBjeyaukP8VmJGKK4oL7hYKFSXQRPHIfYbgDp7IhHt44KA@PGyFoGZdZWTui2u428vtSS5ltgGvbmG1rqmWGq/63faNtwwFC8mUxfqHh3axKjJ8d0Uxs3tp4n/QxvbDBmXtkntiOEdlhg9mv3wFvBKYcxq3t@94pd1OOd4rRXviNcoax/RKHe7F94ONOMXzSit56I2KnrBuUm5LrOa8p0bhxhw9mNsXf7zu27Z1/fvlPTUNUlC@zG5foY9o4xW6Skivi6u51EwSt7TF55o47mm1a/Zu3e@OECdp@XeDU43bV3ax1wAnznEe9DxnbI@KxjbBHE@4xhn75rdwQceOT9S9HJevKiHhHXedasWl4vot7wUkbQ8AXN@t0iZIrWlwjOldeKMKeFGVr4useYXeuDJ2j5ldwkw9fdzMRNG8qRe3wurgvEeB57Lz0P7yGq8AQHq2GTsuJV7CBj/Q0ae1y35cZBD3lviGmgl6uuu5KbGeyeRGytjpkNi78SXAlJsrgivoVal43Ke9E6eLzyMX99pOM4r3872X6zHfzGXn2uFMmv0wmaIR3@qmj5EDT9b/8P)

This is pretty basic. Forwards, it will increment then print `1` (p- is an uncalled function). Reverse, it will decrement then print `-1` (p+ is an uncalled function).

Answer (score 0):

## [<>^v](https://github.com/Astroide/---v#v), 3 bytes

```
(;)
```

Prints -1.

Reversed:

```
);(
```

Prints 1.

#### Explanation

In <>^v, the stack is initialized to `[0]` (only one element, the number 0) at the start of every program. `(` decrements the top of the stack, `;` prints the top of the stack and `)` increments the top of the stack. So `(;)` turns 0 into -1, then prints it, then turns it back into 0. Its reverse, `);(`, turns 0 into 1, prints it, then turns it back into 0.

[Normal version (`(;)`)](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#635ff9390cd6402a30ea701e06ea6c9d20bb85f217ec4d97e433652922768c25)

[Reversed (`);(`)](https://v.astroide.repl.co/#91cb13cd04af5a4d38e0c5875f738c3cf8193ed700102ef0f5732b567c69b3bf)