# I reverse the source code, you negate the input!

Tags: code-golf, math, number, source-layout

*Blatant [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/192979/43319) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/43319). Go upvote those!*

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program/function that outputs/returns its integer input/argument. The tricky part is that if I reverse your source code, the output must be the original integer negated.

### Examples

Let's say your source code is `ABC` and its input is `4`. If I write `CBA` instead and run it, the output must be `-4`.

Let's say your source code is `ABC` and its input is `-2`. If I write `CBA` instead and run it, the output must be `2`.

An input of `0` may give `0` or `-0`, however, if you do support signed zero, `-0` should give `0`.

Comment: Why do we need a copy of the same question?

Comment: @Christian That one outputs a constant number (and its negation) whereas this one has to take input and return/negate it. A very different job in a lot of languages.

Comment: A yes, now I see the difference. One needs to read VERY carefully

Comment: If using a structured language like C#, are you just reversing lines?

Comment: @PerpetualJ No, look at the source like list of characters, some of which are line breaks.

Answer (score 25):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
-&0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/ddUM/mtypSZn5CukKZgowFiWllxcRallqUXFqSkKtnoKBmq6XBA5uKgJGh@o5T8A)

`-&0` is "argument minus 0"

`0&-` is "0 minus argument"

Comment: this is really quite nice :)

Comment: Clever, I didn't think of that one, but rather `][-` etc.

Answer (score 20):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>18</s> 14 bytes

```powershell
$args#"sgra$"-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V8lsSi9WFmpOL0oUUVJ938tF5eaSpqC@X8A) [!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkmZb/V9XSSWxKL1YSbk4vShR5X8tF5eaSpqC@X8A)

First of the trivial comment-abuse answers

Comment: Oh, God. Not *this* again.

Comment: "First of the trivial comment-abuse answers" Redeemed by the TIO links!

Answer (score 16):

## x86 machine code, 3 bytes

```
C3 D8 F7
```

The above bytes of code define a function that is a no-op: it simply returns control to the caller. That function is followed by two garbage bytes that will not be executed, since they come after a return—they are in "no man's land". In assembler mnemonics:

```
ret                     ; C3    
fdiv  st(0), st(7)      ; D8 F7
```

Okay, so now some troll comes by and reverses the order of the bytes:

```
F7 D8 C3
```

These bytes now define a function that takes an integer argument in the `EAX` register, negates it, and returns control to the caller. In assembler mnemonics:

```
neg  eax     ; F7 D8
ret          ; C3
```

So…that was simple. :-)

Note that we can make the "negation" instruction be *anything* we want, since it is never executed in the "forward" orientation and only executed in the "reversed" orientation. Therefore, we can follow the same pattern to do arbitrarily more complicated stuff. For example, here we take an integer argument in a different register (say, `EDI`, to follow the System V calling convention commonly used on *nix systems), negate it, and return it in the conventional `EAX` register:

```
C3      ret
D8 F7   fdiv  st(0), st(7)      ;  \ garbage bytes that
F8      clc                     ;  | never get executed,
89      .byte 0x89              ;  / so nobody cares
```

↓ ↓

```
89 F8   mov  eax, edi
F7 D8   neg  eax
C3      ret
```

Answer (score 15):

## JavaScript, 11 bytes

```
n=>n//n->=n
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1i5PXz9P1842739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahomm5n8A) | [Reversed](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/P1k43T18/z842739yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahomm5n8A)

Answer (score 12):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
oN
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/f7////7qmAA)** and [its reverse](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98v/////7qmAA).

```
oN - (input) OR ((input) negated)

No - ((input) negated) OR (input)
```

Comment: Heh, you can also do `ḷN`, no need for the OR logic. :D

Comment: `Na`, words give `aN` aesthetic effect :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 8 bytes

Anonymous identity function, turning into subtraction from `0` when reversed.

```hs
id--)-0(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5uZV5JalJhcolKckV@ul6anUZSamGJlFVxSlJmXrmvnmVeiyZVmqxDzPzNFV1dT10Dj/3@Tf8lpOYnpxf91I5wDAgA)

Reversed:

```hs
(0-)--di
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ5uZV5JalJhcolKckV@ul6anUZSamGJlFVxSlJmXrmvnmVeiyZVmqxDzX8NAV1NXNyXz/3@Tf8lpOYnpxf91I5wDAgA)

Comment: You’ve managed to break the code highlighting with your reversed version!

Comment: @Tim Curious. Testing suggests it fails when a comment starts right after a right parenthesis.

Answer (score 8):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 48 bytes

```
S S S N
S N
S T N
T   T   T   T   T   T   N
S T N
N
N
T   S N
T   N
S S T   N
T   T   S S T   T   T   T   T   N
T   S N
S N
S S S
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.

Minor modification of [my Whitespace answer for the *I reverse the source code, you negate the output!* challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192993/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4wQDE4uLiVOACssCCQBIszglWpqDw/7@hAQA) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##K8/ILEktLkhMTv3/X0FBgQsIObk4QUBBgRPIAgpxgoS4gEyIOEgQpExB4f9/QwMA) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation:**

Utilizing the *Exit Program* builtin being a short palindrome `NNN`.
The regular program will:

```python
SSSN   # Push 0 to the stack
SNS    # Duplicate it
TNTT   # Read STDIN as integer, and store it at heap address 0
TTT    # Retrieve the input from heap address 0, and push it to the stack
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

The reverse program will:

```python
SSSN   # Push 0 to the stack
SNS    # Duplicate it
TNTT   # Read STDIN as integer, and store it at heap address 0
TTT    # Retrieve the input from heap address 0, and push it to the stack
SSTTN  # Push -1 to the stack
TSSN   # Multiply the top two values on the stack together
TNST   # Pop and print the top of the stack as number
NNN    # Exit the program, making everything after it no-ops
```

Small additional explanation of pushing a number:

- First `S`: Enable Stack Manipulation
- Second `S`: Push a number to the stack
- `S` or `T`: Positive/negative respectively
- Some `S`/`T` followed by a trailing `N`: number in binary, where `S=0` and `T=1`

I.e. `SSTTSTSN` pushes `-10`. For the `0` we don't need an explicit `S=0`, so simply `SSSN` or `SSTN` is enough.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 23 bytes

I decided to give it a go without the comment trick.

#### Forward

```r
`+`=scan;""+-0;nacs=`+`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7wbY4OTHPWklJW9fAOi8xudgWKPbf9P9/AA)

#### Reverse

```r
`+`=scan;0-+"";nacs=`+`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P0E7wbY4OTHP2kBXW0nJOi8xudgWKPbf9P9/AA)

In the forward version `+` is acting a binary operator, and `-` is a unary operator.

In the reverse the `+` becomes unary and the `-` is binary. So scan function takes the arguments: `file=""` which means stdin and `what=0`, which are also defaults. So when the `+` is unary the first argument is on the right, when it is binary the first argument is on the left.

The

```r
;nacs=`+`
```

part of the code does nothing really useful, so in a sense my code is not really very much more valid than using the comment trick.

Comment: This is very smart (+1). We often redefine the R operators to golf bytes, but I think this is the first time I have seen `+` redefined to be used as both unary and binary. It took me a minute to understand how this was parsed… No other operator name would have done the job.

Answer (score 6):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 23 bytes

```c
f(*x){}//};x*-=x*{)x*(g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYrLCoAgEEX3fsUQFOOQuA7xT9qIoQQlES0GxG@3F23bnXvO9covLsVaAxLLXLQuhklZpiyZMNb4eGKriE0RYk4HrG5OKLMAuBfbYTAXAwTsWL647VcKgE07janpPx1/H6We)

Answer (score 5):

## [Labyrinth](https://github.com/m-ender/labyrinth) / [Hexagony](https://github.com/m-ender/hexagony), 6 bytes

Labyrinth:

```
?!@!`?
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fXtFBMcH@/39dUwA)** and [its reverse](https://tio.run/##y0lMqizKzCvJ@P/fPkHRQdH@/39dUwA).

Hexagony:

```
?!@!~?
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/99e0UGxzv7/f11TAA)** and [its reverse](https://tio.run/##y0itSEzPz6v8/9@@TtFB0f7/f11TAA).

#### How?

```
?       - take a signed integer
(` / ~) - negate
!       - output top-of-stack / current-memory-edge
@       - exit
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) / Raku, 3 bytes

```perl6
*-0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPtfS9fgvzUXF5Crlq5gq2Cgq8UF5BYngqQ1jDStwcx0BSNrmJgpXMzU@j8A)

Creates a Whatever code block.  Read in normally its standard block equivalent is `-> \x {x - 0}`, but in reverse it becomes `-> \x {0 - x}`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 22 bytes

```python
lambda x:x#x-:x adbmal
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqkK5QteqQiExJSk3Med/QVFmXolGmoalpuZ/AA)

A lambda which implements the identity function (or negation)

Answer (score 4):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 2 bytes

```
_@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P97h/39TAA)

```
_	| implicit push input and negate
 @	| push next input OR push last input (when all inputs have been pushed)
	| implicit print TOS
```

Reversed:

```
@	| push input
 _	| negate
	| implicit print TOS
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 7 bytes

```
#)]}{[(
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X1kztrY6WuP/f2MA)

Reversed:

```
([{}])#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyO6ujZWU/n/f2MA)

Note: Only works in interpreters that support comments (e.g. works in Rain-Flak, but not in BrainHack)

---

If we also swap opening/closing brackets instead of just reversing the bytes we can do this in 8 bytes without using comments:

```
({}[{}])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O6Nrq6Nlbz/39jAA)
[Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XyO6uja2ulbz/39jAA)

Comment: Is this undefined behaviour abuse? I don't think Brain-Flak specification allows such parenthesis.

Comment: @TwilightSparkle The `#` starts a comment, so the parenthesis in the original version are ignored.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot! But it only works in Rain-Flak then(It's the official intepreter though). You will probably need to mention it?

Comment: @TwilightSparkle added a note for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Fun little challenge: Can you do this without comments if you also swap opening/closing brackets instead of just reversing?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem My first idea came out to 10 bytes: [`({}<>[{}])`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X6O61sYuuro2VvP/f2MA)

Comment: I came up with nearly the same thing: `({}[{}])`

Comment: Yep. Just realized the `<>` doesn't do anything

Answer (score 4):

## Perl 5 (`-p`), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

-1 thanks to @primo

```
$_*=$#
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXstWRfn/f5N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

A comment doesn't change input

```
#1-=*_$
```

Negate the input

```
$_*=-1#
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/ZUNdWK17l/3@jf/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: -1: `$_*=$#` [TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXstWRfn/f5N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA). Note that the `#` must be the very last byte of the program, otherwise it will be interpreted as the variable `$#`, rather than the last index of the array with name <empty>.

Comment: however i don't understand how it works because trying to print `$#` gives either an error (if # is not the last character) or nothing

Comment: Seems to only work with `-p` or `-n`. I suspect the boilerplate has something to do with it...

Comment: @primo It works because `-p/-n` adds a `;` after the code. Which means that `$#` is actually `$#;`: the size of the array `@;`. If the size of `@;` changes, the result isn't correct anymore ([TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9/B2lbDUMdIx1jTmkslXstWRfn/f5N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")). Anyway, this is super clever, well done! :)

Comment: that's the explanation could be seen with `perl -MO=Deparse -p <(echo -n '$_*=$#')`, because it seems `perl -MO=Deparse -pe '$_*=$#'` adds a newline

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 14 bytes

```r
scan()#)(nacs-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzg5MU9DU1lTIy8xuVj3v@n//wA)

A full program that reads a number, or reads and negates a number. The reverse functionality is protected by an inline comment

Comment: Your brackets are the wrong way around in the commented part.

Comment: @AaronHayman thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Backhand](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Backhand), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
I@-Ov
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/9/TQde/7P9/QwMA) [Try it doubled!](https://tio.run/##S0pMzs5IzEv5/7/MX9fB8/9/QwMA)

Made a little complex due to the nature of the pointer in Backhand. <s>I don't think it's possible to get any shorter</s> haha, turns out I was wrong. This duplicates *no* instruction and reuses both the input, output and terminate commands between the two programs. *Now* I think it is optimal, since you need all of the `IO-@` commands to work, and in a 4 byte program you can only execute two of those commands.

#### Explanation:

The pointer in Backhand moves at three cells a tick and bounces off the boundaries of the cell, which means the general logic is overlapping. However you can manipulate this speed with the `v` and `^` commands.

The original program executes the instructions `IO-@`, which is input as number, output as number, subtract, terminate. Obviously the subtract is superfluous. In the code these are:

```
I@-Ov
^  ^    Reflect
  ^     Reflect again
 ^
```

The reversed program executes `v-I-vO-@`. The `v` reduces the pointer steps between ticks, and the `-` subtracts from the bottom of the stack, which is implicitly zero. The extra `-` commands do nothing. The program executes like

```
vO-@I
v       Reduce pointer speed to 2
  -     Subtract zero from zero
    I   Get input as number and reflect off boundary
  -     Subtract input from zero
v       Reduce pointer speed to 1
 O      Output as number
  -     Subtract zero from zero
   @    Terminate
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MarioLANG](https://github.com/tomsmeding/MarioLANG), 22 bytes

```
;:
=#
:)!
--
<(
"
[>
;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///f2orLVpnLSlORS1eXy0aDS4kr2o7L@v9/QwMA)

He just inputs and outputs the number before he falls to EOF

reversed:

```
;
>[
"
(<
--
!):
#=
:;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syszPScxL///fmssumkuJS8OGS1eXS1HTikvZlsvK@v9/QwMA)

He loops until the input value is 0 and the output value is -input, the he says the number.

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, 12 bytes

```
f=id;x-0=x f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P802M8W6QtfAtkIh7X9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagul/AA) Reverse:

```
f x=0-x;di=f
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwtZAt8I6JdM27X9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKagul/AA)

Not as short as [Ørjan Johansen's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193054/34531), but without comments.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>22</s> 14 bytes

```python
int#__bus__. 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPzOvRDk@Pqm0OD5eT8Hgf0ERUEAjTcNYU/M/AA)

Uses the `int` class's constructor and a built-in pseudo-private method.

Comment: Huh. Why is the space before the attribute mandatory?

Comment: @JoKing `0.` would be interpreted as a number, which is followed by a symbol

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> 3 bytes

```apl
-∘0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////3/ao7YJuo86ZhhwpQNZBkCW7v80BUOudAVDAA)

Trivial answer. Returns `arg` or `¯arg`.

Saved 10 bytes by not being dumb (thanks Adám).

Altered the resulting 3-byter to a more fitting function.

Comment: Whoa, this can be done trivially in three bytes!

Comment: Interestingly, you already have a 3-byte answer embedded as a substring of this.

Comment: @Adám yeah, I knew there was a simple answer in there somewhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 9 bytes

```
1&0+#-0&1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2ar9N9QzUBbWddAzfC/EldAUWZeSbSyrl11SL5rRUFRanFxZn5edFqsg7IOikhwCVBlelBqWWpRcaoDSL42Vk3fISgxLz3VwdDgPwA)

Forward: read `((1)&*0+#-0)&*1`=`#&`

Backward: read `((1)&*0-#+0)&*1`=`-#&`

Answer (score 3):

### Excel VBA, 12

```vb
?[A1]']1A[-?
```

Reversed:

```vb
?-[A1]']1A[?
```

Input is cell A1 of the ActiveSheet.  Comments still work in the Immediate Window :)

Comment: I get what you are going for here, but I am pretty sure that you meant to answer `?[A1]']1A[-?`

Comment: @TaylorScott A good catch, oops

Answer (score 3):

## Batch, 34 bytes

```
@ECHO.%1 2>MER@
@REM>2 1%=-aa/TES@
```

Echoes (`ECHO.`) the input (`%1`). The rest of the first line technically redirects `STDERR` to a file called `MER@`, but this isn't impactful.
Second line is commented out (`REM...`).

#### Reversed

```
@SET/aa-=%1 2>MER@
@REM>2 1%.OHCE@
```

Uses the arithmetic mode of the set command (`SET /a`) to subtract (`-=`) the input (`%1`) from an undefined variable (`a`) which is equivalent to `0 - input`. Again, the rest of the first line technically redirects `STDERR` to a file called `MER@`, but this isn't impactful.
Second line is commented out (`REM...`).

Comment: This looks interesting. Care to explain?

Comment: @Adám Added an explanation, and also realised that I had the programs around backwards.

Answer (score 2):

## [Triangular](https://github.com/aaronryank/triangular), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
$%%.|.$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0VVVa9GT@X/f1MA)

Ungolfed:

```
   $           | $: Read an Integer
  % %          | %: Output it
 . | .
$
```

Reversed:

```
$.|.%%$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLPr/X0WvRk9VVeX/f1MA)

**Previous Version (8 bytes):**

```
$.%..|.$
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
(I
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fU@P/f1MA)

[Reversed](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fU@P/f1MA)

```
(    negates nothing
  I  pushes input

I    pushes input
  (  negates input
```

Comment: It is supposed to only negate the input in one direction, leaving it as-is in the other. Clearly, 1-character solution cannot be valid.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood

Comment: Your answer has a couple mistakes. First of all, the explanation for `(I` is slightly flawed: it doesn't negate nothing, it negates the (implicit) input. But pushing the input with `I` means the output is the input instead. Your other problem is that both links you put link to `I(`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 6 bytes

```
&.@.-&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X03PQU9X7f9/QwMA) [Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X01Xz0FP7f9/QwMA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Klein](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Klein), 2 bytes

*Works in all 12 topologies!*

```
@-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/99B9////wYGBv8NAQ)

## Reverse

```
-@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y85Jzcz7/1/X4f///wYGBv8NAQ)

`-` negates the input and `@` ends the program

Comment: Oh come on. This question seems to be _made for_ some clever flipping on the Möbius strip or so, and you submit an answer that doesn't depend on the topology? Meh.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen _that_: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192983/2183

Answer (score 2):

## [Turing Machine Language](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html), 39 bytes

[The Positive](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?3fbc2a79501a4424cbbb52ae008e684f)

```
1 r - _ 0
0 l * * 0
0 - _ l 0
0 _ _ r 0
```

[The Negative](http://morphett.info/turing/turing.html?2742e8faf2421c7f508801f64b69090b)

```
0 r _ _ 0
0 l _ - 0
0 * * l 0
0 _ - r 1
```

This one was a bit trickier than I thought, mostly because I had to get past my prejudices of having code that runs with 'compile' errors.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
n-r0
```

uses stack initialisation with the `-v` option, put your input variable there.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/P09L19Dg////umUKhgYA)

[Or try the reversal](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38BQVyvv////umUKuoYA)

**Explanation**

```
n       Prints whatever is on the stack as a number
 -      Subtract the top 2 elements on the stack.
        There aren't 2 elements, so it crashes.
  r0    Never gets executed

or reversed:

0       Push a 0 onto the stack
 r      reverse the stack (now 0, -v)
  -     Subtract top 2 elements and push result (0-v, ie negated)
   n    Print as number
        The code wraps around and executes again. 
        It crashes on the - as there is only one
        item on the stack: 0.
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) `-mn`, 2 bytes

```
-X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v9fN@L/f9P/url5AA)

[Try the reverse!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v8/Qvf/f9P/url5AA)

#### Explanation

Turns out this is actually a lot easier than the previous challenge in Stack Cats. The full program (after applying `-m`) here is `-X-`. `X` is used to swap the stacks left and right of the tape head, i.e. it doesn't affect the initial stack at all, so we can ignore it. But then the program is effectively just `--` (negate the top of the stack twice), which does nothing.

For the inverse program, applying `-m` gives `X-X`. Again, `X` does nothing, so the program is effectively just `-`, which negates the top of the stack.

The only other 2-byte solution is `-=`, but it's virtually the same. The only difference is that `=` swaps only the tops of the adjacent stacks, not the entire stacks.

But again, using `-m` feels a bit like cheating, so below is a solution that uses a fully mirrored program.

---

### [Stack Cats](https://github.com/m-ender/stackcats) `-n`, 7 bytes

```
:I<->I:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v/fytNG187TCkxzAYl4rhoQqwbECgGxgET8f13D/7p5AA)

[Try the reverse!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTiwp/v/fytNO18bTCkjb6HIBiXiuGhCrBsQKAbGARPx/XcP/unkA)

#### Explanation

The considerations [from the previous answer still apply](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193215/8478): any valid solution needs to use the paired characters and `I`. The six possible solutions (included in the TIO link) are all virtually the same. `-` and `_` are equivalent in this program, and `:` can be replaced by `|` or `T` (which do the same for non-zero inputs and coincidentally also work for zero inputs). I've just picked this one to explain because it's easiest.

So remember that the initial stack holds the input on top of a `-1` (on top of infinitely many zeros) whereas all the other stacks along the tape only hold zeros. Stack Cats also has the property that any even-length program does nothing (provided it terminates, but we can't use loops for this challenge anyway). The same is then obviously true for any odd-length program whose centre character does nothing... let's see:

```
:    Swap the input with the -1 below.
I    Move the -1 one stack to the left and turn it into +1.
<    Move another stack left (without taking the value).
-    Negate the zero on top of that stack (i.e. do nothing).
```

Therefore, the second half of the program exactly undoes the first half and we end up with the input on top of a `-1` again.

The inverse program is `:I>-<I:`. Let's see how that changes things:

```
:    Swap the input with the -1 below.
I    Move the -1 one stack to the left and turn it into +1.
>    Move one stack right, i.e. back onto the initial stack which still holds the input.
-    Negate the input.
<    Move back to the left where we've parked the 1.
I    Move that 1 back onto the initial stack and turn it back into a -1.
:    Swap the -1 below the negated input to act as an EOF marker.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
&ṅ
```

Brachylog implicitly inputs from the left and outputs from the right.
`&` ignores anything to the left and passes the input to the function rightwards.
`ṅ` constrains each side of it to be negated versions of each other.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X@3hztb//w2NDP77h4YEhIYAAA)

Answer (score 2):

### [W](https://github.com/a-ee/w), <del>3</del> 2 bytes

Pretty much a port of the Keg answer. Might get around to implement an implicit return.

```
%_
```

### Explanation

```
   % Since there is nothing on-stack, return the input.
%_ % Start a comment
```

### noitanalpxE

```
_  % Negate input & return
 % % Start a comment
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
#N
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%23N&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

[!enilnO ti yrT](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=N%23&inputs=42&header=&footer=)

`#N` is a comment, so nothing happens and the input is outputted unchanged.

`N#` negates the input, which is then outputted implicitly.

If you’re not a fan of using comments for something like this, the `#` can be replaced with any of `? , ₴ ⁰`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 15 bytes

```
/O\ /I@
@I/R\O/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fP0ZB39OBy8FTPyjGX///f3MjY0MA)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fPyZI39OBy8FTXyHGX///f3MjY0MA)

### Flattened

Original `I O@`, reads from the input, output
Reversed `IRO@`, reads from the input, negate, output

The mirrors switches in and out of ordinal mode, which execute the code in diagonal

Answer (score 2):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 11 bytes

```
\ X'@
/I-O/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/z9GIULdgUvfU9df//9/cyNjQwA)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fX9dTn8tBPUIh5v9/cyNjQwA)

Operates entirely within ordinal mode. The negation is done by taking string symmetric difference `X` with the single-char string `"-"`. The code path `IXO` is common; when reversed, `'-` is also stepped, pushing `"-"` before the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
TnU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VG5V&input=NA) | [Reversed](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VW5U&input=NA)

Same method as [my earlier solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/192997/58974), with `T` being `0` and `U` being the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 5 bytes

```
É-ó--
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v//3Cn7uHNurr//@uaAAA)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: c92d f32d 2d                             .-.--
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 29 bytes

```cpp
#define f(x)x//x-)x(g enifed#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv6vnJmXnFOakqpgk5lfXFKUmphr9185JTUtMy9VIU2jQrNCX79CV7NCI10hNS8zLTVFGS6bDpTVBUkDZdNgsupcXJl5JQq5iZl5GprVXApAUFySYmWVnF9aomBjAzTSxEgTxFCKyVOyxpRPR5Wv/Q8A)

Fixed issue brought up by @Nick Kennedy

Comment: This is shown the wrong way round; it should return the input when called without reversing the code.

Comment: Is `#define f//- f enifed#` (call as `f x`) cheating? ;)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 2 bytes

```
pN
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=pN&i=5)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
-*$1#$
)^(|-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fV0vFUFmFSzNOo0b3/38jLkMuAy5dIDLk0jUCAA) It's impossible for the first line to match anything, so nothing happens. In reverse:

```
-|(^)
$#1$*-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX7dGI06TS0XZUEVL9/9/Iy5DLgMuXSAy5NI1AgA) Explanation: Either a leading (implicitly) `-` or a leading empty string is matched. This is replaced with `-` repeated according to the number of empty strings that were matched.

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @MartinEnder (although, cunningly, the reversed original worked with floating-point numbers in scientific notation). As he points out, Retina 1 would be a further byte shorter as its syntax for `*` is slightly different and does not require the adjacent `$` (and it would therefore also modify illegal inputs such as `-1#` which this version ignores).

Comment: I don't think you need the `^` at the end. Also, Retina 1 would save a byte on `$*`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) -p , 7+1 = 8 bytes

```ruby
#-?<<>$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X1nX3sbGTuX/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Reverse:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxsZeV/n/f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 20 bytes

```php
<?=$argn;#;ngra$-=?<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt5WJbEoPc9a2TovvShRRdfW3ub/f6N/@QUlmfl5xf913QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
*b╘k
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/18r6dHUGdn//xsaAAA) or [try it online reversed](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/z/70dQZSVr//xsaAAA).

**Explanation:**

Regular:

```python
*     # Multiply the (implicit) input with the (implicit) input
      #  STACK: [input**2]
 b    # Push -1
      #  STACK [input**2, -1]
  ╘   # Discard everything on the stack
      #  STACK: []
   k  # Push the input as integer
      #  STACK: [input]
      # (output the entire stack joined together as result)
```

Reversed:

```python
k     # Push the input as integer
      #  STACK: [input]
 ╘    # Discard everything on the stack
      #  STACK: []
  b   # Push -1
      #  STACK: [-1]
   *  # Multiple the (implicit) input with this -1
      #  STACK: [-input]
      # (output the entire stack joined together as result)
```

And to answer your question: no, MathGolf does not have a 1-byte negate for integers. There is `~` for `-n-1`, but unfortunately nothing for `-n` (so `*b` could alternatively be `)~` for the same byte-count).

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
n U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=biBV&input=NA)

[Try it reversed](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=VSBu&input=NA)

## 3 bytes

```
nÎN
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=bs5O&input=NA)

[Try it reversed](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Ts5u&input=NA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 5 bytes

```
@IO\n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/9/B0z8m7/9/UwA)

[Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/z8vxt/T4f9/UwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 6 bytes

```scala
+_//_-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnUM2VkpqmkAtkaiQWpRdbKTgWFSVWRgeXFGXmpcdqWimE5mWWKNgC1ZUl5ihUWGl45pXY2gEJTdv/2vH6@vG6/8EyRallqUXFqSnICrh0QQq0ubgKgIaV5ORpVGgYamrCeTAtYEEkNSbY1JigqtE1wqYILIqkygCbIpAgV23tfwA)

Unfortunately a function can't just contain a `_` to return the first argument, but using `unary_+` will return the value unchanged.

Once flipped, the code is `-_` which does a `unary_-` on the first argument, which flips the sign.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `_//_-`? However, `_-0` seems like a valid solution.

Comment: @Adám It should be `+_//_-`. Unfortunately can't have `_` as the body of the function, but doing `+_` returns the value unchanged. Thanks for point it out!

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 4 bytes

```
Ih-I
```

One byte golfed off courtesy of JoKing

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/3zND1/P/f0MA)

Comment: @JoKing Thank you very much, is that a negate operation? I honestly forgot that there was one

Comment: @JoKing Ohhhhh, I didn't know that, thank you very much for enlightening me on that operation

Answer (score 1):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 4 bytes

```
i@Zi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z/TISrz/39DI2MA) [Try it reversed!](https://tio.run/##KyrNy0z@/z8zyiHz/39DI2MA)

Its the answer I originally wrote on the other challenge when I misread the description.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl 5 - 12 Bytes

```
say$_#_$-yas
```

#### Reversed

```
say-$_#_$yas
```

Abides by the `-0` rule.

Does require the `-nE` flags on execution.

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-U`, 15 bytes

First, a word about the `-U` flag. Internally, BitCycle only deals in 1's and 0's, so to allow working with decimal integers, it has flags to convert decimal input to unary. In particular, `-U` allows for signed integers by adding a `0` to the front of any nonpositive integer's unary representation: `4` is `1111`, `-4` is `01111`, and `0` is `0`. The same transformation is applied in reverse to the output, with the convenient addition that empty output is treated as `0`.

#### Forward

```
^> 

?!+?
 <0/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/z/OToGLy15R255LwcZAX@H///@m//ILSjLz84r/64YCAA)

The leftmost `?` gets the input, which goes straight into the `!` to be output unchanged.

#### Reverse

```
 /0< 
?+!?

 >^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/19B38BGgcteW9Gei0vBLu7///@m//ILSjLz84r/64YCAA)

The leftmost `?` gets the input. The `+` sends the leading `0` bit, if any, left (north), and the `1` bits right (south).

If there is a leading `0` bit, it hits the splitter `/` and turns east, deactivating the splitter. The `<` sends it west again, through the deactivated splitter and off the playfield. The `0` bit that started on the playfield also hits the `<` and goes through the deactivated splitter and off the playfield. Meanwhile, the `1` bits are directed around by the `>` and `^` and reach the `!`, where they are output.

If there is no leading `0` bit, the `0` bit that starts on the playfield hits the `<` and goes west to the splitter `/`. Since the splitter has not been deactivated, it directs the bit south, and the `+` sends it west into the output `!`. Meanwhile, the `1` bits are directed to the output, with enough delay to make sure they get there after the `0` bit.

**TL;DR:** Nonpositive inputs have their leading `0` bit stripped and their magnitude is output. Positive inputs have a leading `0` bit added and are thus output as negative numbers of the same magnitude.

Comment: @JoKing That's clever! It's really different from mine; do you want to post it yourself?

Comment: [Posted](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193503/76162)

Answer (score 1):

## [BitCycle](https://github.com/dloscutoff/esolangs/tree/master/BitCycle) `-U`, 14 bytes

```
<  ^
v/?!
+~ +
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/99GQSGOq0zfXpFLu05B@////7qGhgb/8gtKMvPziv/rhgIA)

And reversed

```
+ ~+
!?/v
^  <
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8osSa5Mzkn9/19boU6bS9Fev4wrTkHB5v///7qGhgb/8gtKMvPziv/rhgIA)

The `-U` flag translates input/output to signed Unary, i.e. unary 1s with a zero in front if the number is negative. The first program just pipes input (`?`) to the output (`!`) directly right of it.

The reverse instead takes only the first bit of the number with the `/` command and dupnegs (`~`). If it is a `1` then it sends `0` left and `1` right, where the `+`s redirect them to join the flow to the output. If  the first bit is `0` instead, the `0` goes right and the `1` goes left, and the `+` redirect them *away* from the output. All in all, this has the behaviour of stripping a leading zero if the input has one, otherwise prepending a zero if it doesn't, which means inverting the sign of the input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), 2 bytes

```
#±
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y05N//9f@dDG//9NAA)
[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##y05N////0Ebl//9NAA)

Real simple. When run in normal direction, it simply prints the input. When run in reverse direction (`±#`), it negates the input.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 3 bytes

```
Ans-0
```

Very simple and works the same way as the [top J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193055/85765).

Input is an integer in `Ans`.

**Examples:**

```
4:Ans-0
              4
4:0-Ans
             -4
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 3 bytes

```apl
-/⊢
-/ ⍝ Summation with alternating sign
  ⊢ ⍝ Identity function
```

Reversed

```apl
⊢/-
⊢/ ⍝ Reduce (fold) with the Right operator
  - ⍝ Negate
```

Mirrored

```apl
⊣\-
⊣ ⍝ Left
 \ ⍝ Expand
  - ⍝ Negate
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///PzXtUdsEXf1HXYu40lKBTCBDXxckrGACFFAwAQA)

Comment: Interestingly enough, -/⊢ -\⊢ -/⊣ -\⊣ all amount to identity functions, and ⊣\- ⊣/- ⊢\- ⊢/- all amount to negation functions... pretty cool :)

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

*Thanks to [Philippos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72726/philippos) for -1 byte.*

```
##--#s;#-#^#s
```

The code is only comment, which means the input is outputted unchanged.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhbrlPX1dXX1i631dfXj9IshglC5BUtMuHSNIGwA)

**Reversed:**

```
s#^#-#;s#--##
```

The code first append `-` in front of the string. Then if there are two minuses they get removed.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ODVlwYKlpSVpuhbrivXj9HX1rYv1dXX19ZUhglC5BUtMuHSNIGwA)

Comment: Why waste a byte for the comment sign, when you can do `##--#s;#-#^#s`?

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 23 bytes

```lua
print(...)--)...-(tnirp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/J@cn5JqqxEd/b@gKDOvRENPT09TV1cTSOlqlORlFhX8j43VtCouTdIw1NE10uTiKkotSy0qTk1RsFUAabWC8jWAUhATQKKaXDn5iSkQpoYJUBtECqYXKg3ngpT8BwA)

Comment abuse all over again.

Answer (score 0):

## [Cascade](https://github.com/GuyJoKing/Cascade), 6 bytes

```
# -
&#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X1lBl0tN@f9/QwMA)

and reversed:

```
#&
- #
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S04sTk5MSf3/X1mNS1dB@f9/QwMA)

I think this is the optimal answer for this question. In order to negate the input, we have to use the `-` operator, which means the code must be at least three wide so the left and the right operands aren't the same. It must then be two tall to have not loop infinitely. That means at least one row must be three wide, and the other has to be two wide, since if it was one wide, it must be the redirect to the `#`, which would have to be directly under it. Feel free to prove me wrong though.

#### Explanation:

For the initial program, we only execute `#` (integer output) on `&` (integer input). Basically, the only instructions that matter are:

```
#
&
```

For the reversed program, the `#` on the second line leads to `-` (left minus right). This wraps around the program, with the right being the `&`, and the left as an empty space, which is zero. This results in `0 - input`, which is the negated input.

Answer (score 0):

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), 3 bytes

```
+.-
```

[Try it online! (Forwards)](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fW0/3v0rmf0NLAA)

[Try it online! (Backwards)](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/P9fV0/7v0rmf0NLAA)

This assumes an empty stack and an empty tape.

Explanation:

Each instruction in Phooey has a modifier:

- No modifier defaults to either the stack or the tape, depending on the instruction.
- A number (with a preceding `_` for negative) uses an immediate value
- A `.` applies to an integer from stdin
- A `:` applies to a char from stdin
- A `!` applies to the stack (for instructions where it isn't the default)

So, when read forwards, it is this:

```python
+.-
+.  # Add to the tape
  - # pop and subtract (does nothing because stack is empty)
```

And backwards, it is the same for -.

---

## [Phooey](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Phooey), universal, 5 bytes

```
;0@.&
```

This version works regardless of the stack and tape state, and also preserves the stack contents.

Forwards:

```python
;0@.&
;0    # tape = 0 - tape (don't care)
  @.  # read input and push to stack
    & # pop from the stack to the tape
```

[Try it online! (Forwards)](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/O9gbORgYqRmYqGQlpmTk1rEZa8AAwFFmXklCimpSaXpCvmlJQWlJQol@QrFGfnlCpl5mSWZiTkKxSWJJalc/60NHPTU/iN0BoPUYNWYmFaSWgTR9t/QEgA)

Backwards:

```python
&.@0;
&.    # read int and store to tape
  @0  # push 0 to the stack
    ; # pop, tape is 0 (stack) - tape
```

[Try it online! (Backwards)](https://tio.run/##K8jIz0@t/O9gbORgYqRmYqGQlpmTk1rEZa8AAwFFmXklCimpSaXpCvmlJQWlJQol@QrFGfnlCpl5mSWZiTkKxSWJJalc/9X0HAys/yN0BoPUYNWYmFaSWgTR9t/QEgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: <s>30</s> 27 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = <s>30</s> 27 bytes, does not support signed zero, not clean.

- Filename (escaped unprintable): `._.n.o.-a.d.n.-.-.00y.\001c._.`

  - Reversed: `._.c\001.y00.-.-.n.d.a-.o.n._.`
- Content: empty

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrV9pI9Ht/xTiLMAOEJIitMo6uot1lV6mrbrctsJ6YhBINCZKgUKB/vXvvJEGw7tnH6SkzuXPnvl@jY0X9bz@Q4cQdeJVqZeAFlWEYeRMvGrz6gZhV16za24aza25Vq2@c7Z2d3druds01b8wb23Xt1@Ybt7dlvorcmGjuWIwHVnRHDKNaFe5kGI5ictq4Pjw9lQ3B4unQJZ/d2A6DXj6vvuxwMLACh@/rjvugB2PfJ9X9vJnPp5fPD69@ljTHUjyiDTMC6ojnZriU6otkoy1oxvb3VvPD9eXVsawaxlYGPH932fxw@vG68e7i4qRxJU3RJlpAaG52dHj58/X7k4vL5rtWHciQbj4/I0qrkCiDCPwoHYnF8s6nl664g7FvxS6J@nghHMawewxHTjT0vVhYvmdFRPtMCrmZWaK5H@miIAu4FkTr99PTxtmxrCsWoDQydETU93qxYu4QREwBrt0PSe4HTokkJrJmChL1XbBhHIYk9J39PHrBi4nJhftg@YRukJ7lRy6dz19AJ6v4SgKFM5lHrkMKkT7Rp7qI4OeLXlB8v5DufA4qK0qA8x1b0AQs4D/I3V0BLhx6vss460lD2FbkAgeTEi8grFfkpAfeEG5k2cKKIndw40/R8SH4/DAg2kM8NufxiGiNiBhmdau2/frNzi4ptDtBsVuYfx65Q1KZW493pHB08lOzNfOBiSNrrwVYlw1HXhD3SGF4Hr4LWl7z2m5Elw/ve2/dk9HF4x@TD9OPXz5Zh/HV4Mw5Lmkbuc3Nwvx/sM4ZkjbalOQMQruyQymYxA8f3RGLEhEY3bRpOWdwTmiHCirAkAUVGozS8mWZ1ikXKHpPRpJS0QtHTEDE@17gkt6@IfjM67EMEO1Jgys8AEZoyUY@35PS4bMTxoViSRrtqCsWLnidIJY6feyjJ5L9KetxZCeeE05OkJBypiEWiyWb7xkoDsmVUxZxACDGojcO7NgLA3LKbCW7vQHy8ii27Lu2Xyp1pb2CBFcQx@ez1GPUT23gg@6@pvEMDv9SGprZTQUBOywWBeUJ7YGEED4q@GgWEonWqY77oGBQknr7cTL90tU13dLRAsGekTKnFYsc1UglQaBzalsQ0RDbdBncCg98zRIqVlc/oORHEC0oAbk66IkkQ6WT7uj5/EbAU1smED4by0AzRSJZsD9eda/yQSpKIgR51ENSsV6U5bkuiXDUSuUBDOW@4D@QzNwOMSpSu29GnQ7WvixF6Zy1SWJmovkxqWIlAkrzzAuWNHCBIM31KO76AChERTDZMAzs6GEUd/Uis/ZMXtLbJcg8LfmucvCPO4nFQh/qMyAjIigQi2jPFPA/PerDrg@Kx3pxY8MSi1kkN/R2z029ISw0infd1Uu6D1RbbzVgwyzwPQhgg6HaYRCBAADsI1Af6Bocm7DLZBELE5L0mZpba2oWZudtr2R0ZQ78WiqJoYRvrQpJMfwKAZzPA/NZApLDJHTHN1E8YjmjvMWF4/ouNIzztqZ5XZEoBhf/9En7T9It4X1bn8EVRhUgR8s0T/K0nJD8RwI5pBDpM0@T1We4f3PTT28onmTJ9F9zfBI8syKEPng8t4k7QGTEmBMjQeM5ymch2g6q51BMZK71VpCpzCXuEitCrIoy5IgfYiJN9qZ8UpJTjU3lhIulpd9eQq2Kmd4p6QeT0rQO/j6YaLBuwFqEdRPWzWkd@trLKp20jmdYfW4h@m73PHFbKiUFCNBuu5gYWWuELKsUc7peSAA6WALMp@vYL1Hoon7O8lzon@Gb6LDcQGtUKeBdQxL03FE86ILJ9TwUTV3EIstlACXFAQ74TJ1YCFyorYNbbHDYrXvLUUA15AKmLzN4YT5Pvh0gPXLj8SjAppNwKSEBy3Eyrhp@Rzdx9r2B3zDRZN@dHAIc7yEDbCqEMCMQ6ZWi/sfVW0bzUPzAHM8kW3bipCJftu8k5A3kdtYC@0kLLMCAEGdFp4CGni@vLruFy4747A4SDsh0JfxgK0B/HQHFoz2EiiNwGWzKRykCbJ4RR9GBAVct3iFQ37iArI7skTeMZSooNj7Xdb7SCvSuEUyi6nO1v52zY476lH9lvCuPlUwg2npvS8y/8etaZ/xleUDgYN9cOfr16Uhp83RytXaCTFH5p/MP7ILPLiSgKUk0LXU9uVhBGrNG2g6YZu7B7NDYq26/5geNOrbSJdpPSAssMA6@6hUdyY4DMQ5w7ngimu6W3fUgZ9S1VV1@R2Zwq7ECO2RnWT86vIEBvQ618eylVrS8MWTZ9LIBBuVj9gF@V87DZIJ4@TBgzfJ9@bjsP@HM7iUgwcjlu8HnuM/uuYqgJvSa5p70RRPiZ8zYsUxL9n25WTY5/0rbhrbbpQfHpdpOvbaN886SjQcynLOf1nlfs7Nyo/yp/JHPziStXNdJK4yxPrmf3REVDQn44hOwVeNOMufV3iRO2d7hNyPXusNi14AyW2tvbXexbH6StZrWSC8nKNjk2U5yz6xBY2tIuYXNNEGCp1PsBWNXLND2CXZjr7aDiPvbbzhXYCXDE/eEAf8oPxLW0ABZoDPFOftU/Liqo71i/HN2tW6AaOXww1oCPIBbbsvvuaq1YHoDsv1WqpAGJ9yCLd5j8pabXaEWnBpxc5t832paV75fdcBohRVuRvCACwN/ms@DTDhWHTJaGdUJbCmqgQmgkpoXMWLWnPn4lGhADsoQYGwAiRX5J@y38n3CEXKZp9im@E2FVhJgKfC3vfuVi9P/cHF/9eKXpVAsuZrJlYq/RIxXLNHHKrlu@UFyfIczfR9chiir5w56ZhUl7ZKIJ@6gqKx5TJWoJtbdEtQihqkDct0mS1IPOU8cJxUSevSJmWpDyOsXFT4gaelZ/mJjai5RIMeANaBoiLZnHGjNenPNd6pxrVEsPqOInew@rQe/pNHClOFhQvTVKtN4ydXJJ3cUbiwj5n7fP7jX/bqv33O@yhW64b@kufkizU2gualoYmv/9rZ1eHYiC5XrSlAJK5pVcWCjwT/DmFY6hmHacFR41XjXujppXclv2RMppy5SMifp05v04CewBi7J5199j/VoE82Gqrt2mlJdpYIlxIUZ6G/QXiKztE0P/LF8jj9d@59v7daFmqZhdIS5C/@@o90RMxiVzWws@1NV6SLpsEqxw3MwhHVMHEv4gsKbBlu4VMOTZhP1B6gxVoFwgJMKAEffAZ/EdGpEa9XWEHBEieA8JEPPKbuxN3DLQ3s4Lj9EX4RjxS5fVbP2z2rGlucTLahVM3VACVbpzHY6C1SmY@qFp2eWVjVrb2o7W69rO/AggYcPWEUNsMnAaiXPuP9uZ3y8JXbCheLbLxuOaIZwLzsFXN9dXMpCIRvusDZ4MIl5OFTgw4jbba8rl38J6XQ2Q1r2IB1bF5vbhpRmKmtE6PKZfw/PvntCOwEMJOmx3c4Z3UQ3HMvSiTxDgkjoEy36Zv4F)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##nRhrV9pI9Ht/xTiLMAOEJIitMo6uot1lV6mrbrctsJ6YhBINCZKgUKB/vXvvJEGw7tnH6SkzuXPnvl@jY0X9bz@Q4cQdeJVqZeAFlWEYeRMvGrz6gZhV16za24aza25Vq2@c7Z2d3druds01b8wb23Xt1@Ybt7dlvorcmGjuWIwHVnRHDKNaFe5kGI5ictq4Pjw9lQ3B4unQJZ/d2A6DXj6vvuxwMLACh@/rjvugB2PfJ9X9vJnPp5fPD69@ljTHUjyiDTMC6ojnZriU6otkoy1oxvb3VvPD9eXVsawaxlYGPH932fxw@vG68e7i4qRxJU3RJlpAaG52dHj58/X7k4vL5rtWHciQbj4/I0qrkCiDCPwoHYnF8s6nl664g7FvxS6J@nghHMawewxHTjT0vVhYvmdFRPtMCrmZWaK5H@miIAu4FkTr99PTxtmxrCsWoDQydETU93qxYu4QREwBrt0PSe4HTokkJrJmChL1XbBhHIYk9J39PHrBi4nJhftg@YRukJ7lRy6dz19AJ6v4SgKFM5lHrkMKkT7Rp7qI4OeLXlB8v5DufA4qK0qA8x1b0AQs4D/I3V0BLhx6vss460lD2FbkAgeTEi8grFfkpAfeEG5k2cKKIndw40/R8SH4/DAg2kM8NufxiGiNiBhmdau2/frNzi4ptDtBsVuYfx65Q1KZW493pHB08lOzNfOBiSNrrwVYlw1HXhD3SGF4Hr4LWl7z2m5Elw/ve2/dk9HF4x@TD9OPXz5Zh/HV4Mw5Lmkbuc3Nwvx/sM4ZkjbalOQMQruyQymYxA8f3RGLEhEY3bRpOWdwTmiHCirAkAUVGozS8mWZ1ikXKHpPRpJS0QtHTEDE@17gkt6@IfjM67EMEO1Jgys8AEZoyUY@35PS4bMTxoViSRrtqCsWLnidIJY6feyjJ5L9KetxZCeeE05OkJBypiEWiyWb7xkoDsmVUxZxACDGojcO7NgLA3LKbCW7vQHy8ii27Lu2Xyp1pb2CBFcQx@ez1GPUT23gg@6@pvEMDv9SGprZTQUBOywWBeUJ7YGEED4q@GgWEonWqY77oGBQknr7cTL90tU13dLRAsGekTKnFYsc1UglQaBzalsQ0RDbdBncCg98zRIqVlc/oORHEC0oAbk66IkkQ6WT7uj5/EbAU1smED4by0AzRSJZsD9eda/yQSpKIgR51ENSsV6U5bkuiXDUSuUBDOW@4D@QzNwOMSpSu29GnQ7WvixF6Zy1SWJmovkxqWIlAkrzzAuWNHCBIM31KO76AChERTDZMAzs6GEUd/Uis/ZMXtLbJcg8LfmucvCPO4nFQh/qMyAjIigQi2jPFPA/PerDrg@Kx3pxY8MSi1kkN/R2z029ISw0infd1Uu6D1RbbzVgwyzwPQhgg6HaYRCBAADsI1Af6Bocm7DLZBELE5L0mZpba2oWZudtr2R0ZQ78WiqJoYRvrQpJMfwKAZzPA/NZApLDJHTHN1E8YjmjvMWF4/ouNIzztqZ5XZEoBhf/9En7T9It4X1bn8EVRhUgR8s0T/K0nJD8RwI5pBDpM0@T1We4f3PTT28onmTJ9F9zfBI8syKEPng8t4k7QGTEmBMjQeM5ymch2g6q51BMZK71VpCpzCXuEitCrIoy5IgfYiJN9qZ8UpJTjU3lhIulpd9eQq2Kmd4p6QeT0rQO/j6YaLBuwFqEdRPWzWkd@trLKp20jmdYfW4h@m73PHFbKiUFCNBuu5gYWWuELKsUc7peSAA6WALMp@vYL1Hoon7O8lzon@Gb6LDcQGtUKeBdQxL03FE86ILJ9TwUTV3EIstlACXFAQ74TJ1YCFyorYNbbHDYrXvLUUA15AKmLzN4YT5Pvh0gPXLj8SjAppNwKSEBy3Eyrhp@Rzdx9r2B3zDRZN@dHAIc7yEDbCqEMCMQ6ZWi/sfVW0bzUPzAHM8kW3bipCJftu8k5A3kdtYC@0kLLMCAEGdFp4CGni@vLruFy4747A4SDsh0JfxgK0B/HQHFoz2EiiNwGWzKRykCbJ4RR9GBAVct3iFQ37iArI7skTeMZSooNj7Xdb7SCvSuEUyi6nO1v52zY476lH9lvCuPlUwg2npvS8y/8etaZ/xleUDgYN9cOfr16Uhp83RytXaCTFH5p/MP7ILPLiSgKUk0LXU9uVhBGrNG2g6YZu7B7NDYq26/5geNOrbSJdpPSAssMA6@6hUdyY4DMQ5w7ngimu6W3fUgZ9S1VV1@R2Zwq7ECO2RnWT86vIEBvQ618eylVrS8MWTZ9LIBBuVj9gF@V87DZIJ4@TBgzfJ9@bjsP@HM7iUgwcjlu8HnuM/uuYqgJvSa5p70RRPiZ8zYsUxL9n25WTY5/0rbhrbbpQfHpdpOvbaN886SjQcynLOf1nlfs7Nyo/yp/JHPziStXNdJK4yxPrmf3REVDQn44hOwVeNOMufV3iRO2d7hNyPXusNi14AyW2tvbXexbH6StZrWSC8nKNjk2U5yz6xBY2tIuYXNNEGCp1PsBWNXLND2CXZjr7aDiPvbbzhXYCXDE/eEAf8oPxLW0ABZoDPFOftU/Liqo71i/HN2tW6AaOXww1oCPIBbbsvvuaq1YHoDsv1WqpAGJ9yCLd5j8pabXaEWnBpxc5t832paV75fdcBohRVuRvCACwN/ms@DTDhWHTJaGdUJbCmqgQmgkpoXMWLWnPn4lGhADsoQYGwAiRX5J@y38n3CEXKZp9im@E2FVhJgKfC3vfuVi9P/cHF/9eKXpVAsuZrJlYq/RIxXLNHHKrlu@UFyfIczfR9chiir5w56ZhUl7ZKIJ@6gqKx5TJWoJtbdEtQihqkDct0mS1IPOU8cJxUSevSJmWpDyOsXFT4gaelZ/mJjai5RIMeANaBoiLZnHGjNenPNd6pxrVEsPqOInew@rQe/pNHClOFhQvTVKtN4ydXJJ3cUbiwj5n7fP7jX/bqv33O@yhW64b@kufkizU2gualoYmv/9rZ1eHYiC5Xrit0xDLMyNYyKBv@CilOxtEoIm@tK4VXjXevqpHUlv2VPpJy6SMmcpE9v0oOfwBq4JJ9/9T3Wo000G6ru2mlKdZUKlhAXZqC/QXuJzNI2PfDH8jn@dO1/vrVbF2qahtER5i78@452R8xgVDazsexPVaWLpMMqxQ7PwRDWMXEs4QsKbxps4VINT5pN1B@gxlgFwgFOKgAcfQd8EtOpEa1VW0PAESWC85AMPafsxt7ALQ/t4bj8EH0RjhW7fFXN2j@rGVueT7SgVs3UASVYpTPb6SxQmY6pF56eWVrVrL2p7Wy9ru3AgwQePmAVNcAmA6uVPOP@u53x8ZbYCReKb79sOKIZwr3sFHB9d3EpC4VsuMPa4MEk5uFQgQ8jbre9rlz@JaTT2Qxp2YN0bF1sbhtSmqmsEaHLZ/49PPvuCe0EMJCkx3Y7Z3QT3XAsSyfyDAkioU@06Jv5Fw)

### With comments

#### Original

```
XX.z
.a._.nXX.z # push getint; putint pop
.a.o.-XX.z # DOTo and DOT- works like EOF for insufficient items
.aa.dXX.z # push ascii code of a; exit
.a.n.-.-.00y.\001c._.XX.z # deadcode
  ## NOTE this is syntaxically valid
.a
```

#### Reversed

```
XX.z
.a._.cXX.z # push getint; dup
.a\001.yXX.z # push 1; while pop>pop; do
  .a00.-.-XX.z # (*essentially*) push abs(0-pop)
    # NOTE actually: push 48; push 48; 
    #     push abs(pop-pop); push abs(pop-pop)
    # NOTE NULL char not supported for filename
  .a.n.dXX.z # putint pop; exit
.a.aXX.z # done
.a-.o.nXX.z # push hyphen; putchar pop; putint pop
.a._XX.z # this is why it aborts when only an integer is given
.a..c.sXX.z # push dot
.a
```

---

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 34 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 34 bytes, clean.

- Filename (escaped some): `._d..s.s.n.o.-a.d.n.-.-.00y.\001c._.`

  - Reversed: `._.c\001.y00.-.-.n.d.a-.o.n.s.s..d_.`
- Content: empty

This version deals with exiting; reversed version exits well against non-negative input, too.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhtV9pI93t/xTALZAbIG2JrGUZX0XbZVeqq27UC9cQklGhIgASFAv3r3TuTBMH2nOfZPT1lJnPfX@beOzpWNPj@C9p7Y@xYb42acVez39b27N3XdtWpmXv2G9Myqn3H2rP7tV3bfPULGs3coadVtaEXaKMw8mZeNHwVuTFS3SmbDq3oARlGtcrc2SicxOi0eXt4esqbjMTzkYu@uLEdBv1iUX7Z4XBoBQ7d1x33UQ@mvo@q@0WzWEyJzw@vfuM4T1I8pI4yBhJE8wuxlOurZKOucCb2r3br@vby6phXDWMnOzz/cNm6Pv102/xwcXHSvOIm6yA1QDi/ODq8/O3248nFZetDuw5sUK9YXCBpVYiklUx8lI/Yak1z8zMSdzj1rdhF0UAQhKMYdk/hxIlGvhczy/esCKlfkJJfmGWc/xWvFK6IVWHtv05Pm2fHvC5FgNFCoMOigdePpXAHCcT0wLUHIcr/QjHiyBSiiTyJBi74MA5DFPrOflFEwYuRSZn7aPkI51Df8iMXL5c/QUeb@FIDiTNbRq6DlEif6XOdRfDzVVek3K@ot1yCyZIT4PwgFiwBD/iP/O1bBiEceb5LKOlzg9lW5IIEEyMvQKRfoqgP0WBuZNnMiiJ3eOfPReBDiPlhgNTHeGou4wlSmxEyzOpObff1m723SOl0g1JPWX6ZuCOkLa2nB6QcnbxvtRc@CHF47TUD75LRxAviPlJG5@GHoO21bu1mdPn4sf/OPZlcPP09u55/@npjHcZXwzPnuKzm8oWCsvwPovMGx80ORnkD4R7vYgwu8cMnd0KiRAWCCzau5A1KEe5ihhk4UpGpQTCuXFZwHVMmVO/ziGPM@uGEMMh43wtc1N83GF14fZIdRA1uUIkHh5HwZLNY7HPu0MUJoUyKRM1O1GMrF6KOBJaEPg1EJJL9KelTIY69ZJxABCMZTIOtVmsxPwqQEhKSUxJROBAYq/40sGMvDNApsaXudg70pVFs2Q8dv1zucXsDCUgEjk8Xibuwn7rAB9N9VaXpMcIo5aCavUQNcMJqpcgwqI8ohNyRmYezfEhMTg3cB@uCMtc7T7P5156u6pYuzA8aRioZaxY6qiEtQcBLbFuQzpDYeJ3ZEg8CTRIuVk8/wOhX0CwoA7s6GClYhtIg3dGLxVxAU0cmJ3Qx5YFqskSzYH@6GVsZgFSVRAn0pIdIs36qy0tbEuWwleoDGDJ2wb9gmcUcEpSl16cQdbui8GX3Ey9JByVuRqofo6ooQ8BpmUXB4oZYIEPzEDPYDeBAiUrgslEY2NHjJO7pJWI1TFrWO2W4dmryXaUQH3cWs5U@0hfAhkVQHVZRw2TwPwUNYDcAw2O9lMtZbLWIeE7v9N00GswSTvFue3pZ94Fr@50KYogFsQcFbHBUJwwiUAAOB@JQH@oqgE3YZbqwlQk39IWZO1tmKovzjlc2ejxvsBEX@7LIydUo9w2yN7PC1wWaWu3xEXp3iaLpXRRPSN6o7FB23lFVr8evQViDtHlSDUYVq/LuktJiEVRdAD7BeQwnyOq0e5WEF2WO67vQaxIObNVu7AB@JGSlLNebVI8o5YU6n1GvDByv17ye1WjvV6GdCCeAC6BT6J18oQcJLESX4Afsg/jMuPhmc56ciKSeNeZ0VuZzlcz5DMoDz@7vPa@y@wagMTpKPGB17nts0yWQYUTvlvWDWXleh@AczFRYc7CWYC3AWpjXoQP9YPRJ@3iRyDBAhsfuy@WkTAAGyIAEzvoX3AatlNf1dc2W5/pnH4FXdF30NuGWkn5OipTpX@Ab6bDcQRuTGevdQs723Uk87IEn9SIUOJ3FLLt6cJTcZQDQhYRY4nAlt47YimYkOmt/3bZl81TEbSMGVZbL5NsB1hM3nk4C0SASKWXBwHKcTKoqvqO7OPvOiW@YPrLvbl4cON5jdlCQCGHGINK1kv731TuCi1CrwCsvNFt3zaSAXnYeOKQ5XMWsXQ2SdqVAM4@zGqEIfy/XpOvK7pIjungolxmw6XH4ESkjwnYEHI8a4pQdQeRgUzlKEWDzgrlQHQRQ2Y4dBOWIMriEkT3xRjFPFRVNynWdb1iDPjOBqVF@bvaic3JMhT2VPwjt8WOpE6i23YcS9@f@2Opiv68BCAD75gboj2eQtOYZcrUFEUJlhVjDr8kFXVxwQJOaqGoaenSxgTQlzbR6E9VsQJ9vNqq7r@lBsy463xrtveAFHpgG33RNF2ynAZsGYkZ4Zpru1s3wIG/U1U1b/hLCgKq5cXZIzrL2cXgHw3QdWsvZZudIYDnM1j1kTTsi2cyRA9fSKbmG3w14mPT9nwMD0qqMK8cV/xlnMeaABIOS7wZf4gEZU5lLLWgSrQb3WQsyaUrIMU8L7bjSqpiUfsMdQ33bwwfH5dpevbYrppS1GA90OCfvt2XfkrNKs3JT@UQXZxxrt3XUDmNRq9wv7gSzJgd8dgNi5ZSSTGe1N0l4dvfo3cS1HkRlbH7Dn2udnd1eHtPFDa/V1GZKnKCI7kz2EjqzBh2pyfmO6IIJEjx4Yi@YumwlopBgNxu1PYG4v/uGUnksdXiWngign/gnRJoqIDMRVnZObkqfNm20N5x/Tq62HRBtAK@3rsIjhOW@8pHK4guuN@De33OZ3BCEe/DFR3GNK60ek4uY9cTmPvm@V9Ue/7gZgMmGKLGZwLMrDPx5sQg6iXnokGBtUkewxcIMcRXk9aYlkTFbwXx6vnLADgoSYOSAxYb@M/JnZZxIhFtNU2yT/SlTK0mw9PDPxniDcP4vCPc3Cb@ulSIJaaZXqv4aMd7wxEDUy23PDxPwg5jEBxAygbIJd0RkNlHSjinw2AOUl62IyWLVEhW4DFWJiKtTIvfyN6mLlCZh4xJFxPNZlGxHQtLvMnlAz/KL2ysaVGuNAjcMBAOKKtAaxoHaqre2Iicb2BbH0guOoqON02rwe5orRLodVPblytNsydfRjTsJc@t8Ge/7B2Pdr/v6mNJNqdAV/0@ehZ/yLADPguQpWvz3d@3DsxOuaLeOpkXwL9BCTbU0BzYq/DOMudY1DNPWbjUFFYuv6mhNodkCos0NQ6IGQGSpQB5IRpoDFK@aH9pXJ@0rrijf09aI85IBXqbPbNR/tYak2M8w@9VLqicbqTZU8Z8Q/QBaO60PgVq/rTco/tvDuX2BxLsOxmhlGYk/1qgPyAwmFTMb3z7L4l1CXaKVujQPU1rXFHMLXWF4o4gez@V0pdpI/jVpKopDOBSjDBxOfjh8VtOpIbVd20IQM0wE8BCNPKfixt7QrYzs0bTyGH1ljhW7dNPM2v82M7Y8H6lBrZqZA0YQrbvY666EMV1TV56fTWrVrL2p7e28ru3BAwMeMuAVOegmg62VPMv@vZ/FYyzxk1iweMtl0xPOEMa8q4j1w8Ul5Fc2/YmS4cGo5ompg8Ejh9odeC2s/6zR7RZCXPHgnsIcKkewdAgfI9wNIDxAmwwIyXCQPDThrXFR2DU4N1PLIoSzfEJjIEqpVynY7uSNdOT/UQS8/qMBUqPv5j8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 12 bytes

```
||1c0gI|\\&-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7T1rd9s2st/1K2BqY4u2JEty2iRq3CRNk7M@Z2@bk6S7H2SlpURI4oYiFT7iuNc3f713Bg8SAEFKipNtt7s@rSIRwACYGcwLA3Bzna3i6Oy3Nukd98g89oNoOSZ5tujdxyctx3FaTxPqZdQncURer3LyJF@S4RkZ3B/fvT8@u0dGg9Gg1Xrs5QApGZPvvSigYevxe5qkQRyNybA/7EOFnzY@gwLVh73BqDe6C1/HgwF59uo16wb@8J8sJn48bhH4Yx8@nUGHizyaZwDugD9ce28pjDaaexnJU0ree2FOCfzYxEGU0YQEC@IlSxKkZBZ60VvS8SKfZNgKHi9Cb5kS6EhAmHnzt1de4qduCTyM401KljQTsOMF@UhmdBEnlCyhE4AdpYHPKx6wdnKMCHkZk0USr8l85SX4G0ZFcAjvgzntIWq8coZlp54GAzAar70smHtheE3SDLv2IphA4l0DQLKm6zi5ZmDX8XtKshUt5g/N8WdEP4gJlJ3QEBCWZkCMNY2y9BGJEyi4nlHyzzzNSBRnWunDXo9crYL5isyx8znMIzVhkA6DHHBisDEyJD9yBWXx810ezN@STRIvE2@dKhR@Hvz66@F3@a@/3hxcTJYnL4ez9M7ZZDAbzN4Mpss7X8HXIX79bjoEdgGSYgOsT3rEC2G2ESDpPQ2vxxqs9FU6fDVMRy/OVKDDEuioAMqGcYWgVzQMY3IVJ6HPHt5Mhufvpge99OTbdLJ8eOfjZHC@eTdd9tJvpx/PhxsgMJ2/ZcyUUopsF0SbPENQmyRYU7LKsk06Pj2FpUWXcbjoA9bmb@kHYIxoSfvzeH36Lqcp0jw9/ere18N7p0Hay1bwEeXrGU16Xo9BEsMZvJtONtMBrBEKvUK18X5dfD26dzY6DdabkJEOoGcJrNze2puvgkj0QnBV7Al2dDY4TRncHrTuCTqTDvATHZObDaLkhx9fA48jcFHchSU195BpkFs56mDNAfK8JAVhcbWiwOceMDu0Rs6k6012zZfpd4ezw3yx8ML4kNxcnE9mgwlQdDacAmHPgM6jydm76ezsZHr3k5E1Gt4f3b97GucZDKw347196r8ctRcvBpPl5sXHvUno4Wju33tw@uCrr@8NGbDg5OUv88F88JfJSTD9@AnwHty7e1@BV37MaIZShLMw50PO6RQk/M1i8A0si8VUWxWLYlGAyJAAJHWv41yKj5xJM8/3UduAsFhgvcXAGIDt4yaF3gYnsACgp4fHH7E3FF43F6OHleeE9L4FkQwdxknghaQTh/6YA@kJKKwqNJl@fLhE@MQVkop9PAfIjCG5pOK8uUYJCdijUhUg296A@AuWKy46V957lIDX5OZIqBOQCTj9Ky/C9mEWwBLh4NKulJeHKFQ9ECHA9x6MmHRAll4FYWgogTlTxaUWQNnPlgqsFFhV2fUG5DuoF9DqqKLSVZyHPoy1OpJC@9EIIYKa8ntIEF/M9CrIVjg6gQTAX8L1A1OicYQaCfEQgApIcfRlXVdMi1yyXvGPfvBQMozJ5eEmBrURXx6OLtVOcSLXND0cdQkFtNzVIcIThowliHkycaCi0yVQ1eHA@M@7U9YdyJhnY6QLakv4P4oB4twDxKAuBn4A5Us6tL/sk8vIRf55lyMUVLprLwFZ3nG6Ry5AAIQiz4JixDlHOCQh3CNG4SsgQB6FNE0ZWv04n4WMI9b9YuJvAOe8wO@WqyCEprBUYXUh0eFfoNXsmiTIU0DsDH/nKX6@HA2ZOQF2SBL4aIUgx8FCxl7NgcO6Y/NynAwkmOPcYOserAP@uyVNLFxQ8OfTBWeeDtLAVTTyMoxnsGZQ8Kq/pXGSqg8TugGeVJ9wcfkkexb56uMs3vy4eIVySH2KZo23pOojYcOoj9DIehrnxeO28hxAJlr/8zxJQLU9jddrYKuLyKcfTFjG0Oa8ampW@1uQZrZ6T@PNtTkJ6j/BJak9prDE4PFSfQim0XMwjbQJAwNk34GW0Cctao62ksA2/C1ISN8Gm9ex@oRG/nMB3BxfEMkS21BEFxVcVQfw3FJug6yiWWuzCSgwvj60LP4bUAqQnJb8qz4l52QyLYuMbqG0N1QLtPGWbS2TxcLJtHvr/6akjUobLRxc22GwBtkPggAkVx8X/EIQW8MKdF6Hf4EBZYbPPTDXyzKD0tUKnDnsiFPxAzW43m4X61B/JJZs8VB6J/K3WPzY02BKjok0xUtRUVSVy7EclbLolIdyycGjH2Jhz4qFpE1ULi7tobIQjdmzD0WwQfHrRHhVKmFktxwHfhwdoUkQ@aAYaJLEoHo4Za9sBs7R0VFpa9yg9P1GEnlYfBv12Z/8@cM3ZJKhlYwWFUwq5w4ZU3/cbUMlyHHFnErA5LyUu1zPr70PyGnoXjFnMZ0ytw/N9U2ernhLZkJ2pY0Cz0BjdaVdcSPZdxEkaCJJVdst/SGuRLNVEufLFX/ccfvkYiGUdYAWkHMDqpzNBw0aNGWYuZVKeyvgrpU@qD75EUFcBSntor5nsJW1sLCNjHnQwrPwhI0rusbarGhNs1Xsc9sDzACu6rBjtA3WaANkAQ6uE/QpGbImrG6SA5ArcPVdtELTDZ2jCTr3cHwDfMQhpYBxpFuAhEQNyYEhhwyH4lcGKj50dR7hzMXM53NmRfcBXujNacchTtdxeHUuLGWNdBMGWcf5BgpFKCBA0cArweozWDFYdIAUEkfCNihKRQ0skoBvHBfX8Pk5WB9K9cpqFnRXKpRGIizDhpbV3rS6xQ8xM7P6cGrFkjIV6@CZSOiUA3G10oRmeRJVkYMkZKGfIFImoUOGXlkV6PXo8vLI6Lcy/fJHOY/LS6crMdoduhUArSpadRnGRR/nCPEP2PObIZN@bfQ9esxCTBX/HMxg5mzAUiz8i6LlSJW7WXJddlw3GUGiQ4UeiD0a0nUT9jTYpZtB5x3Hgw4ccoKGdQfBuFXEyKEyWZh23InjOTo7oYm9yca1LRFwyywY9r3NBtRrh9Vya@aOFa3rKaSRymnIGcOmtVT@kIvBHHUFS1UMKR269V3ZEWVD0sZLU8lQquWUltJmOB5PRSE62UjmBOMSDAFFfVeZevFwEkwV0wd/Vla1jloNA1zsMimUsSUPeHNtgoMPUSGNbAnmiEGRAuZwUO1HfDkhQyt5yrb6oKVFASXg@SkGHht0lzdzK9WFAWJrIrpy9X7apnTrEl67QLBs2C06cQ1N0UZlJwu5bdJXSpkk5KVIZ1lxTNrplbdhv8FgAZ0aBhGImdCTLh5rrVGvzVCWS4O3I2CVc2qb@G0XDFk8aWrPWRLD9qh7SbDexGDRbmiy@HkuLFkQfsIQfo1VhCHKDV@loONqa7vEB5hkIfjbFlv6IUHuL7CscFl1yOnEAkHhZBv8kwqXSSVkqXyH2YIWbi/ri2l@K6Z/Qr6yaDDOX84LEQxGtPqogvrk@8Bn8RDgDwxuwFeQ@R8CjK5F3CB65FTl9iyh3lt1Fgqnsfgk1x3Aa2yPZ4zWINd4XfEvcJhun9Jsrpk9ioJUJgQFqnNwgPrRaik4Tv@f4OWotRW5ynSxRgC7jdGS8RljLS9w7auRmk2cpsEspMLTdQbD0dndr76@d//Bx18eH7551Hfa5BDXcEJT5hh4YI6CtGSWCRqkPIpXCumI4lqMoWa8KP0JjuE3LEz3iHkUsogjutD/uovGPTePPeJxJ1Ir9l0d21EMs0VpD7XUSbqmQhSdSs2LbXS@Ef1jQZOpKeBMekPUMKzRid5IAabWrlqh3CrsFPg4RgK4VWGgfCCt1XUuZrlXkMwSWdJCSIU6Rlmlmfwe85fnpdYrfIA3zAeAcgXtvDZ8lqr3jW5Qlw534STrGLd55EWfj3br85G1z9HWTkfVXmXX2MuB4QRUTCgcYt8yRH2oizD2MgSoM2OV8comKATKZu52K8scuum/eHoYxFb9Y7U@DkMw3ERw2dSizhQgv9iBmE6T2eyxvZno07V0CF4C4h3NVoaicZtvaKWsOY9uyDCYzjU1XoYhhDjQ7X4G1OOGKI6X/3B38h40W8SwwgBOl@3gCPIb7ClF9PfBHCXQ/2qwnRNn7Pl@V3/Yc8ZpPstQ0xklx85YbEVdGyWnztgP3gc@NZ5fOWO2N/4P3Bo3yl46Y7l10SVtRPqA/YEliDu4YpuMx1/8YMljOGyvqjM8h6l3yeic74J0ydk5WwIu6bEN9RkN4ytGKp9mXhACpWegoUGgoqGKOyQMYKoPKIWJY8TLGOfSGYM@NR4@dMaC476PryKj8Nui8KeNUfQC@qDZC15qlG2gWRKZPR04Y1SWxtO5M@YbccbzCc4BLCuMYxtFU2cMqs5ScAfIGvt5GBvP/wKwwNo2niY4AxEuZbrcKD93xuUSfvYuB5lp1PhZosf/O4YNL6JXXG5YK2c4ISSyDD4b5V1EGgB7CrbZE3MsHvA3RnovoqCI3ZsdPBF1fgSL3eMV2nybNC6eYKYKprosWNILDGfOYmyxvnydNSASSz809fcK8RfSefYcXAYWhzYqzCRpX8cvSnPQqPSdmPaTyH8JNpq9UiAqXQCul5XSd874XR5kwso2Ci/EWrjA4I1RtgBG@kDneUZraOKDNMD8q3L/qOJB4N//KWY4izCowor9cMGYcsBFP5Gy@8RxhSzWKk/wx9QtFafpbXLymdlS6IOKfCyP/P1/QHjgfjnf3QSnbQmy4hFvD6ot4CVZwLbUc5gauqgRjCxn0HjHbRZQZ@atkv8UJ1hbz9PCzll8BKD1SNCnfZYJ4AEd52wrV8SSMVtLuCpQFwuOFkcsAI8SjWdNcZuaou@PMlP4WkV3zE40SFbgjxFJNxybd@62biJWdwm3bCs2bCLWbup9uX1EbQu3ui1WmImqFnbkcMYgkYiOWs2K0YrQnkE7SzEeqrtsRX/a@qmNCDxnrggPC1hwNDEmPnWrrvouzSZ1XU9lPH/qWKxcn5b4rXhBX7Zr2a10@QY1ge@GaAjHLYZEzAZt@z4nXwn9Tbzp9JRAu2QasWPKk5mgEmMe/tC1eCLVTWiNmyphzyYkVgN@ZXRUgzpVdwi01fiZYDZ82T@oVh9Ya2mQbcS1MMYXW2Um3xvL3sK@Tdvv9bEue39WcWaJG95uNbq7L6dWHV5qW9WGGj8h3PglQo52UtgwsnU564JGDNQHtUG2KR2lgYWUXStN3OY1UhFlFn9YSDDXiKjzx@gBA8lrFo5FLLSFEBWr0xqkrgVXJ3MrktZKocZZWrszplxscICVSZOsZvBD@D/oWsW2jBCotoZlS0WkjPCcTsXM7BHeMQkwMlu6M5jpRN7lNKf6XOvyf9B@LC36ThnBktwotwWxBG12svIw@YJG0uz0HdeMWwrfX4G2WKPclnDETlDV/@/yAwpBEb/B@AhL68hnvYVq0XG6YahAHOtIA@b6p3LTh/xKk5hFtMv6LJJQtOCBAqGjfToP1pgWnMToAPhuExwZmxCARF6Wkk6KmZwoZpiaox74ClQkGLaUrV1ASmVPFxF1gnF7Rzcu15k0gYaqCbRGIjEpABUwWutK80JvNNIaIR12aHSmNeKRSEuzkvBsNEAIpMP5QPc8jGxP6ElUNEW9kR0iQ6DqtjRpWfItdIuKYR54cCUNjDBeFoUzARmeVaF3hwPX3WM0p8PB8XFndjLsiQnB@I4rz1oCQ2IJbMeOCIoOMCFZfDccCm1oxs69LdOjLlUAoI97bF1OFVLyeX5WYlZQZ89I0dqw5WghEikR23hOAOdSxim5RGqzB11@qocnvL33ksCT@1oc@9xaa2OKeUTesHz8pGQhIR7/Wh4PcpRFJHcWivaPtrc/MABYKK426pJ/1LUaVJusLOM0dx6t0I8R6MnQdS149XyJUJFrWCTgFQGTlLB0daAcSkiljKOFhbhZNdG6UtHOcII7XYVc5@f1y6MwRGsZ7eS8oA6AUzmwsnXRJKoqOxyIJhlyF7iSP9mUmZhS0CILEW/cR2rCXFm7gPVlENjbisAeQ2CpsD4vCvkOhEAg/8GneCqpJp7yKJmKBMxKHamYG4il2CVFE6O6SNwR9WNMJW1u4OkZ/bfD9em5GG/dktbrisHWEub0s3O2ofPFtpHkbqxyfF6QRRQH@1FGbbUrcRraNNOnvSeBjvcg0PF2Ah2bKwd3/FR0HzDtzlItPtuqUgjINgME9URmtLBrEQVdJa0TPI6Mej6RxzNlMFpNPWgzcBqx8SsnBZ5Iq2snxJqUbM1Q2AAjWxqE5ZHdtjqoaFe5xw2lU81CstDP3A/X68tMHcUBaqd4itU6H3E0uziyrhzbtqJmZ0AG298CNYapWeJpm/lm4qlku2IbVUUSHltPtXPr@caGA1s9xhQsFSSty4upNawwm0sAgsk/eGBmcokyLaBVzdwwT7MYHokeaKjmimwZRO1A6tNIzAHZQyEKNXDHu5kePtTYjSJY8/PRZFBDkt6uJHnw4PY0GTSQpLcvSWBAVTqUGQRW2WHc5mAscBWtZT8ilcTdHgsruSGJNNnFPIO0KqVMCWRjjLq29SL8k86FljkzbjNb2c9v6MTidVQ5p0QvEUG4CawiKE/56SMoCyJaHPDhOactETQ8IBirwDxKjjK8GyGYg3oViagCMc9@fE46fIMZdDA7WI3t@H0r6n0S7PyU23TQtsaWsR35qG7V4Dx5toI6U@WMeFrRNpIvrXyxsxayULeZpI2BEB69rOSvbVdcTWAYS/AjMiK8NMcTwNycEjk62gLGh@I4JxSRHtEXCaNykkf8JM1RKnMXigaB4Blx90ykaH3gBIrpNaZQaPMrb9iWUoclIbxx@XG2AHvwMEHiPU0w1T5YlHe37HNmuErKpkPSe0C2ZK7aMxe2JQPU5RJoB1S3DKZypHg/ttUSBlVYct9jIsOxqi3fJfJphXWVMpka6XYZA/Z9Sjf4RTZyJaNvOwZkHdfg8w6iNnWVx51@ivi5WJ8fjO2TFyFl@eiYvc/25tgBR8yv8bIspKzTTULh8/Fy7QUh3mLCvCSPLIIPxSHNIE1zAJrGcXTguNUcX0wsL5lL9aLMvAILn7jtdlu1WDQBhXk97CYOmfHIvdVZglevZGwjRUnyadXmhaohxap9IrpUmKdqdbCdNpJHWRByDyyM2W0SYiiV@mJ3vOlwCcuLtqZj7HTgpKniFptOS4@tOYcp6FrFzZ8LOVLOF9KbnbYiMy/l5kKa5YuFYmaBYYHRbpHFhjtZMR5phtnaFOIO/F9NFXFtR4r@VMvidrkTe7OGJZdia@1/ixX0b4JHq5tU/4BnZPJsbNUELFI4rQYgu/CDaSxWzGxpPO6veVTkTVepw67z4zdxoa3NLgdgjsci4HcxVKxzu7tlu/6m2SCyGnQ1N@FYjiXt7AF8XpNvW9qpzXStmH4y1wTvT8JEkx3OX5pNZD/7NLYkhsD6VHM6hB@nLAd5eYg8KvOLo563tfepL6ZmFXfeXF6ey/rFKW1F3aUaaichcZAff69BfnSajF1zmI9/r2E@dix2t2vcmlGe0/ucIwRhK7zgSnDENQSiynoNX353rlSXN8p77fT/H4AhK@MbTv9QnFgZ32j6e/BiZRhnU8GXu3Bh67MYrIkMsqjWuG5R1WbIq/uIw6Z04l1Jh7rNWsdmBeq6Zad0fiw0ka6DVi6sUAelOMuVybWLVJWEGmm3beNaHa0Llrhqc823G8CN@MQsuJLHmqvybDj3862zvTsnPeO6n5pzC0XcyyBFfW3JAXW0M@yb0rxpnmGXOJeR41YWoE4si664Zeq6zgi39EHObwngE9XRnxMFe2m8PycK9laqfyw0cLVcp44tmvYP5aP81xr8T7EGFbb7cxiGt165zcf/6pv@16D81xmUv7OW0od/S1hfymZ9Lq9rqjdcjfRVdj3GXol6vIksKhe4AHXmsthuquYT3CFn7n4ZwtvSHDTgO6ejGu2K1FS7mGlqONj9gAnUlzkJttMZeBEJx39x5g0f1SV/YhZskQnlK@@yMdMkt8PYITi@fY/fEtSupyBdb17hLYc1iZHbM0trLxBFsDaSVHss0ja357w291RNF9Jvj7EuKl6lvNnCnsmmX5Sv3uHNUqXVRcw6Nq@l2Ws9sxUcJ2TQFZsyUUyKPLJt57Oa1ujAek5NqyKmY6bFWq/PUSa1NSduS8aUhckGtrFa6hVLmSc7qff3qKdHvTRty2w4/j6L8kpBVMhjsgiDzWmCN3rjLdizIDpdgbTvsHt43uKbqq7wpnuWoglUSqnbxUOa8RpvLpQv7BiOvoaW7A0s7DEmcHTJ3KOpl5B0FSwy@VqL8iIhlTdUemupiuwiZsEs7FVdn5TwyKBYMrpvk@i4JbFxvqrmErk20urV67Y8lMNelduWVEQSbyhz9sUNSwt2cJayayNDGi2zlcr5tjR3gPEzv8k9LV9oI7A9i7MMs3sqZ8yIN7K1KV4DBowXR6zQlwPqCYFSnN6Vpxx4kh4MbdjXqwyM8kGfPAtT3orrerVvKa7g51EqlUzZPbsrXo6PdjlYHCdLzYDR9LCimB1eYef7Y56f3MU7cdltnV2yGx/Z3kGy09WRugBuSU7gZDDeppAxm724KJBnLhfOs5ZqprbXajN70Jqqpl9sWF5Q/ATXWgFP3xiVI9LNGXY6WbvkXRlOZTnViD/@XgqLnmy6/V0T@ZOiVwNSdfQj9dYB8UopvI51xDWoOhVFR1qnwjV3kM1XxMyAwCLjrRk1@fEluu33oDMo6pXnvEfXdo2HUmxP4dBGPKjemmJNr982VdOY4ctDd7g1VA6a8Dj4Lx41PFpdcfvVugVgXdL8R@CyZsrNOJUXQBs3GoqDe3kEplaAL0FpKcIiT1WDWyTwX89D1DpoHOFl7sL@Oukdn97pkpcvnz1naoZ6SYgvFfUpIs7DizbW3ofTNV4GL77gnU38cot5HObr6DSJr7rEA4AgM0/BG8Zu8nXlLWI16qqicepNnbYYNkdGq/YOXHmFq6kJas5FVGEo92qXbzHQP@pP0VgujDTOjFhdogP82/rWMAOJzclpwjnTrqbcx5uo6XivUxm6Ji3eT7H70UHdcbWdU9Fu1VRRzW4YYLcBy3fr8VvbUZQwgwKflW8asJ2cYLYeS76j@EIu9o5Els2H93/jOw/ZPR2kOJxf5q4q0EYC3CMFnA9kscFinFGk8@HTAlpEA3nsGaGKpEAu4hrcFGipeypmM5kkbDHOd3g73W1e57ftpnI1lDt0uuLeCDn94rYNU3QYmcG1rFr4Q3xWIoYoLqivOVioVBfBE8chthtAWlvi0Y2jwsC4MbKGQZm1lRO6zW4jry@1pPkWmJq9@ZqWemaY6n/rN9rWHDAUbybTFyre3RpH6Mkx3dTEjY3nST/DGxuMmZf2ie0IoR0WmP3aPfBWcMphzPKe351iF9V4pzjtlW0JVyjrH1GoN/sXHs404xe16K0mIraqukG5Cbmq8@oynWtHWHN2YzS8e@/u/bOv796raKjykgV243J1DDvHmC1SUkV81d2OQ/@1PSavvFFH803LX9Nmb3x/AbvLS7xqnO7Ku7X2OAG@9Yj3PmPbZ3zWMTYI4l3GsEvflTsC9jzy/qXoZD15UY2I6zxrVi2uF1FveCkiaPiCZv1uETJB60sE54prRZjTwgwtfN1jxK71wRO0/EpukuLrbqbipg3lyD0@F9cFYjyPvZeeh/cQVXiCg9WwSVnxKnaQsd4ajT2u2zLjoIe8N8Q00ItV117KzQx2TyK2VsfMhsVfCa6EJFlcEd9CrctG5b1oLTxe@ZS/PtJxnMvfbm6G88Hy4uby8rD3G3sDulJDfp2M0Rpp8TdGy4eg8H8b/T8)

[!enilno ti yrT](https://tio.run/##7T1rd9s2st/1K2BqY4u2JEty2iRq3CRNk7M@Z2@bk6S7H2SlpURI4oYiFT7iuNc3f713Bg8SAEFKipNtt7s@rSIRwACYGcwLA3Bzna3i6Oy3Nukd98g89oNoOSZ5tujdxyctx3FaTxPqZdQncURer3LyJF@S4RkZ3B/fvT8@u0dGg9Gg1Xrs5QApGZPvvSigYevxe5qkQRyNybA/7EOFnzY@gwLVh73BqDe6C1/HgwF59uo16wb@8J8sJn48bhH4Yx8@nUGHizyaZwDugD9ce28pjDaaexnJU0ree2FOCfzYxEGU0YQEC@IlSxKkZBZ60VvS8SKfZNgKHi9Cb5kS6EhAmHnzt1de4qduCTyM401KljQTsOMF@UhmdBEnlCyhE4AdpYHPKx6wdnKMCHkZk0USr8l85SX4G0ZFcAjvgzntIWq8coZlp54GAzAar70smHtheE3SDLv2IphA4l0DQLKm6zi5ZmDX8XtKshUt5g/N8WdEP4gJlJ3QEBCWZkCMNY2y9BGJEyi4nlHyzzzNSBRnWunDXo9crYL5isyx8znMIzVhkA6DHHBisDEyJD9yBWXx810ezN@STRIvE2@dKhR@Hvz66@F3@a@/3hxcTJYnL4ez9M7ZZDAbzN4Mpss7X8HXIX79bjoEdgGSYgOsT3rEC2G2ESDpPQ2vxxqs9FU6fDVMRy/OVKDDEuioAMqGcYWgVzQMY3IVJ6HPHt5Mhufvpge99OTbdLJ8eOfjZHC@eTdd9tJvpx/PhxsgMJ2/ZcyUUopsF0SbPENQmyRYU7LKsk06Pj2FpUWXcbjoA9bmb@kHYIxoSfvzeH36Lqcp0jw9/ere18N7p0Hay1bwEeXrGU16Xo9BEsMZvJtONtMBrBEKvUK18X5dfD26dzY6DdabkJEOoGcJrNze2puvgkj0QnBV7Al2dDY4TRncHrTuCTqTDvATHZObDaLkhx9fA48jcFHchSU195BpkFs56mDNAfK8JAVhcbWiwOceMDu0Rs6k6012zZfpd4ezw3yx8ML4kNxcnE9mgwlQdDacAmHPgM6jydm76ezsZHr3k5E1Gt4f3b97GucZDKw347196r8ctRcvBpPl5sXHvUno4Wju33tw@uCrr@8NGbDg5OUv88F88JfJSTD9@AnwHty7e1@BV37MaIZShLMw50PO6RQk/M1i8A0si8VUWxWLYlGAyJAAJHWv41yKj5xJM8/3UduAsFhgvcXAGIDt4yaF3gYnsACgp4fHH7E3FF43F6OHleeE9L4FkQwdxknghaQTh/6YA@kJKKwqNJl@fLhE@MQVkop9PAfIjCG5pOK8uUYJCdijUhUg296A@AuWKy46V957lIDX5OZIqBOQCTj9Ky/C9mEWwBLh4NKulJeHKFQ9ECHA9x6MmHRAll4FYWgogTlTxaUWQNnPlgqsFFhV2fUG5DuoF9DqqKLSVZyHPoy1OpJC@9EIIYKa8ntIEF/M9CrIVjg6gQTAX8L1A1OicYQaCfEQgApIcfRlXVdMi1yyXvGPfvBQMozJ5eEmBrURXx6OLtVOcSLXND0cdQkFtNzVIcIThowliHkycaCi0yVQ1eHA@M@7U9YdyJhnY6QLakv4P4oB4twDxKAuBn4A5Us6tL/sk8vIRf55lyMUVLprLwFZ3nG6Ry5AAIQiz4JixDlHOCQh3CNG4SsgQB6FNE0ZWv04n4WMI9b9YuJvAOe8wO@WqyCEprBUYXUh0eFfoNXsmiTIU0DsDH/nKX6@HA2ZOQF2SBL4aIUgx8FCxl7NgcO6Y/NynAwkmOPcYOserAP@uyVNLFxQ8OfTBWeeDtLAVTTyMoxnsGZQ8Kq/pXGSqg8TugGeVJ9wcfkkexb56uMs3vy4eIVySH2KZo23pOojYcOoj9DIehrnxeO28hxAJlr/8zxJQLU9jddrYKuLyKcfTFjG0Oa8ampW@1uQZrZ6T@PNtTkJ6j/BJak9prDE4PFSfQim0XMwjbQJAwNk34GW0Cctao62ksA2/C1ISN8Gm9ex@oRG/nMB3BxfEMkS21BEFxVcVQfw3FJug6yiWWuzCSgwvj60LP4bUAqQnJb8qz4l52QyLYuMbqG0N1QLtPGWbS2TxcLJtHvr/6akjUobLRxc22GwBtkPggAkVx8X/EIQW8MKdF6Hf4EBZYbPPTDXyzKD0tUKnDnsiFPxAzW43m4X61B/JJZs8VB6J/K3WPzY02BKjok0xUtRUVSVy7EclbLolIdyycGjH2Jhz4qFpE1ULi7tobIQjdmzD0WwQfHrRHhVKmFktxwHfhwdoUkQ@aAYaJLEoHo4Za9sBs7R0VFpa9yg9P1GEnlYfBv12Z/8@cM3ZJKhlYwWFUwq5w4ZU3/cbUMlyHHFnErA5LyUu1zPr70PyGnoXjFnMZ0ytw/N9U2ernhLZkJ2pY0Cz0BjdaVdcSPZdxEkaCJJVdst/SGuRLNVEufLFX/ccfvkYiGUdYAWkHMDqpzNBw0aNGWYuZVKeyvgrpU@qD75EUFcBSntor5nsJW1sLCNjHnQwrPwhI0rusbarGhNs1Xsc9sDzACu6rBjtA3WaANkAQ6uE/QpGbImrG6SA5ArcPVdtELTDZ2jCTr3cHwDfMQhpYBxpFuAhEQNyYEhhwyH4lcGKj50dR7hzMXM53NmRfcBXujNacchTtdxeHUuLGWNdBMGWcf5BgpFKCBA0cArweozWDFYdIAUEkfCNihKRQ0skoBvHBfX8Pk5WB9K9cpqFnRXKpRGIizDhpbV3rS6xQ8xM7P6cGrFkjIV6@CZSOiUA3G10oRmeRJVkYMkZKGfIFImoUOGXlkV6PXo8vLI6Lcy/fJHOY/LS6crMdoduhUArSpadRnGRR/nCPEP2PObIZN@bfQ9esxCTBX/HMxg5mzAUiz8i6LlSJW7WXJddlw3GUGiQ4UeiD0a0nUT9jTYpZtB5x3Hgw4ccoKGdQfBuFXEyKEyWZh23InjOTo7oYm9yca1LRFwyywY9r3NBtRrh9Vya@aOFa3rKaSRymnIGcOmtVT@kIvBHHUFS1UMKR269V3ZEWVD0sZLU8lQquWUltJmOB5PRSE62UjmBOMSDAFFfVeZevFwEkwV0wd/Vla1jloNA1zsMimUsSUPeHNtgoMPUSGNbAnmiEGRAuZwUO1HfDkhQyt5yrb6oKVFASXg@SkGHht0lzdzK9WFAWJrIrpy9X7apnTrEl67QLBs2C06cQ1N0UZlJwu5bdJXSpkk5KVIZ1lxTNrplbdhv8FgAZ0aBhGImdCTLh5rrVGvzVCWS4O3I2CVc2qb@G0XDFk8aWrPWRLD9qh7SbDexGDRbmiy@HkuLFkQfsIQfo1VhCHKDV@loONqa7vEB5hkIfjbFlv6IUHuL7CscFl1yOnEAkHhZBv8kwqXSSVkqXyH2YIWbi/ri2l@K6Z/Qr6yaDDOX84LEQxGtPqogvrk@8Bn8RDgDwxuwFeQ@R8CjK5F3CB65FTl9iyh3lt1Fgqnsfgk1x3Aa2yPZ4zWINd4XfEvcJhun9Jsrpk9ioJUJgQFqnNwgPrRaik4Tv@f4OWotRW5ynSxRgC7jdGS8RljLS9w7auRmk2cpsEspMLTdQbD0dndr76@d//Bx18eH7551Hfa5BDXcEJT5hh4YI6CtGSWCRqkPIpXCumI4lqMoWa8KP0JjuE3LEz3iHkUsogjutD/uovGPTePPeJxJ1Ir9l0d21EMs0VpD7XUSbqmQhSdSs2LbXS@Ef1jQZOpKeBMekPUMKzRid5IAabWrlqh3CrsFPg4RgK4VWGgfCCt1XUuZrlXkMwSWdJCSIU6Rlmlmfwe85fnpdYrfIA3zAeAcgXtvDZ8lqr3jW5Qlw534STrGLd55EWfj3br85G1z9HWTkfVXmXX2MuB4QRUTCgcYt8yRH2oizD2MgSoM2OV8comKATKZu52K8scuum/eHoYxFb9Y7U@DkMw3ERw2dSizhQgv9iBmE6T2eyxvZno07V0CF4C4h3NVoaicZtvaKWsOY9uyDCYzjU1XoYhhDjQ7X4G1OOGKI6X/3B38h40W8SwwgBOl@3gCPIb7ClF9PfBHCXQ/2qwnRNn7Pl@V3/Yc8ZpPstQ0xklx85YbEVdGyWnztgP3gc@NZ5fOWO2N/4P3Bo3yl46Y7l10SVtRPqA/YEliDu4YpuMx1/8YMljOGyvqjM8h6l3yeic74J0ydk5WwIu6bEN9RkN4ytGKp9mXhACpWegoUGgoqGKOyQMYKoPKIWJY8TLGOfSGYM@NR4@dMaC476PryKj8Nui8KeNUfQC@qDZC15qlG2gWRKZPR04Y1SWxtO5M@YbccbzCc4BLCuMYxtFU2cMqs5ScAfIGvt5GBvP/wKwwNo2niY4AxEuZbrcKD93xuUSfvYuB5lp1PhZosf/O4YNL6JXXG5YK2c4ISSyDD4b5V1EGgB7CrbZE3MsHvA3RnovoqCI3ZsdPBF1fgSL3eMV2nybNC6eYKYKprosWNILDGfOYmyxvnydNSASSz809fcK8RfSefYcXAYWhzYqzCRpX8cvSnPQqPSdmPaTyH8JNpq9UiAqXQCul5XSd874XR5kwso2Ci/EWrjA4I1RtgBG@kDneUZraOKDNMD8q3L/qOJB4N//KWY4izCowor9cMGYcsBFP5Gy@8RxhSzWKk/wx9QtFafpbXLymdlS6IOKfCyP/P1/QHjgfjnf3QSnbQmy4hFvD6ot4CVZwLbUc5gauqgRjCxn0HjHbRZQZ@atkv8UJ1hbz9PCzll8BKD1SNCnfZYJ4AEd52wrV8SSMVtLuCpQFwuOFkcsAI8SjWdNcZuaou@PMlP4WkV3zE40SFbgjxFJNxybd@62biJWdwm3bCs2bCLWbup9uX1EbQu3ui1WmImqFnbkcMYgkYiOWs2K0YrQnkE7SzEeqrtsRX/a@qmNCDxnrggPC1hwNDEmPnWrrvouzSZ1XU9lPH/qWKxcn5b4rXhBX7Zr2a10@QY1ge@GaAjHLYZEzAZt@z4nXwn9Tbzp9JRAu2QasWPKk5mgEmMe/tC1eCLVTWiNmyphzyYkVgN@ZXRUgzpVdwi01fiZYDZ82T@oVh9Ya2mQbcS1MMYXW2Um3xvL3sK@Tdvv9bEue39WcWaJG95uNbq7L6dWHV5qW9WGGj8h3PglQo52UtgwsnU564JGDNQHtUG2KR2lgYWUXStN3OY1UhFlFn9YSDDXiKjzx@gBA8lrFo5FLLSFEBWr0xqkrgVXJ3MrktZKocZZWrszplxscICVSZOsZvBD@D/oWsW2jBCotoZlS0WkjPCcTsXM7BHeMQkwMlu6M5jpRN7lNKf6XOvyf9B@LC36ThnBktwotwWxBG12svIw@YJG0uz0HdeMWwrfX4G2WKPclnDETlDV/@/yAwpBEb/B@AhL68hnvYVq0XG6YahAHOtIA@b6p3LTh/xKk5hFtMv6LJJQtOCBAqGjfToP1pgWnMToAPhuExwZmxCARF6Wkk6KmZwoZpiaox74ClQkGLaUrV1ASmVPFxF1gnF7Rzcu15k0gYaqCbRGIjEpABUwWutK80JvNNIaIR12aHSmNeKRSEuzkvBsNEAIpMP5QPc8jGxP6ElUNEW9kR0iQ6DqtjRpWfItdIuKYR54cCUNjDBeFoUzARmeVaF3hwPX3WM0p8PB8XFndjLsiQnB@I4rz1oCQ2IJbMeOCIoOMCFZfDccCm1oxs69LdOjLlUAoI97bF1OFVLyeX5WYlZQZ89I0dqw5WghEikR23hOAOdSxim5RGqzB11@qocnvL33ksCT@1oc@9xaa2OKeUTesHz8pGQhIR7/Wh4PcpRFJHcWivaPtrc/MABYKK426pJ/1LUaVJusLOM0dx6t0I8R6MnQdS149XyJUJFrWCTgFQGTlLB0daAcSkiljKOFhbhZNdG6UtHOcII7XYVc5@f1y6MwRGsZ7eS8oA6AUzmwsnXRJKoqOxyIJhlyF7iSP9mUmZhS0CILEW/cR2rCXFm7gPVlENjbisAeQ2CpsD4vCvkOhEAg/8GneCqpJp7yKJmKBMxKHamYG4il2CVFE6O6SNwR9WNMJW1u4OkZ/bfD9em5GG/dktbrisHWEub0s3O2ofPFtpHkbqxyfF6QRRQH@1FGbbUrcRraNNOnvSeBjvcg0PF2Ah2bKwd3/FR0HzDtzlItPtuqUgjINgME9URmtLBrEQVdJa0TPI6Mej6RxzNlMFpNPWgzcBqx8SsnBZ5Iq2snxJqUbM1Q2AAjWxqE5ZHdtjqoaFe5xw2lU81CstDP3A/X68tMHcUBaqd4itU6H3E0uziyrhzbtqJmZ0AG298CNYapWeJpm/lm4qlku2IbVUUSHltPtXPr@caGA1s9xhQsFSSty4upNawwm0sAgsk/eGBmcokyLaBVzdwwT7MYHokeaKjmimwZRO1A6tNIzAHZQyEKNXDHu5kePtTYjSJY8/PRZFBDkt6uJHnw4PY0GTSQpLcvSWBAVTqUGQRW2WHc5mAscBWtZT8ilcTdHgsruSGJNNnFPIO0KqVMCWRjjLq29SL8k86FljkzbjNb2c9v6MTidVQ5p0QvEUG4CawiKE/56SMoCyJaHPDhOactETQ8IBirwDxKjjK8GyGYg3oViagCMc9@fE46fIMZdDA7WI3t@H0r6n0S7PyU23TQtsaWsR35qG7V4Dx5toI6U@WMeFrRNpIvrXyxsxayULeZpI2BEB69rOSvbVdcTWAYS/AjMiK8NMcTwNycEjk62gLGh@I4JxSRHtEXCaNykkf8JM1RKnMXigaB4Blx90ykaH3gBIrpNaZQaPMrb9iWUoclIbxx@XG2AHvwMEHiPU0w1T5YlHe37HNmuErKpkPSe0C2ZK7aMxe2JQPU5RJoB1S3DKZypHg/ttUSBlVYct9jIsOxqi3fJfJphXWVMpka6XYZA/Z9Sjf4RTZyJaNvOwZkHdfg8w6iNnWVx51@ivi5WJ8fjO2TFyFl@eiYvc/25tgBR8yv8bIspKzTTULh8/Fy7QUh3mLCvCSPLIIPxSHNIE1zAJrGcXTguNUcX0wsL5lL9aLMvAILn7jtdlu1WDQBhXk97CYOmfHIvdVZglevZGwjRUnyadXmhaohxap9IrpUmKdqdbCdNpJHWRByDyyM2W0SYiiV@mJ3vOlwCcuLtqZj7HTgpKniFptOS4@tOYcp6FrFzZ8LOVLOF9KbnbYiMy/l5kKa5YuFYmaBYYHRbpHFhjtZMR5phtnaFOIO/F9NFXFtR4r@VMvidrkTe7OGJZdia@1/ixX0b4JHq5tU/4BnZPJsbNUELFI4rQYgu/CDaSxWzGxpPO6veVTkTVepw67z4zdxoa3NLgdgjsci4HcxVKxzu7tlu/6m2SCyGnQ1N@FYjiXt7AF8XpNvW9qpzXStmH4y1wTvT8JEkx3OX5pNZD/7NLYkhsD6VHM6hB@nLAd5eYg8KvOLo563tfepL6ZmFXfeXF6ey/rFKW1F3aUaaichcZAff69BfnSajF1zmI9/r2E@dix2t2vcmlGe0/ucIwRhK7zgSnDENQSiynoNX353rlSXN8p77fT/H4AhK@MbTv9QnFgZ32j6e/BiZRhnU8GXu3Bh67MYrIkMsqjWuG5R1WbIq/uIw6Z04l1Jh7rNWsdmBeq6Zad0fiw0ka6DVi6sUAelOMuVybWLVJWEGmm3beNaHa0Llrhqc823G8CN@MQsuJLHmqvybDj3862zvTsnPeO6n5pzC0XcyyBFfW3JAXW0M@yb0rxpnmGXOJeR41YWoE4si664Zeq6zgi39EHObwngE9XRnxMFe2m8PycK9laqfyw0cLVcp44tmvYP5aP81xr8T7EGFbb7cxiGt165zcf/6pv@16D81xmUv7OW0od/S1hfymZ9Lq9rqjdcjfRVdj3GXol6vIksKhe4AHXmsthuquYT3CFn7n4ZwtvSHDTgO6ejGu2K1FS7mGlqONj9gAnUlzkJttMZeBEJx39x5g0f1SV/YhZskQnlK@@yMdMkt8PYITi@fY/fEtSupyBdb17hLYc1iZHbM0trLxBFsDaSVHss0ja357w291RNF9Jvj7EuKl6lvNnCnsmmX5Sv3uHNUqXVRcw6Nq@l2Ws9sxUcJ2TQFZsyUUyKPLJt57Oa1ujAek5NqyKmY6bFWq/PUSa1NSduS8aUhckGtrFa6hVLmSc7qff3qKdHvTRty2w4/j6L8kpBVMhjsgiDzWmCN3rjLdizIDpdgbTvsHt43uKbqq7wpnuWoglUSqnbxUOa8RpvLpQv7BiOvoaW7A0s7DEmcHTJ3KOpl5B0FSwy@VqL8iIhlTdUemupiuwiZsEs7FVdn5TwyKBYMrpvk@i4JbFxvqrmErk20urV67Y8lMNelduWVEQSbyhz9sUNSwt2cJayayNDGi2zlcr5tjR3gPEzv8k9LV9oI7A9i7MMs3sqZ8yIN7K1KV4DBowXR6zQlwPqCYFSnN6Vpxx4kh4MbdjXqwyM8kGfPAtT3orrerVvKa7g51EqlUzZPbsrXo6PdjlYHCdLzYDR9LCimB1eYef7Y56f3MU7cdltnV2yGx/Z3kGy09WRugBuSU7gZDDeppAxm724KJBnLhfOs5ZqprbXajN70Jqqpl9sWF5Q/ATXWgFP3xiVI9LNGXY6WbvkXRlOZTnViD/@XgqLnmy6/V0T@ZOiVwNSdfQj9dYB8UopvI51xDWoOhVFR1qnwjV3kM1XxMyAwCLjrRk1@fEluu33oDMo6pXnvEfXdo2HUmxP4dBGPKjemmJNr982VdOY4ctDd7g1VA6a8Dj4Lx41PFpdcfvVugVgXdL8R@CyZsrNOJUXQBs3GoqDe3kEplaAL0FpKcIiT1WDWyTwX89D1DpoHOFl7sL@Oukdn97pkpcvnz1naoZ6SYgvFfUpIs7DizbW3ofTNV4GL77gnU38cot5HObr6DSJr7rEA4AgM0/BG8Zu8nXlLWI16qqicepNnbYYNkdGq/YOXHmFq6kJas5FVGEo92qXbzHQP@pP0VgujDTOjFhdogP82/rWMAOJzclpwjnTrqbcx5uo6XivUxm6Ji3eT7H70UHdcbWdU9Fu1VRRzW4YYLcBy3fr8VvbUZQwgwKflW8asJ2cYLYeS76j@EIu9o5Els2H93/jOw/ZPR2kOJxf5q4q0EYC3CMFnA9kscFinFGk8@HTAlpEA3nsGaGKpEAu4hrcFGipeypmM5kkbDHOd3g73W1e57ftpnI1lDt0uuLeCDn94rYNU3QYmcG1rFr4Q3xWIoYoLqivOVioVBfBE8chthtAWlvi0Y2jwsC4MbKGQZm1lRO6zW4jry@1pPkWmJq9@ZqWemaY6n/rN9rWHDAUbybTFyre3RpH6Mkx3dTEjY3nST/DGxuMmZf2ie0IoR0WmP3aPfBWcMphzPKe351iF9V4pzjtlW0JVyjrH1GoN/sXHs404xe16K0mIraqukG5Cbmq8@oynWtHWHN2YzS8e@/u/bOv796raKjykgV243J1DDvHmC1SUkV81d2OQ/@1PSavvFFH803LX9Nmb3x/AbvLS7xqnO7Ku7X2OAG@9Yj3PmPbZ3zWMTYI4l3GsEvflTsC9jzy/qXoZD15UY2I6zxrVi2uF1FveCkiaPiCZv1uETJB60sE54prRZjTwgwtfN1jxK71wRO0/EpukuLrbqbipg3lyD0@F9cFYjyPvZeeh/cQVXiCg9WwSVnxKnaQsd4ajT2u2zLjoIe8N8Q00ItV117KzQx2TyK2VsfMhsVfCa6EJFlcEd9CrctG5b1oLTxe@ZS/PtJxnMvfeoeXlzcXy8F8eHPzG3sDulJDfp2M0Rpp8TdGy4eg8H8b/T8)

This takes advantage of how Rattle is parsed. As of right now, there is only support for one input section (everything before the first `|`) - this means that anything after any following `|`'s will be disregarded. This more or less splits the code into two sections:

```
|
```

This is the effective forward code, which is the cat program.

```
-&\\|Ig0c1
```

This is the reverse code, which spits out the negative of the input. There's still possibility that this could be golfed further!

Answer (score 0):

## MMIXAL, 35 bytes

`f POP 1,0 # 0,1 POP ;0$,0,0$ UGEN f`

Very simple; when reversed, is just negate-and-return.

Answer (score 0):

## MMIX, 12 bytes (3 instrs)

```
00000000: f8010000 000001f8 00000036           ẏ¢¡¡¡¡¢ẏ¡¡¡6
```

Disassembled:

```
f   POP  1,0
    TRAP 0,Fopen,248
    TRAP 0,Halt,36
```

Reversed and disassembled:

```
f   NEGU $0,0,$0
    POP  1,0
    TRAP 0,Fopen,248
```

This is essentially the same as my MMIXAL answer, except that that relied on comments and reversed the source code, while this just relies on early return.

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 38 bytes

```
	OUTPUT =INPUT;END;DNE;TUPIN-= TUPTUO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETB1tMPSFm7@rlYu/i5WoeEBnj66doqAOmQUH/O//9NAQ)

[Reversed](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9M/NCQgNETBVtfTD0hbu/q5WLv4uVqHhAb4edoqAKmQUH/O//9NAQ)

Anything after an `END` label is ignored. `;` is an alternate newline delimiter which made this answer easier to think about.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 5 bytes

```
dp-r0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2ikwKWcll9UnliU8j@lQLfI4L9yUWpZalFxKhdQzqBItyDlPwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 3 bytes

```
+0-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/1/bQPf/f0MjcwA)

Forwards:

```
+    : compute "0 + STDIN"
 0   : push 0
  -  : subtract the top two stack entries
     : prints stack as a number automatically
```

Backwards:

```
-    : compute "0 - STDIN"
 0   : push 0
  +  : add the top two stack entries
     : prints stack as a number automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Knight](https://github.com/knight-lang/knight-lang), 5 bytes

```
O P~O
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##lVjZcts2FH3vV9BsahEiTctpp51Ipj2J63QybeQ0dptpJSUCQUhiQhEKF9upxP66ey@4gdqcvngo4OBuOHeBP9JbGrPIXyRHofD4AwtoHGu/hv50llxGkYg0fp/w0Is1@WuZ5YA3NIp5c185U6LepmHizx/HXScRp/MlE2GcRClLRGRQskxmfmzHIo0Yd2gGO/7i3cxPeLygjBvF/pwmbGYcvzcGw9FwMIxhPeuOzNW3g/fDcNQ2huHqCSHtY5ItOP8EuxFP0ijUFOGDzmi1CtMgyHJhrsWcDlkGPNGo49r8njNDgZNeIQKPOI5Dz/Gjq0Ic5duOUxdsNyiosQMeTpMZseiAjUiWCHDcD6dbrcoyGQ7t5q83l9fOYNTLQ/UnDVK@jBOa@Exb4C0YLlm69kZ4ehOI4i2NwIdOj55KMYX@HjXN3D/myPUBHdmlrJ4/MRgp7GGZ4msWpaEMeyTutJDf5YzIPO6m0y3rO7yTQux6E3D9dO7yaAeu3ATcCyECTsMdwGo3K1j1GwQjokFFvDx0aySL0wVKt6SoDx5NKHAtd1RRssWZ4nd9bpsnxe8maMONckGF8c8BmlcgqOaD1TRkXExyrxU3Dg8V44GP@VcZBRRehaAIyQZ/Sq7X2XTzckQGz4/@HrWPrZOK8vTwEC8YZRr6jY7aSOal80XlzLh05onMz4yMsyCZ1a4c1LYeHtLGtU1VnKbiDprALCfzIo1nBq6SXp4ql/0/X7296r@@7N84y6xImFceD5M1Djzm/oAe/fNhhH87R88@QAjWAyCFgrHZPjb5CAI2NeMjj/oTH3B5iHIcBgrM9achylE8GdSYUUXN3OAdKMzgW@F7WucA76e0vFcnqFqXjfEf4adQ3IWaX1mmtRqmtcbNmEsXSBlfJbpfS6@hZ26GFAJapAsl66QqNmpOUc9TuFKerzljUqV0kAxq8F74URM@T4O98HYT7vm3qpf1Ft5E4xJKUa9pMrOBNyFTpB6D37suSb@gYSgSDVTBnWjuF@0fHgkdTBXe/9RdK/yOPqoPxKeBUPQtxN1@fbX41erAoKcd8lXOt9tf4T2/X4gQSUoTLg3SEgG1MeRT4Nst18A4HoGRwY5Kcqre2856c9ZANYhf074PDXE/75XqXRG/X5RUknMehTRKSFlBsN2u5YCOYIPo@zqDlFc4/0gomZiDmVwesfUqGP/zlBocXCujA83x0eAghVyHKj1Hb40IzHHx8HrUPifDk2PrqaQVRgOY5apEAg04rORDDLXz4Q7BegvbElutWnoLP0jtUj20YtEDq@Z@CEzytM@pAELxkIkUl7nX1Z4saTbe1tKl/c08sk46ZLXqrNWsYkDYV7PQiXEBKBRulh4E1brsiC84hd6jVqBHGF@NWnsZX6HUS4XForvCKepdfwlZl2ZOxD@nfsQNfRLrxFriiCy3XGWLzfzA@7CIBOMxol7@0b@4eXXVv65780uoAftas8KS/IJhMq/EDFyl08mbVmbVnsKr867MOnNlk@OcMRznaZyP8YcH87F3ysrZ2Ctn44kjLbJLU1DZwWQHnV770LvDqUajaTrHgePJ0jNPMg2UaBP0Ejqqi420x/PATkim3DEGwmCWa/G1kQKW2NpYgeIcmn@HdM4dN/8G1bHDNmdXecCwbbtCVZUlr@I6ak98ERq6WUmtwuNq5cgpj1LT0S1NN107l1F1cVPfqE1X7kfOEtuPJX8tGJeySaFKi/jUjxMuXSRLCO0J9qrygbT2ljD0PpikzVMY8lxI1HvKkuCLBr1AYzMawS@YWQIRTqEm9WqC0JHjKhohMFXnUq@2SDJ4gRqukgdErT31GJW/N3pbaaD3hXaLkqFQpoGHtkoV3gHUSiWrMODEqkKgv9EtgzhnxZNM1y3XeZFOJjyyaRAIZsAA7gkMEjU6wIgOTOQWUN6FJyVxwfBPPWaCq3eQcdw4gS4sd@RLzsbceudD4uvDUCeEOcyOAx9eiB1LO6on@7LSMJKplr3NLWu07kkgwNcfnj774dmPPz199mNbrkY09MQcw6aev9Qt6pxhyGgjtDWk9byFkCrR8/AWVrlqdwMDzkszc0n2JBLzC2DAhfBg0CzeTqRbmqtep80K3PMEZzbVyBfSSKouXeRLxeNS/lW3x3K76kNN53Y4qv8uDxUF0eb3/noVV7AHlQL51mo@gBrI3yokeqwaUiaTiv4ZuXVWjW@NYJeWxYkn0sS@i6Bxg8A8z4lFGzG7agqqtRbS9OFQPg8LsgHTznfIL9kIENLdihljb/xmTKxqZlItMYGiWETq68JGW/jWcP5oA4nvgm3I9gYS@/I25PEGUr4GtiC/25Qpttv5fgMpp@4tyNMKWVGlPIITQXVEPXO2@8x015nz3Wew5G89c1idMWiZ143/05wXx7qNzFs9eox23c2M7CnH8l1rW8AcBdaoLfikXa1ApfK8byYytYv3uetU@t2G8HeV8CV2z14jaXtkLd22kvlVLgKavnNGtwaLbfr@i3JIBq2223IbjzQLy7/ys6xgtPwvJQpZrXS9GbXrQoEnVZSHHlHlOd6m5gpctnoc68@pCVNlaQJ0OGIyszbJ9LAX1w3j35Za8ZpPd8BBdMoqAhPL7eApdMKHh4fvv3m40t78e/Uf)

[Try It Online reversed!](https://tio.run/##lVjZcts2FH3vV9BsahEiTctpp51Ipj2J63QybeQ0dptpJSUCQUhiQhEKF9upxP66ey@4gdqcvngo4OBuOHeBP9JbGrPIXyRHofD4AwtoHGu/hv50llxGkYg0fp/w0Is1@WuZ5YA3NIp5c185U6LepmHizx/HXScRp/MlE2GcRClLRGRQskxmfmzHIo0Yd2gGO/7i3cxPeLygjBvF/pwmbGYcvzcGw9FwMIxhPeuOzNW3g/fDcNQ2huHqCSHtY5ItOP8EuxFP0ijUFOGDzmi1CtMgyHJhrsWcDlkGPNGo49r8njNDgZNeIQKPOI5Dz/Gjq0Ic5duOUxdsNyiosQMeTpMZseiAjUiWCHDcD6dbrcoyGQ7t5q83l9fOYNTLQ/UnDVK@jBOa@Exb4C0YLlm69kZ4ehOI4i2NwIdOj55KMYX@HjXN3D/myPUBHdmlrJ4/MRgp7GGZ4msWpaEMeyTutJDf5YzIPO6m0y3rO7yTQux6E3D9dO7yaAeu3ATcCyECTsMdwGo3K1j1GwQjokFFvDx0aySL0wVKt6SoDx5NKHAtd1RRssWZ4nd9bpsnxe8maMONckGF8c8BmlcgqOaD1TRkXExyrxU3Dg8V44GP@VcZBRRehaAIyQZ/Sq7X2XTzckQGz4/@HrWPrZOK8vTwEC8YZRr6jY7aSOal80XlzLh05onMz4yMsyCZ1a4c1LYeHtLGtU1VnKbiDprALCfzIo1nBq6SXp4ql/0/X7296r@@7N84y6xImFceD5M1Djzm/oAe/fNhhH87R88@QAjWAyCFgrHZPjb5CAI2NeMjj/oTH3B5iHIcBgrM9achylE8GdSYUUXN3OAdKMzgW@F7WucA76e0vFcnqFqXjfEf4adQ3IWaX1mmtRqmtcbNmEsXSBlfJbpfS6@hZ26GFAJapAsl66QqNmpOUc9TuFKerzljUqV0kAxq8F74URM@T4O98HYT7vm3qpf1Ft5E4xJKUa9pMrOBNyFTpB6D37suSb@gYSgSDVTBnWjuF@0fHgkdTBXe/9RdK/yOPqoPxKeBUPQtxN1@fbX41erAoKcd8lXOt9tf4T2/X4gQSUoTLg3SEgG1MeRT4Nst18A4HoGRwY5Kcqre2856c9ZANYhf074PDXE/75XqXRG/X5RUknMehTRKSFlBsN2u5YCOYIPo@zqDlFc4/0gomZiDmVwesfUqGP/zlBocXCujA83x0eAghVyHKj1Hb40IzHHx8HrUPifDk2PrqaQVRgOY5apEAg04rORDDLXz4Q7BegvbElutWnoLP0jtUj20YtEDq@Z@CEzytM@pAELxkIkUl7nX1Z4saTbe1tKl/c08sk46ZLXqrNWsYkDYV7PQiXEBKBRulh4E1brsiC84hd6jVqBHGF@NWnsZX6HUS4XForvCKepdfwlZl2ZOxD@nfsQNfRLrxFriiCy3XGWLzfzA@7CIBOMxol7@0b@4eXXVv65780uoAftas8KS/IJhMq/EDFyl08mbVmbVnsKr867MOnNlk@OcMRznaZyP8YcH87F3ysrZ2Ctn44kjLbJLU1DZwWQHnV770LvDqUajaTrHgePJ0jNPMg2UaBP0Ejqqi420x/PATkim3DEGwmCWa/G1kQKW2NpYgeIcmn@HdM4dN/8G1bHDNmdXecCwbbtCVZUlr@I6ak98ERq6WUmtwuNq5cgpj1LT0S1NN107l1F1cVPfqE1X7kfOEtuPJX8tGJeySaFKi/jUjxMuXSRLCO0J9qrygbT2ljD0PpikzVMY8lxI1HvKkuCLBr1AYzMawS@YWQIRTqEm9WqC0JHjKhohMFXnUq@2SDJ4gRqukgdErT31GJW/N3pbaaD3hXaLkqFQpoGHtkoV3gHUSiWrMODEqkKgv9EtgzhnxZNM1y3XeZFOJjyyaRAIZsAA7gkMEjU6wIgOTOQWUN6FJyVxwfBPPWaCq3eQcdw4gS4sd@RLzsbceudD4uvDUCeEOcyOAx9eiB1LO6on@7LSMJKplr3NLWu07kkgwNcfnj774dmPPz199mNbrkY09MQcw6aev9Qt6pxhyGgjtDWk9byFkCrR8/AWVrlqdwMDzkszc0n2JBLzC2DAhfBg0CzeTqRbmqtep80K3PMEZzbVyBfSSKouXeRLxeNS/lW3x3K76kNN53Y4qv8uDxUF0eb3/noVV7AHlQL51mo@gBrI3yokeqwaUiaTiv4ZuXVWjW@NYJeWxYkn0sS@i6Bxg8A8z4lFGzG7agqqtRbS9OFQPg8LsgHTznfIL9kIENLdihljb/xmTKxqZlItMYGiWETq68JGW/jWcP5oA4nvgm3I9gYS@/I25PEGUr4GtiC/25Qpttv5fgMpp@4tyNMKWVGlPIITQXVEPXO2@8x015nz3Wew5G89c1idMWiZ143/05wXx7qNzFs9eox23c2M7CnH8l1rW8AcBdaoLfikXa1ApfK8byYytYv3uetU@t2G8HeV8CV2z14jaXtkLd22kvlVLgKavnNGtwaLbfr@i3JIBq2223IbjzQLy7/ys6xgtPwvJQpZrXS9GbXrQoEnVZSHHlHlOd6m5gpctnoc68@pCVNlaQJ0OGIyszbJ9LAX1w3j35Za8ZpPd8BBdMoqAhPL7eApdMKHh4fvv3m4@veNdvUf)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 2 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 1.65 bytes

```
nI
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaL8jwhDCh_wUJTCAMA) or [!enilnO sihT tpmettA](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhaLPPMgDCh_wUJTCAMA)

Outputs inside brackets, e.g. `[5]`.

Port of [jasanborn's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193027/114446). `n` = negate, `I` = push input.