# The Nineteenth Bakery

Tags: code-golf, array

> Yes, this is very similar to [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/216196/107299). However, that concerns infinite linked lists, and you do not need to handle out of bounds indexes in that question.

You are in a strange city, looking for the fabled [Nineteenth Bakery](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123853/the-nineteenth-bakery), where it is said they sell the most delicious deleted posts. The order of shops here is strange. Each street has a number of shops on it, but they are not numbered in order. Instead, each shop has a number `n`, indicating that the next shop is `n` shops form the beginning of the street.

For example, consider the street `s`, which is like this: `[1,4,3,-1,2]`.
To find shop number 3, you first start with the first shop on the street, shop #1. In this case, `s[0]` is `1`. That means that shop #2 is at index `1`. `s[1]` is `4`, meaning shop #3 is at index 4. If an index is `-1` or is greater than the bounds of the array, that means that there is no "next" shop. A shop may reference a shop already visited. For example, if you are at shop #10 and the next shop has been visited and is #5, that means shop #5 is *also* shop #11.

### The Task

You are given a positive number `n` and a street, which is a non-empty list of numbers. `n` may be 1 or 0-indexed. You are to follow the path of shops until you get to shop #`n`. Then output the index (0, or 1-indexed) of shop #`n` in the list. If there is no shop #`n`, output any consistent value that is not a positive integer (i.e negative integers, `null`, `undefined`, etc.).

### Examples (Array indexes 0-indexed, `n` 1-indexed)

```
2, [3,-1, 8, 2] -> 3
1, [13, 46] -> 0
4, [1,2,3,4] -> 3
5280, [8] -> -1
3, [2,0,2,-1] -> 2
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: "If an index is -1 or is out of bounds of the array" - does this mean we do or do not need to handle negative numbers other than `-1`? (They are out of bounds but then again, so is `-1`.)

Comment: Yes. -1 is the only negative number possible

Comment: Can you walk through the first test case step by step?

Comment: @Jonah there is a walkthough in the second pragraph

Comment: Yeah still wasn't clear to me :(  eg, "you first start with the first shop on the street, shop #1. In this case, s[0] is 1"  So do I always start at position 0, or at the position whose value is 1?  Neither interpretation works for the first test case.  So obviously I'm missing something...

Comment: The array is 0-indexed. So the very first shop is at index 0

Comment: got it now.  fwiw, it was confusing that we were mixing indexing styles for `n` and the array....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Follow a linked list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/216196/follow-a-linked-list)

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal see the disclaimer at the very top

Comment: I don't see that as different enough to make this challenge not a duplicate. We'll see what the rest of the community thinks.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 38 bytes

Expects `(0-indexed-array)(1-indexed-n)`. Returns `NaN` if the shop is not found.

```javascript
a=>g=(n,i=0,q=+a[i])=>--n?g(n,q):i+q-q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc/dCsIgFMDx@57CS2XH5lcxAteDDC9krbEYmi16fXNGGyzy8pwf/4M3@7JT@xjuT@r8pYtXHa2ue40dDJpB0IVtBkN0Tak792kayGkoAg2x9W7yY7cffY@vuOGgQALlIAzBkhCUXlkitdu4bFAFaHZicXLruASkjmZeE8wXx34ciHRXmezU/16VU@jTO8iKJZoc5VsogKUk5WaG60fE1mXxDa6O8vgG)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>        // a[] = input array
g = (       // g is a recursive function taking:
  n,        //   n = remaining number of shops
  i = 0,    //   i = current position, starting at 0
  q = +a[i] //   q = value stored at a[i] (next shop),
            //       forced to NaN if undefined
) =>        //
--n ?       // decrement n; if it's not 0:
  g(n, q)   //   recursive call with q as the new position
:           // else:
  i + q - q //   return either i or NaN (if q is NaN)
```

Comment: Cool beans, glad it didn't thwart the approach!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 7 bytes

```
{x y/0}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k/#eJw1j7FugzAQhnc/xQ0dQLJj++ykDpYqdejaKRtCCgUTUBKTgiuBovTZ65Bmu+/7/zvpmuw6wczFjZBddn3J598ha2AFk933R5vsm7I72cnOdkiLG9nlCVoJGhQwCZhaXdydtAubu1GLEVYq0JvUigVVXMK4pJ/5Gl+3lpqYfxaPqwgiVphMLRaEcNKGcBkzzqu+dof+1KzGUFZHN1Vt6Q9uVfVn/v3jxtD1fuSoldmueWgd8513wTkfWvZVHt0wE/IxlefLyY2QvA9DOUPnazdFFOwx1RQ8yCekBCnkijJJwVDAAtgbKBIpl4rGpxYhiL4LilRR/V9ZoxFRmgWZJLGdIxWxw+Ti8A8ojGCT)

Takes the array (`y`) and `n` (`x`) 0-indexed. Returns `0N` (the integer null) if the shop is not found.

Successively indexes into the array `x` times, starting with the first index (hence the `0`). The value at that index is then used as the index for the next iteration. Out-of-bound indexes return `0N`, the integer null. Only the last value is returned, representing the index of the n-th shop.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Jelly does not like bounds!</sup>

```
1³JiⱮ¤ḣṪƊ⁴¡
```

A full program that accepts a non-empty list of integers, the shop's pointers (1-indexed), and a non-negative integer, the path-length (i.e. "0-indexed \$n\$"), and prints the resulting (1-indexed) index or `0` if the path-length is not possible.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/w0GavzEcb1x1a8nDH4oc7Vx3retS45dDC////RxvpmOuYAaGpjrGOSex/cwA)**

#### How?

```
1³JiⱮ¤ḣṪƊ⁴¡ - Main Link: shops, path_length
1           - one -> the initial value of Current, used below
          ¡ - repeat...
         ⁴  - ...times: path_length
        Ɗ   - ...action: last three links as a monad - f(Current):
     ¤      -   nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 ³          -     shops
  J         -     range of length -> Valids=[1,2,...,number_of_shops]
    Ɱ       -     for s in shops:
   i        -       1-indexed index of s in Valids or 0 if not there 
                    -> s or 0 if s is out of bounds
      ḣ     -   head to (1-indexed) index Current
       Ṫ    -   tail (Note: an empty list yields 0) -> new value of Current
            - implicit print of Current
```

Comment: You may assume that there is at least one element ;) "and a street, which is a non-empty list of numbers"

Comment: Thanks @Seggan it's so dense I didn't spot that; was going to ask...

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 61 bytes

```
\d+
$*
;
;1;
+`1;1(1)*(;(?<-1>1*,?)*(1*))
;$3$2
1*;(1*).*
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxDsIwEATAft/hwr4ckdd2FFmLko@kAAkKGgrE/00oZz7P7@t9H@N4TAgGQRSmG8XIZFFxv1640Xw/RUsJCjUU0PTnbAgzx6CaZ@9ekcXmbUVV8erNFyxl7eooqs6z8g8) Link includes test cases. Takes `n` as 0-indexed but the shops are 1-indexed. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
;
;1;
```

Start with the shop at index `1`.

```
+`1;1(1)*(;(?<-1>1*,?)*(1*))
;$3$2
```

Until either `n` is zero, the index is zero, or the index is out of range, replace the index with the value at that index and decrement `n`.

```
1*;(1*).*
$.1
```

Extract the final index and convert it to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 14 bytes

```
1 :'{&u&0 ::_'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcsxC4MwEAXgvb/i0cEopJK7aNWAk@DUqX8ggzQUF6dO/vj0QQaH43Hfu9vzvTUJc4CBhUPgPFos79eaBcGc1a@ihmhyc/ts3wMeM2pvo1iMFtokSCkcC/Honkhw161AmR3RF4zEkWuvw1REKcp/RRQWmv8)

*If "index error" is allowed for my out of bounds value, I can do -4 bytes*

- 0-index for both
- Returns `_` (infinity) for out of bounds.