# I Rot-13 the source code, you Rot-19 the output!

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout, encryption

This is alternate of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/221209/i-palindrome-the-source-code-you-palindrome-the-input) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196864/i-shift-the-source-code-you-shift-the-input) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/193315/) of a  [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/193021/i-reverse-the-source-code-you-negate-the-input) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/192979/43319) of a [rip-off](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132558/43319). Go upvote those!

Your task, if you accept it, is to write a program/function that outputs/returns its input/args. But again, The tricky part is that if I `rot-13` your source code, the output must be returned `rot-19`.

Your code will be only rotated *once*.

### Examples

Let's say your source code is `ABC` and the input is `xyz`.

Code `ABC` should return `xyz`.

Code `NOP`(*rotated*) should return `-./` (**Rot-19**).

### Details

- If your language has a custom codepage, apply rot13 to the bytes in the printable ASCII range in your code, and do not modify the rest. The input and output will be in pure printable ASCII.
- The input only contains ASCII character.
- use printable ASCII table for rotating
- rot-13 means to forward 13 positions in ASCII table
- Same applied to rot-19, which forward 19 positions instead.

### Rules

- Input can be taken in any convenient format.
- Output can be in any convenient format as well.
- Standard Loopholes are forbidden.

### scoring

This is code-golf so the answer with the fewest amount of bytes wins.

### Extra scoring rule

If there's somehow, a *non-esolang* appeared as a valid answer, it may considered as a better answer.

Example: `python`, `C++`, `java script` etc.

### If you are confused with Rot

Here is a [encoder](https://www.dcode.fr/rot-cipher) to get some idea with.

<s>Use full ACSII Table for this question’s requirement.</s>
**Use printable ASCII Table (33 ~126) for rotation!**

- `Space` are 32 in ASCII, which count as unprintable!

Comment: "If your language has a custom codepage, apply rot13 to the bytes in the printable ASCII range in your code, and do not modify the rest." So a language that uses a code page which doesn't include any ASCII is excluded from this challenge, right?

Comment: Is the rot13 on the ASCII subset of a custom codepage relative to the codepage or to ASCII?

Comment: @Adám If your code don't have any ASCII, then the Rot-13 code won't change at all, producing unchanged output. So the answer is yes, it's excluded, since it's impossible with it.

Comment: So, how rot 13 and rot 19 works?

Comment: @Adám Do you mean the definition of ASCII, if yes, then ASCII is defined to the default ASCII table, which contains 128 char.

Comment: @tsh look it up on google, it rotates the char by it's ASCII value.

Comment: I meant to ask if ASCII characters are rotated 13 positions in the ASCII table or 13 (ASCII) positions in the custom code page.

Comment: @okie I looked it up on google, google suggests a link to wikipedia, and wikipedia only suggests rot 13 works on ascii latin _letters_ (a-z), not _ascii_. Also I didn't find out some useful webpages for rot 19.

Comment: ok i will make a clarify on the question

Comment: This is why it is recommended to use the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for challenges before posting to main.

Comment: Why does `rot19(xyz)` = `♀♪♫`? I thought it should only rotate to ASCII. Also you mention "128 char" ASCII. Does that mean we should rotate characters at the end of the ASCII range into non-printable control characters?

Comment: @user81655 it will rotate to the beginning if it’s at the end.

Comment: @okie Sorry I'm still confused. Could you please list out all the characters that we are rotating through to clear up any confusion?

Comment: "Use printable ASCII Table (33 ~127) for rotation!", but the link you shared only does the alphabet.(side-note: [this](https://rot13.com/) site is a better one for alphabet only)

Comment: @Alexbries the site provided have setting to change to met this question. And also, the rotation is **not** alphabet only.

Comment: This challenge might be better if you first figure out what you're actually asking for. It seems like the intended challenge was to figure out the difference between rotating the input and output differently, but as-is, the main challenge will be to figure out how to make this arbitrary rotate work.

Comment: Copy these code to create a HTML code snippet in answer typing box to write source code with rotated source side by side: `<textarea style="width:100%;" id=i oninput="o.value=String.fromCharCode(...[...i.value].map(c=>(d=c.charCodeAt())>32&&d<=126?d+13>126?d-81:d+13:d))"></textarea>
<textarea style="width:100%;" id=o oninput="i.value=String.fromCharCode(...[...o.value].map(c=>(d=c.charCodeAt())>32&&d<=126?d-13<=32?d+81:d-13:d))"></textarea>`

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 50 bytes

```javascript
a=>01+"$25hYYXeya=>z!`TcyV01yV~$'zv,'|&&z|xx-$"&&a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/taoMwFIb/exVZcflADVoZg246Ri@gYytlZRssZK61WCMxikrprbv40UL7a4TAOcn7Pue8O1aynMs4U04qfqKWizRXIBdJoWKRgqBlQeh61sSc3m3X6/eo1n1z873k9cr16tXRRE1powOEzaGqHHMCITszCskjEJxhVIk3JeN0g8mDMWikUJ7fSUAQgg9Kaf5F9yzDfMukfjIA6KswAEgfCIf2UbdHBJ7AgKO/Uuzn@mOuA@DeS7kuX0ScqmeFXeL4vuX55BZ703tdE0tfMOthBqE7rcMIjUuJJKKJ2GDU0WbIHnPYAH2miFxKFoXKCtWJopIleFASjKq6QWR0XFFfF0ud@MTu8598/xlxYbie1P4B)

Both versions are a function which takes a string as input and returns a string.

ROT13 code:

```js
nJK=>8/1?Buffer(nJK).map(c=>(c-14)%94+33)+'':1/33n
```

### Explanation

Hides tricky characters used in the ROT19 logic inside a string. The quotes map to `/` characters so it's just a matter of finding where to put them to make it work.

Comment: woah... I didn’t thought there would be a non-golf lang answer. congratulation!

Comment: Is this allowed to [use comment](https://tio.run/##jVDdTsIwFL7fUxyjri0/3eZiTMBhDA@AUUIkQGJTB4xAS7YO2ERefR42uIAr0zQ55/T7OV8XYiMSGUdr01T6OyykVomBRKexDCGAaaqkibQCyuAHnFohgo7r2bZwnFux3T7Oh8PPMMNhfvPVl9nA9bLB4Y7kmwbZ23a@3@2KmgO/3OgPE0dqRhlfCSPn1BkrymtsrJyEjbxJ27Iq51gbz0fjBIIOjDjnyQQZayrnIsaRBVBWnQAIHtuu2mdsDwReoHLh01ivuvjQxUi05HKJ5ZuOlHk11GVN3697Prun3sMT1qyOF1qlmMX4AnGUENYul9LLkC/1jJKjWos0Tr/TADJWhF1CeqlZp@YICjdiSSsko2SX5YSdGFeq770@Jj5rl/nPvP9YXBCunYo/)?

Comment: @tsh sorry for the late reply, but **yes**, you are allowed to use comment

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

*-2 thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs).*

```
žD¦7$,!R‡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D6XQ8vMVXQUgx41LPz/v6KyCgA)

```
žD¦7$,!R‡  # full program
     ,     # output...
    $      # input
```

## =BNO>R, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
žQ¦D19._‡
```

[a!( v# |{yv{r.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AQ8tcDC314h81LPz/v6KyCgA)

```
žQ¦D19._‡  # full program
        ‡  # push...
           # implicit input...
        ‡  # with each...
žQ         # ASCII character...
  ¦        # excluding the first...
        ‡  # replaced by corresponding character in...
žQ D       # ASCII characters...
  ¦        # excluding the first...
      ._   # rotated...
    19     # literal...
      ._   # characters to the left
           # implicit output
```

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6D6XQ8vMVXQUgx41LARxAw8tczG01IsHcgE) using transliterate.

Answer (score 4):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 8 bytes

```
#.n$,p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X1kvT0VHrkDi//@M1JycfAA)

[Try it online!(rot13)](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/38C62tBSu1b1/39lvTwVHbkCCQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 75 bytes

Comment still do the trick quiet well :).

```
t=print(input())
#.ce\agyxx!]b\ayNV[eyybeWy\z~$'zv,'|&&zYbe \ \a \achgyzPzz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/v8S2oCgzr0QjM6@gtERDU5NLWS85NSYxvbKiQjE2KSax0i8sOrWyMik1vDKmqk5FvapMR71GTa0qMilVIUYhJhGIkjPSK6sCqqr@/08EAA)

```
#J}!v{#5v{}$#566
0;print(''.join([chr((ord(i)-14)%94+33)for i in input()]))
```

[a!( v# |{yv{r.](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/X9mrVrGsWtm0rLpWRdnUzIzLwLqgKDOvRENdXS8rPzNPIzo5o0hDI78oRSNTU9fQRFPV0kTb2FgzLb9IIVMhMw@ICkpLNDRjNTX//08EAA)

Comment: Doesn't this append the input reversed when rot-13'ed, rather than rot-119'ing the input?

Comment: Ouch, sry, i will update the code, I mess up this one with palindrome one

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 96 bytes

```
⭆Ｓ§Φγμ⁺Σ+&+⌕Φγμι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///R2rb3ezYfWn5u2bnN5/Y8atx1brG2mvajnqkQgXM7//@vqKwCAA) After ROT13, this becomes:

```
⭆Ｓ§Φγμ⁺Σ838⌕Φγμι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///R2rb3ezYfWn5u2bnN5/Y8atx1brGFscWjnqkQgXM7//@vqKwCAA) Explanation:

```
 Ｓ                  Input string
⭆                   Map over characters and join
        838         Literal string `+&+` or `838`
       Σ            Digital sum i.e. 0 or 19
      ⁺             Plus
           ⌕        Index of
               ι    Current character in
             γ      ASCII characters
            Φ       Filtered where
              μ     Current index is non-zero
  §                 Index into
    γ               ASCII characters
   Φ                Filtered where
     μ              Current index is non-zero
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 60 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 60 bytes.

- Filename (escaped): `.w.o.i.c\001.+.a.d!md!T!j!b!\\!V !k!V\177!lG!|Q!vr!|KK!TKK!T!V\001!|!T`

  - Actual: `.w.o.i.c.+.a.d!md!T!j!b!\!V !k!V!lG!|Q!vr!|KK!TKK!T!V!|!T`
- Content: empty.

### With comments

See also: [Simple cat program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/221388/100411)

```
XX.z
# pasted cat program
.a.w.o.i.c\001.+.aXX.z
# exit
.a.dXX.z
# these literals are ignored
.a!md!T!j!b!\\!V !k!V\177!lG!|Q!vr!|KK!TKK!T!V\001!|!T
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRjtVuJK8v88RaeHj24ghACOStN6FXUuM4qOOl4VGDcmQaIhARIUB5hzdl91H2S2upMgOnPO7t0fku6q6vruqmotI@j/fI8qvQ8V3bo1dN3WDatX2TQ31vSeXjF1s2ev9@zKxqZRrmz23r1Hw6k9cIrl4sDxikM/cKZOMHgX2CFS7QmbDIzgAZVK5TKzp0N/HKLDxs3O4SFvMBI@D210Z4em7/UyGbkz/cHA8Cy6pVn2o@ZNXBeVtzJ6JhMfPtk5/5PjFInpkDpMGEgUTc3EJ19bRAt1gROxX1vNy5uz8z1eLpUqCfDk@Kx5eXh10zg@Pd1vnHOdtZHqIZya7e6c/XlzsX961jxu1YAN6mYyMySt8pG0kolNfpctlmeuf3fEHkxcI7RR0BcH/GEIqyd/bAVD1wmZ4TpGgNQ7lE3N9DxO/YEXWZ4V3yxrfT08bBzt8ZoUAUYLgRYL@k4vlMItJAhjgG32fZR6TzHiSBeiiYQEfRt8GPo@8l1rKyOi4IRIp8x@NFyEFdQz3MDG8/lvyNEqvdRA0kzngW2hbKBNtWeNBfDzXctKud9Rdz4HkyUnoPlFLFgCHnAf@eYmgxAOHdcmlPR4iZlGYIMEHSPHQ6SXo6gH0WB2YJjMCAJ7cOs@i8D7EPMdD6mP4USfh2OkNgJU0suV6tqH9Y1NlG13vFw3O78b20NUnBtPDyi7u/@x2Zq5IMTi1Q8MvEuGY8cLeyg7PPGPvZbTvDEbwdnjRe/A3h@fPv01vXy@@n5t7ITngyNrL68qqXQ6O/8/RKdKHDfaGKVKCHd5B2Nwies/2WMSRCoQnDZxIVWiFOEOZpiBI7MyNQjGhbMCrmHKhOo9HnCMWc8fEwYZ7zqejXpbJUZnTo8kgKDOS1TSATAQnmxkMj3OLTrbJ5RJkajRDrpsYUPUkaCS2Ke@iES0PiQ9KsSxt4wjjGAkg1lii8VSzK8CpIToyCEJKAAExaI38czQ8T10SEypu6mAvjQIDfOh7ebzXW6uEMERQePSWeQu7MYucMF0V1VpDEYYxRxUvRupAU5YLLIyDOoj8iF3ZObhJB8ik2MDt8A6L8@19tP0@XtXUzVDE@Z79VIsGRcNtFtFxYgAz7FpQDpDYuNlZks6CDSJuBhdbRujP0AzLw/samCkYOlLgzRLy2QUj8aOjCB0NuGeqrNIM29rshpbGYBYlUgJ9KT5qGj8Vpe3tkTKYSPWByhk7Ly/wTKJOSQoi69POuh0ROFL7ieekzaK3IxUN0RlUYaA0zyJgsFL4gMZmoKYwaoPgGyQA5cNfc8MHsdhV8sRo67TvNbOw7VTo32ZQnzsacgW2lCbARsWQHVYBHWdwV@M6sOqD4aHWk5RDLaYBVzR2j07jgYzhFOcm66W11zg2jpQQQwxIPaggAmOavteAAoAsC@A2kBTAa3DKtGFLXS4oW/MrLwyMzs7aTv5UpenSmzIxTovcnIxVH5A9iZWuJogU8tdPkQHZyiY3AbhmKRKhQplJ21Vdbr8EoTVSYtH1WBYMAoHZ5RmMqDqDOgJTmGAIKPd6hYiXpRZtmtDr4k4sEWrXgH6QMiKWS4XsR5BzAu1v6FuHjheLnm9qNHaKkM7EU4AF0Cn0NqpdBcSWIjOwQ/YB/GZcrFnzzyCiKSe1p/pNM@fVfLMp1AeeHJ/73mZ3deBjNFh5AGjfQ@Xn606BXKMaJ28tj3NP9cgPNtTFb4KfHPwTcM3/VyDHvSL2futvVkkpQRSHBZVCUBLEZDBSQOD61DMpTRtWbQlXPvmInCLponmJvyS005IhjLtDvZIg88t9DGZss4NJG3PHoeDLrhSy0CF01jIkrsHoOgyA4LOJMYQwIVcWmIpupForb1l35bdMyuuGynR7Hwe7S1gPbbDydgTHSKSkhcMDMtKpKpiH9yGyV4Rexg/kn0nJQCW85gA0pLATxgEWjGn/XV@QHAGihV45Y1my7YZVdCz9gOHPIe7mPSrftSvstDNw6RIZIW/58ujy9Juk106e8jnGbDpcvgROSOitgscd@sCynbzeQqLwm5MAIs3zIXqIIDKfmwhqEeUwS0MzLEzDHmsqOhStm39wEVoNGMYG@V2tRmdkD0q7Cl8JrTL96ROoNrrRhS5X/n8qo19WiIQILb0FdTnF5S05gVz/gojhMoSscRfklM6O@VAJjVR1Tj06HSFaEIacfkmql6HRt@ol9c@0O1GTbS@JdlHwQs8MPF@aEVNsJ14bOKJIeGFabxadsPtVKmmrtryVQiDU40V2A45SvrHTg0Xjla7RgRWXtrH8tSQJOOGAk6lE3IJvyt4P2r5v0d6pFkYFfYK7gvNbMSBCGYk1/buwj4ZUZlFTegPzTp3WRNyaELIHo9r7KjQLOiU/sDtkrrZxdt7@epGrbomBpSlGAd0OCEfX8u@IUeFRuG6cEVnRxwXb2qo5YeiSNl39hizBgd6dg1i5YASDWbV9Sgwaxv0dmwbD6IoNn7gb9V2Za2bwnR2zatVtREfjkhEYyYb0Tm9Cs2owXlFNMCICN46oeNNbLYQ/o@oG/XqhiDcWlunVIKlDi/SIwH0il8h0lCBmImAshNynbtatdFccf4JOX/tgGAFefnqEjxCWO4LF1RWXXB9CW78PZdpDUG4B19ciAtcaHaZ/IgxTyzuo/29qnb5xWoAxiuixGIMLy7fc58zGdBJjEI7BBfHNQRLLMwQl0BebJoTGfMqmE8vlw3YQSkCCgVYrOg/JV8Ko0gi3GcaU@vsi0ytKMFi4Jf6aOXg8984uLV68PtSKRIdTfSK1V8Shiue6ItK@drzgwj9IIbwPoRMkKziLRGZVZK4VQo69gCF5VXEZJlqitqbh3pExNXJkXv5G1VESqOwcUki4vkiSjYiIemTTB7QM//m9orW1FySwA0DwUCiCrJ6aVtt1pqvIidb1yuOuTccRS8bxdXgU5wrRLodVHbll8fZkqqha3vsK8t8GW252yPNrbnaiNJVqdAP/0ee6d/yTAPPtOQpmvvPg9bO0T7PFp@KftEpmp1SSS/mi0bRUgaWcq7cK7dKp6NcIOVBuejo6@uK@1GZf1Eex8r882flXPwBAk4pc@U8@65x3Drfb53zbPZn3ARxSorA8/hFjXrvlpiY@gVnvnt76slEqglF@zeHfkVFZ1ZBS7/1IFbLl/UKk//v2dw6ReJVB0N0dh6If9WoD0j3xgU9md2@yfqdQx1SzHVoCka0ji6GFrrA8EIRDZ7L0Uo1kfxf0kTUB38g5hgAjn8BvqhpVZHaqr4iEANMAHgfDR2rYIfOwC4MzeGk8Bh8Z5YR2nTVzOp/NzM0HBepXrWcmANGkGJnttFZCGM6upZ9eTSpZb26Xt2ofKhuwPMCnjHgFTnkRnOtET3K/r6fxVMs8pP4YPGSS0YnnBCMeCcrvsenZ5ByyegnqoYDc5ojRg4GTxxqtuGtsPynRqeT9nHBgasKQ6icv@IZfIRwx4PwwNloRIjmg2hOgJfGaXqtxLkeWxYgnOQTGsGh@PQiRpvtVCke938VAW//oI/U4KeC36fSmSwUj3xBLWovLqmxf//zX@/e1fnW9h87u429/YOPfzY/fT48ah2ffDk9O/968dfl1bWkaXe6327@Ydyalt276zv3D@7A84ejcRBOHsWoP5svfvwH)

### ]'rz.

- Filename (escaped): `;&;|;v;p\001;8;n;q.zq.a.w.o.i.c .x.c\177.yT.+^.%!.+XX.aXX.a.c\001.+.a`

  - Actual: `;&;|;v;p;8;n;q.zq.a.w.o.i.c .x.c.yT.+^.%!.+XX.aXX.a.c.+.a`
- Content: empty.

#### With comments

```
XX.z
# they are just literals but discarded later
.aXX;&;|;v;p\001;8;n;q.z
# while size<2||pop!=0; do push 'q'; done
.a.zq.aXX.z
# while empty||pop!=0; do
.a.wXX.z
  # if ! empty; then putchar pop; fi
  .a.oXX.z
  # push getchar; dup; push 32;
  # while size<2||pop<pop; do
  .a.i.c .xXX.z
    # dup; push 127; while size<2||pop>pop; do
    .a.c\177.yXX.z
      # push 84; push pop+pop;
      # push 94;
      # push ((x=pop)<(y=pop))?y%x:x%y
      .aT.+^.%XX.z
      # push 33; push pop+pop;
      .a!.+XX.z
    # push X; push X; done (* idiom for BREAK statement *)
    .aXX.aXX.z
  # push X; push X; done
  .aXX.aXX.z
# dup; push 1; push pop+pop; done
.a.c\001.+.a
```

[a!( v# |{yv{r.](https://tio.run/##nRjtVuJK8v88RdPDRzchCQEclab1KupcZhQddeaqwLgxBImGBEhQFJhzdl91H2S2upMgOnPO7t0fku6q6vruqmq7ZtD/@R6Vex/KRvfGNAzbMLu98qa1sWb0jLJlWD17vWeXNzbNUnmz9@49Gk7tgaOVtIHjaUM/cKZOMHgX2CFS7QmbDMzgHhWLpRKzp0N/HKLD@vXO4SGvMxI@DW10a4eW7/WyWbmz/MHA9Lp0S@/aD7o3cV1U2soa2Wx8@GTn/E@O0ySmQ@owYSBRND0TH6W6iBbqAidivzYbF9dn53u8VCyWE@DJ8Vnj4vDyun58erpfP@cGayHVQzg92905@/P62/7pWeO4WQU2qJPNzpC0ykfSSiY2yi5bLM9c/e6IPZi4ZmijoC8O@MMQVo/@uBsMXSdkpuuYAVJvUS49MxSc/gMvcjwnvjnW/Hp4WD/a41UpAowWArss6Du9UArvIkEYA2yr76P0e4oRR4YQTSQk6Nvgw9D3ke92t7IiCk6IDMrsB9NFOIV6phvYeD7/DTlapZcaSJrpPLC7KBfoU/1JZwH8POs5KfcZdeZzMFlyAppfxIIl4AH3gW9uMgjh0HFtQkmPF5llBjZIMDByPER6eYp6EA1mB6bFzCCwBzfukwi8DzHf8ZD6EE6MeThGaj1ARaNUrqx9WN/YRLlW28t3cvPbsT1E2tx8vEe53f2PjebMBSFdXvnAwLtkOHa8sIdywxP/2Gs6jWurHpw9fOsd2Pvj08e/phdPl89X5k54Pjjq7ilqKp3J5Ob/h@h0keN6C6N0EeEOb2MMLnH9R3tMgkgFgjMWLqSLlCLcxgwzcGROpgbBuHBWwFVMmVC9xwOOMev5Y8Ig413Hs1Fvq8jozOmRBBDUeJFKOgAGwpP1bLbHeZfO9gllUiSqt4IOW9gQdSSoJPaxLyIRrQ9Jjwpx7C3jCCMYyWAW2WKxFPOrACkhOnJIAgoAQbHoTTwrdHwPHRJL6m6lQF8ahKZ133IVpcOtFSI4ImhcOovchd3YBS6Y7qoqjcEIo5iDanQiNcAJi0VOhkF9QD7kjsw8nORDZHJs4BZY5ylcbz1On547uqqbujDfqxVjyVgz0W4FaREBnmPLhHSGxMbLzJZ0EGgScTE7@jZGf4BmngLsqmCkYOlLg/Suns2mPBo7MoLQ2YR7qsEizbytyWpsZQBiVSIl0KPuI838rS5vbYmUw2asD1DI2Hl/g2USc0hQFl@fTNBui8KX3E88Jy0UuRmpbohKogwBp3kSBZMXxQcyNA0xg1UfALkgDy4b@p4VPIzDjp4nZs2git5S4Nqp0b5EIT72NGQLfajPgA0LoDosgprB4C9G9WHVB8NDPZ9KmWwxC3hKb/XsOBrMFE5xrju6orvAtXmgghhiQuxBAQsc1fK9ABQAYF8A9YGuAtqAVaILWxhwQ9@YWX5lZm520nKUYoeni2zIxVoRObkYpn5A9iZWuLogU0sdPkQHZyiY3AThmKSLhTJlJy1VdTr8AoTVSJNH1WBYMAsHZ5Rms6DqDOgJTmOAILPV7BQiXpR1bdeGXhNxYItmrQz0gZAVs1wuYj2CmBdqfUcdBTheLHm9qNHcKkE7EU4AF0Cn0FvpTAcSWIjOww/YB/GZcrFnTzyCiKSe1p7oVOFPKnniUygPPLm/d7zE7mpAxugw8oDZuoPLz1adAjlG9Laib0@VpyqEZ3uqwjcF3zx8M/DNPFWhB/1i9n5zbxZJKYIUh0VVAtBSBGRw0sDgOmj5tK4vi7aE699dBG7RddHchF/y@gnJUqbfwh7p8LmBPiZT1rmGpO3Z43DQAVfqWahwOgtZcvcAFF1mQNCZxJgCuJDLrliKbiRaa2/Zt2X3zInrRoo0N59H@y6wHtvhZOyJDhFJUQQDs9tNpKpiH9yEyT4l9jB@JPt2WgC6zkMCyEgCP2EQ6Fpe/@v8gOAsFCvwyhvNlm0zqqBnrXsOeQ53MelX/ahf5aCbh0mRyAl/z5dHl6XdJrt0dq8oDNh0OPyInBFR2wWOuzUBZbuKQmFR2I0JYPGGuVAdBFDZj7sI6hFlcAsDa@wMQx4rKrqUbXd/YA0azRjGRrldbUYnZI8KewqfCe3wPakTqPa6EUXuT31@1cY@LREIEFvGCurzC0pa84I5f4URQmWJWOIvyCmdnXIgk5qoahx6dLpCNCH1uHwT1ahBo6/XSmsf6Ha9Klrfkuyj4AUemHg/dE0XbCcem3hiSHhhGq@W3XA7Xayqq7Z8FcLgVH0FtkOOkv6xU8WFo9WuEYFTL@1jeWpIknEjBU6lE3IBvyt4P2r5v0d6pFEYFfYK7gvNbMSBCGYk1/Zuwz4ZUZlFDegPjRp3WQNyaELIHo9r7KjQKBiU/sCtorrZwdt7SmWjWlkTA8pSjAM6nJCPr2Vfk6NCvXBVuKSzI4616ypq@qEoUvatPcaszoGeXYFYOaBEg1llPQrM2ga9GdvmvSiK9R/4e6VVXuukMZ1d8UpFrceHIxLRmMlGdM6oQDOqc14WDTAigrdO6HgTmy2E/yPqeq2yIQi31tYplWCpw4v0SAC95JeI1FUgZiKg7IRc5S9XbbRWnH9Czl87IFhBXry6BA8QlrvCNyqrLri@CDf@jsu0hiDcgS@@iQtcaHSY/IgxTyzuov2dqnb4t9UAjFdEicUYXly@5z5ls6CTGIV2CNbGVQRLLMwQl0BebJoXGfMqmI8vlw3YQSkCihSwWNF/Sr4URpFEuM80pjbYF5laUYLFwC@10crBp79xcGv14PNSKRIdTfSK1V8Shiue6ItK@drzgwh9L4bwPoRMkKziuyIyqyRxqxR07B4Ky6uIyTLVELVXgXpExNXJkzv5G1VESqOwcUki4vkiSjYiIemTTB7QU3lze0VraixJ4IaBYCBRBVmtuK02qo1XkZOt6xXH/BuOopeN4mrwKc4VIt0OKrvyy@NsSVfRlT32U8t8GW252yPdrbr6iNJVqdAP/0eemd/yzADPjOQpmvvPg@bO0T7PsSybswc2bBeLBttgHhtpzyPN1B41X3M0C2lTzWob6@va07mmfNcymZSmXFxopvgDDJzSFM3MvasfN8/3m@c8l/sZN0GcliLwPH5Ro967JSamfsFZ796eerSQakHR/s2hX1HRmVXQ0m89iNXyZb3C5P97NjdPkXjVwRCdmwfiXzXqPTK8ccFIZrfvsn7nUZto@TZNw4jWNsTQQhcYXiiiwXM5WqkWkv9Lmoj64A/EHAPA8S/AFzW7FaQ2K68IxAATAN5HQ6dbsENnYBeG1nBSeAieWdcMbbpqZuW/mxmajotUr1JKzAEjiNaebbQXwpi2oedeHk1qyaisVzbKHyob8LyAZwx4RQ650VxrRo@yv@9n8RSL/CQ@WLzkktEJJwQj3s6J7/HpGaRcMvqJquHAnOaIkYPBE4daLXgrLP@p0W5nfFxw4KrCECrnr3gGHyHc9iA8cDYaEaL5IJoT4KVxmlkrcm7ElgUIJ/mERnAoPr2I0VYrXYzH/V9FwNs/6CM1@JnC79OZbA6Kh1JQNf3FJVX273/@6927Gt/a/mNnt763f/Dxz8anz4dHzeOTL6dn51@//XVxeSVpWu3O9@t/mDdW1@7d9p27e3fg@cPROAgnD2LUn80XP/4D)